# Display review queues based on watched tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, review-queues

I feel I could review better and clearer in the questions of the tech-stack I know about. I already have some watched tags. Is it possible that review queue fetches only those questions that are tagged with my watched tags? 
This will help in clear decision making and wasting my time in guess work/skipping.

Comment: All queues (except for triage) already allow you to filter by tags. Click the "filter" button next to the headline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that this is useful - that's why this behavior has been a part of review for over 6 years now: [Are review queues curated for the reviewer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289781/are-review-queues-curated-for-the-reviewer/289860#289860)

The caveats here are:

1. Ignored tags are not taken into account
2. If no tasks in your watched tags are available, you'll be shown whatever *is* available

Comment: I think that the bias should be more extreme, especially on the close queue.

Comment: We need a [status-already-there] tag on meta.

Comment: @Braiam Agreed for dupes. But it doesn't really require an expert to determine whether a question is unclear, too-broad, or off-topic. On the other hand, there are generally plenty of review tasks on a large site like Stack Overflow, and assuming enough reviewers, matching them with their expertise does seem like the best possible use of their labor resources.

Comment: @CodyGray I prefer the expert because they would be *more invested on being accurate* with their votes, which puts them in a advantageous position at identifying the issue with the question and savaging what can objectively be savaged. Also, it keeps the reviewer engaged since they would be reading stuff they do have informed opinions about which doesn't seems like Klingon to them.