# What can we do to encourage downvoting?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

Downvoting is a bigger privilege than upvoting and it plays a crucial role in keeping the content on this site clean. Downvoting is our most powerful tool for us, non-moderator users. Downvotes are a strong signal both to future readers and the author of the post that something is wrong and the experts on this site deem the post to be of little value for future readers.

The new tooltip popovers contain the following explanation:

> Downvote this question if you find it unclear or not useful.
> Downvote this answer if you find it unclear or not useful.

As everyone knows we rate content, not the users. Votes are not meant to be friendly or offensive. There's no shame in using the downvote button just as there is no shame in using the upvote button whenever you like. It is our own personal choice how we rate the content and what we do with our votes as long as we do not abuse the rules.

There will always be two extremes possible. Some users mostly downvote:

[image: Some user's vote stats]

However, there's [a number of active users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1253867) who decided to never cast a single downvote or use them very sporadically:

[image]

While we value contributions from both groups of users, it sometimes feels like downvotes are treated as toxic behaviour. It could be very much the reason why some people decide to never cast a single downvote even if it seems like it is easier to cast downvotes than upvotes. There are almost [8 times more upvotes on Stack Overflow than downvotes](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1253875).

Downvotes are very important and necessary for this site to function properly. If a user posts an answer and the answer is wrong then we must downvote. **It is not enough to just ignore and never upvote it.** Without our downvotes, users might never know that their 0 scored answer was not useful. 0 score means nothing.

Upvotes and downvotes are the community's way of separating the cure from the poison. We must use both of them.

Many new users get very offended by a single downvote on their question, yet they have completely no objection for the upvotes. Why is that? Why so many users demand that the downvotes be accompanied by an explanatory comment yet nobody demands an explanation for the upvotes? Do people really value the fake Internet points so much or is it about acceptance by strangers? Why is their perception of our voting systems so skewed?

It's true that the ratio of upvotes to downvotes is often driven by the tag, but I am pretty sure that we all encounter bad questions and answers in every tag. There's always something to upvote as well as downvote. If we see a badly asked question, then we should downvote. If we see a wrong or outdated answer then we should downvote.

Do we have any ideas about what we could do or change to encourage people to spend a little bit more of their votes on downvoting posts?

Comment: The solution to this problem is the holy grail of Stack Overflow. I can't overstate how important and crucial this subject is and how much effort the company should be investing in bringing downvotes as the widely admitted form of curation without the poor recurring stigma.

Comment: ++, but I'll be happy starting off with fewer upvotes.  I swear there is an upvote bot running on the tags where I hang.  These stray, single upvotes prevent bad questions from being deleted.

Comment: I thought that current SO stance was that downvotes are unwelcoming and therefore discouraged.

Comment: @Kreiri that was never the case, although the misconception emerges fairly often. Relevant reading: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366889

Comment: Getting things closed that really deserve to be closed should also be encouraged. Seems harder and harder in the current *"be nice"* environment to get more than one close vote sometimes even when the question is pure garbage

Comment: **For anyone who decides to post an idea here:** Do not delete replies under this post if they are met with disapproval. Even bad ideas bring something to the table. If your answer starts to gather downvotes, please leave it, don't delete it.

Comment: related discussion at MSE: [A badge that rewards “prophetic” downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134551/165773)

Comment: @Michael-Where'sClayShirky The only thing close to that is the help center, which still suggests that downvotes should be [reserved for extreme cases](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down), although experience later on showed that [downvoting (questions at least) more aggressively is actually important](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/). Other than that, the feature exists, with a limit of 40 a day, so let's use it for what it's meant to be used.

Comment: There's definitely no stance at the company level that downvotes are "unwelcoming" or discouraged in any way. What's unwelcoming are snarky comments, which many users post *in lieu of* downvotes. A silent downvote on problematic content would be far better.

Comment: Downvoting an answer is usually -1 rep. Sometimes I just let it go... I'm not proud about that either.

Comment: there is much to much downvoting already,and not enough upvoting. the peolple should be encouraged to get a silver and gild medal for there favourite tag, but it is quite hard to reach it, when nobody upvotes, only acknowledged thh answer. we should so encourage more upvotes and less  downvotes

Comment: @nbk Did you see this link posted in the question? "_There is almost [8 times more upvotes on Stack Overflow than downvotes.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1253875)_" I see a lot of bad questions with upvotes. Some of those are pity-upvotes where users admit in comments they upvoted because "we shouldn't be mean". This needs to stop.

Comment: Could you add a statistic here? 8 times more upvotes than downvotes is skewed by the fact that lower reputation users are far more common. In other words: how many people have 15-125 rep, and how many >125?

Comment: new users should be encouraged, to do a good job, and downvoting at once, because they are no experts in the field and can't kiow what is needed to solve the problem, so closing and commenting, how to improve it isd mre than enough. But there are a lot iof problems. the colsing vptes review s still to big to handle, amd threcent ban puinishment for making an error, will not help to make that huge riwview queue smaller, so that close votes a noticed and swiftly dealt with.

Comment: No, @nbk, downvotes should not be based on the skill level of the user. That has no relevance whatsoever. Votes are on *posts*, not on users.

Comment: Does the SEDE query pickup downvotes on deleted posts? I know the vote timeline in profiles doesn't. I'm asking because I see users in the table who are no strangers to curation, and the ratio for them makes no sense to me.

Comment: One problem with downvoting is not the just fact people don't do it, it can be more that if I want to point out issues with an answer a comment helps others understand why the downvote is there.  I've had an answer downvoted as the person who did it had misunderstood something, their accompanying comment let me clarify the issue.

Comment: @StoryTeller Good thought, but it looks like the SEDE totals *do* include deleted posts in the vote tallies. I just checked the results for myself, and while SEDE reports my vote totals as 18,693 and 33,734, the all-time numbers reported on my profile page (Activity -> Votes cast) are 18,706 and 34,089. That means I must have downvoted about 400 posts in the past week since SEDE was last updated, and that's correct.

Comment: @CodyGray The reality now adays lokks so, if you want to get a upvote, you have to fist upvote the qustion the answer, nobody except the user who made the more or minus good question will give you any kind of upvote. and that is why there are much miore upvotes than downvotes.

Comment: I don't think that's true, @nbk. As you can see from my previous comment, I cast a lot of downvotes, yet I also receive plenty of upvotes. While some users may follow a "tit for tat" sort of rule when it comes to votes, that's something that we strongly discourage, and extreme versions of that "tit for tat" approach are considered voting fraud. However, it stands to reason that answerers would upvote the question, so that in itself is not particularly suspicious. After all, if a question is good enough for you to take the time to compose an answer, why would it not be worth an upvote?

Comment: Honestly I think the premise in the question is wrong. People are spending a good amount of time downvoting. Always when I see a bad question, it's literaly instantly downvoted. The right question here should be: How to encourage people to upvote questions? I've noticed that many, many upvotes are based on how "interesting" a question is and not how "good" it is technically.

Comment: @CubicleSoft I don't know what makes you think that reputation points are subtracted from users that have commented on a post, that gets downvoted, but you're misinformed. This is not correct.

Comment: *"Why so many users demand that the downvotes be accompanied by an explanatory comment yet nobody demands an explanation for the upvotes? "* Explanationa for upvotes usually come in the form of "thanks it worked". Do we want more of these comments? When you upvote something, the explanation almost always is "this was helpful". We don't want such comments. The system even forbids comments with `+1` in them. Downvotes, on the other hand, need an explanation as you are suggesting the answer is lacking some quality you are aware of and sharing what's wrong is helpful for the author of that post.

Comment: I'll be pruning some comments here since the discussion got lengthy. Let's continue the discusson in [The Meta Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197438/the-meta-room) or [Discord](https://discord.gg/tpgZmwR). If you have a contribution, please post it as an answer below.

Comment: To some extent, downvotes make it less likely that others will see a post. By downvoting a post early, you're not only stating your own opinion of the question but also signaling to others that they shouldn't even waste their time looking at it (plus any algorithmic ranking effects). That's pretty harsh and I'd only want to do that with questions that are truly trash.

Comment: I never downvote, since it costs me 1 rep and thus feels like I am doing something wrong.
On the other hand, one of my first questions got multiple downvotes, which made me feel so bad I never wanted to look at the question again. It took me some time after that, until I dared/had to use Stackoverflow again.

Comment: I don't trust the average human's judgement of what questions are "useful", and to whom, enough to make the premise of your question valid. I think there are far too many downvotes and deleted questions on this site. Answers are a whole different story.

Comment: @LearningFast Downvotes are not "judgement", they are an opinion. We as users get to vote on our perception of the post.

Comment: @BluE Downvoting questions does not cost rep.

Comment: @LearningFast so you trust humans when it comes to asking good questions, but not when it comes to downvotes? Interesting stance

Comment: I get a lot of what has been said here, some of which I had not realised before. However, as a counter argument: there are those cases where people have downvoted questions, perfectly reasonable ones, perfectly clearly expressed, because theIr own experience gives them  no obvious answer to hand. Asking to have the question made clearer, more focused, or generally simpler is useful, helpful advice that a more experienced person can offer to a lesser experienced one. Downvoting without leaving a helpful explanation will not improve the quality of the content, and put less experienced people off

Comment: @iainH "Downvoting without leaving a helpful explanation will not improve the quality of the content, and put less experienced people off" If the downvotes are really well deserved then the quality of the overall content on SO that is seen by visitors is improved by downvoting without explanation because: downvoted questions may get auto-deleted, may get less traffic, can result in question bans, can result in fear and more carefulness with the next questions, can be seen as a general hint to check the question again with help from the help center. Not all of it may be good but it works.

Comment: _"Downvotes are very important and necessary for this site to function properly."_ - that has not been proofed with any researches results on either SO data nor other internet communities rating systems, but the whole question about the ways of encouraging of downvoting is based on this arbitrary statement of the author

Comment: @EgorBEremeev here is a proof - content rating is at the core of the website philosophy. It's mentioned in the tour. Also see [Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote), [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and [the vote down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) privileges, as well as [Expected behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) under **Be honest**. Voting makes SO what it is - a good place for getting valuable answers. Downvotes *are for content rating*, ergo they are part of the core philosophy of SO.

Comment: @EgorBEremeev also, I'd love to know why you've upvoted content without being shown any "has not been proofed with any researches results on either SO data nor other internet communities rating systems" - a rather high bar that you expect from downvotes yet apparently waive for upvotes.

Comment: @VLAZ, Firstly, it is the author of the Question must _show research efforts_, not you - commenter and sympathizer, not me when upvoting some question. Secondly, the help center article you've mentioned is not proof :-), simple because it does not contatins any word about analysis of results which have been achived by current voting system. Thirdly, Your statement _content rating is at the core of the website philosophy_ is a sophism in context of prooving as it is, obviosly, not equal to the statement _the content rating systems which includs downvoting is efficient_.

Comment: @EgorBEremeev I don't know what scientific study you are looking for. If you want to discuss this topic further please ask a new Meta question. We can discuss this in a separate topic. Comments are not for extended discussion.  VLAZ did explain shortly why voting is important, either up or down. From personal experience, I can clearly see that downvotes are an effective tool in letting other readers know what is useful and what is know, but downvotes are also helpful in actual moderation of the content.

Comment: Just give users +1 rep for downvoting instead of -1. The just watch as everyone expend their daily downvote count for free internet points!

Comment: @EgorBEremeev "..it is the author of the Question must show research efforts.." In principle yes, but in this case it's okay because most people here believe in the premise of the question anyway. But we could probably try to prove it. First define a success measure, then do a controlled experiment without downvoting and see if the control is doing better or worse regarding the chosen measure. The same way you would try to prove any ideas proposed here. The sad thing is that the whole discussion basically ended without any impact and in particular the company ignored it completely.

Comment: @Trilarion, I'm glad to know that this discussion ended without any impact and company ignored it completely. I glad because, supporters of downvoting here just try to pushed the opinion based actions. Like, Dharman, VLAZ above judged personal experience and short explanations enough for themselves, but for other SO user's they have more strong criteria armed with downvoting. And I repeat: demonstration of the research efforts by author is the _SO requirement_ for the question. Oppositely the question should be downvoted ))), but seems moderators community tended to double standards.

Comment: @EgorBEremeev The criteria for downvotes are already defined. The question wasn't asking for opinions on when it is justifiably to upvote or downvote a post. The question was asking what we can do to make downvotes more utilized by more people.

Comment: @EgorBEremeev please feel free to write a meta post about it. Comments aren't big enough to express ideas properly and engage a limited audience. Also, as Dharman said earlier, comments aren't for extended discussion.

Comment: @EgorBEremeev Sure you can downvote the question and more than 100 other people did so too. But then, you can also upvote as useful and more than 400 other people did so. It's not really shown that more downvotes would be better, but that doesn't kill the question. Do you know what the company sometimes pulls off? They introduced a "Thank you" feature last year without asking anyone publicly before. This here is just a brainstorming discussion and I would have expected that the proposed changes all get a separate discussion before even trying them out. Enough time to vet them thoroughly.

Comment: @Cody Gray: why did SO not originally use views instead of votes to rank answers - the same way questions are?

Comment: The 8 times statistic might be less meaningful than it seems, since many low rep users(like me) upvote, but can't downvote, which would skew that particular statistic.

Comment: I am about to go on a downvoting spree (constructively not recklessly).

Comment: **As everyone knows we rate content, not the users**  Why would you think that ?

Comment: I wanted to answer this question, but since we have 73 answers, and it's quite messy - should I write a new question referencing this post or still post it here?

Comment: @LightningMcQueen please go though the answers. 73 answers likely have most of the important points covered. If after reading them you feel like you can add something more then feel free to write a new answer.

Answer (score 412):

- Increase the number of downvotes given to each user per day. On many days, I have run out of votes while still seeing truckloads of low quality content ("Me too!", "why does this not work [wall of code]" and "here is my assignment how do I do it [wall of text]", etc.) that I have to let slide with just a closevote or flag.
- Remove the -1 rep cost of downvoting an answer.

Comment: Point 2 thats' the key. Remove that and we will be flooded by downvoted answers.  Has this any chance to happen? My gut feeling is a categorical NO

Comment: @Steve We never witnessed a flood of downvotes on questions when the cost to downvote questions was removed years ago. There is no reason that it would be the case for downvotes on answers.

Comment: "Me too!" answers don't need to be downvoted (unless someone has upvoted them), since they get deleted, and once they get deleted their score is irrelevant.

Comment: @pppery There's also no harm in downvoting them either. It might be a good thing sometimes. Negative score can show the author that this is not how answers work. When a mod deletes their answer out of the blue it will be less of a shock since they will see that other people downvoted the answer. NAAs usually get deleted quickly so you get your vote back before the end of the day.

Comment: @pppery - I am sorry I disagree.  If you don’t downvote bad answers that are not actually an answer, the author of that answer, will never understand they are not supposed to submit those answers.  There are users who will submit upwards of 10 answers within an hour span.  Downvoting these low quality answers is the only way to get their attention.

Comment: @pppery Deleting answers is much easier if they are negatively-scored. Therefore, if an answer needs to be deleted, you should be downvoting it. There are really no exceptions. If an answer isn't something you think deserves a downvote, then it definitely doesn't need to be deleted.

Comment: Remove -1 rep... NO... Revenge down votes are real. Usually they are contained to questions because down voting answers costs rep. I don't care about rep much, and Q score is not important, but down votes on answers should be down votes on content and not just random revenge. In high traffic tags they might not matter as much but in some others they might.

Comment: I certainly hesitate to downvote sometimes because I don't like the -1 messing up my reputation being divisible by 5, 10, or 100. So yes, point 2 please.

Comment: @cs95 Alternative solution: make downvotes cost -5. (I'll wait while you prepare the tar and feathers.)

Comment: Before something similar to the proposal is implemented, I believe, we also need to analyze how frequently the downvotes are being misused (e.g. personal attacks, revenge, racial bias, etc). Naturally, I agree with @DalijaPrasnikar.

Comment: @CodyGray I would not mind if down vote would cost -5, on the other hand I was down voting really bad answers when my reputation was around 200. At that time -5 would have significant impact even though I was earning rep rather fast.

Comment: @CodyGray: if there really are "no exceptions", shouldn't a close vote automatically apply a downvote then? (That is, any flag other than "needs moderator attention".) That downvote would certainly have reason to not cost any rep.

Comment: Wait a minute here. First we're supposed to be "more accepting". Now we're supposed to downvote more. WILL YOU MAKE UP MY MIND?!?!?!?!?

Comment: @CodyGray: rep matters - that's the whole point behind "game-ifying" the idea of a question-and-answer site. Increasing our rep and having something to brag about / put on our resumes is to some extent why those of us who answer a lot of questions are here. If the downvote "price" is increased I will absolutely stop what little downvoting I do, and I suspect others will too. And to JeroenMostert's point about "close-vote = downvote" - if you put a cost on close-voting, you'll copy your lack-of-downvote issue to your (new and exciting!) lack-of-close-voting issue.

Comment: @CodyGray: if you want more downvotes, remove the -1 penalty for downvoting, and eliminate rep mins for downvoting privileges. You will quickly have more downvotes than you know what to do with - and everyone who's getting killed by noob downvotes will bail on the site and head elsewhere.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica You look a bit confused, don't you? :)

Comment: -1 points for downvoting is poorly justified. I understand the reasoning, but this sweeping policy is not the answer. Sure, for competing answers on the same question, we can keep this. "Revenge downvotes" can be mitigated by forcing people to leave a comment when they downvote someone. Or we can give users a choice, do you want -1 point or do you want to leave a comment explaining the downvote?

Comment: @Drew required comments are easy to abuse: "I'm downvoting this answer because it sucks", "I'm downvoting this answer because asdop asdfsaef", or "I'm downvoting this answer because it is bad and needs to be downvoted."

Comment: @RobertColumbia I think you may lack some imagination here. "How is foo defined?", "@SomeoneElse has a good point", "Would you mind accepting my answer?" for users with self-answers.. or the killer: "Thanks!  It works for me" :)

Comment: @RobertColumbia Good point. This should be treated like any other abuse. If the only explanation one can provide for a downvote is nonsense, then it should be reported and their downvote or at least their comment should be removed. I proposed requiring a comment because it would make it much easier for a person receiving "downvote revenge" to identify and report it.

Comment: "Remove the -1 rep cost of downvoting an answer." <-- I disagree with this. Change it so that the -1 happens if someone upvotes the question after you downvoted.

Comment: Meh. You want more rep to downvote with? Then perhaps consider participating more. This answer is kind of lazy to be honest. If you are going to suggest a fundamental change to voting, then you should really back it up with some citation or at least something pointing to the impacts, advantages, and disadvantages. One reason that the cap is in place for votes (both up and down) is to ensure that voting is not skewed too hard by a single group of users who contribute more votes than others. Another is to reduce fatigue. None of these points are addressed, and there are dozens more.

Comment: I'll admit: I've not downvoted bad answers that I didn't expect would be deleted afterward. Is it lazy? Sure, I'm not proud of it, but I've only got 7k rep. Many of the people who suggest that this is lazy are well over the maximum privileges, and often have large amounts of rep from older posts that have accumulated it over time. I get more rep here and there, but if I downvoted every bad, lazy answer I saw, I would probably have a lot less. There are many ways to participate in this community.  Downvoting bad answers is one I've chosen not to use heavily, because I'm penalized for doing so.

Comment: Both of the points here would not work for me. The "minecraft-commands" tag on gamingSE has the issue that MC 1.13 changed all commands, so ~70% of answers are outdated for years and don't work. I already don't run into the vote limit, because I don't go around intentionally looking for outdated answers (except when I do [big cleanups](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/363578)), but I still keep encountering them, and I don't care about the -1 (my rep. would be 5.8% higher without it). The problem is that **not enough people** downvote, especially (for gamingSE) on old posts.

Comment: @FabianRöling Don't down vote answers just because they are outdated. If the answer no longer applies then leave comment under the answer, notify OP to add warning or edit the answer yourself. Note - edit answers only if it is not obvious from the question/answer that answer is no longer valid for since certain version.

Comment: It's gotten to the point where I would downvote almost every question and a significant percentage of answers. I no longer trust my sense of what should be downvoted. I only downvote blatant garbage these days. But there's plenty of that.

Comment: I didn't notice that penalties for downvoting questions had been removed a year ago, which shows how many times I downvote.  The penalty for answers isn't a consideration itself, but the fact that it it exists at all is a strong signal that it is considered antisocial.  If you want people to believe downvotes serve a valuable purpose, that signal must be removed.

Comment: The few times that I downvote *answers* I usually get the rep back because it's on bad answers that eventually get deleted.  The times that I don't is when I vote down answers to obvious duplicates.  I understand the need for duplicates, but they attract bad behavior.  Point-wise, it's better to throw an answer at the duplicate and upvote the question to try and get the question to stick around before it closes.  The question usually comes from users that are more than happy to upvote the answer which perpetuates it and keeps it from roomba.

Comment: +1 I dont downvote unless its so bad I can smell it through my monitor because of the cost. However if downvotes were free, I would do it all day long. So many questions and answers deserve it but it would kill my score.

Comment: You will never get people to adopt a habit if there is only negatives associated to it without providing context, or a greater reward down the line. I distinctly remember the first time I downvoted, and felt penalised for it, so I have never downvoted since. It's just basic human psyche. Definitely remove the -1 for downvotes if there's no other upside to it. Or at the very least give a warning about it, or allude to it in the hover tooltip.

Comment: Minor note: some users interpret the 1-rep cost of downvoting answers [as a discouragement of “negative” behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334018/289905#comment1092858_334018).

Comment: @user4642212 I would be surprised if this isn't how *most* new users interpret it... *Losing reputation* means you've done something *disreputable*, such as post an answer that isn't useful or a question that isn't well formed or researched - it means you're not contributing to the site. It's easy to interpret downvotes as one of these disreputable actions and never want to do it. But downvotes actually do contribute to the site, so how on earth is that reasonable?

Comment: The minus one rep cost is a big deal, I typically only down vote something when it's actively wrong and is the most upvoted answer or is the accepted answer. in the case of the accepted answer I check to see how long it's been since it was accepted just in case the user might return to except another answer but if the answer looks old enough that they could have switched it by then I give it the down vote. as you can see though those are pretty stringent requirements for me to use my points that way.

Comment: Reading half of the comments here, I really want a downvote comment option... which is a whole other discussion.

Comment: @cs95 Everyone starts at 1 reputation though, so if there was no -1 penalty then a lot of users would be locked at reputation ending with a 1 or a 6 (once they are past the +2 from suggesting edits)

Comment: From my perspective, I think it is not good to quickly downvote people if something useful can come from answering the question, then it is useful for everyone. The point here is to help each other, and even if you think downvoting is useful for you, it could be harmful to the one who's asking if you didn't mention why is the question is not good. If you did say why it's not good enough then you're helping the person whom you just unvoted, and decreased the reputation. It is not about who downvote first. It is about willing to have an open mind and help each other.

Comment: Running out of vote seems impossible to me. I mean, the limit is 40/day so even if you spend 2h on SO, that means one vote every 3 minute. I don't think allowing frenetic voting is a good idea, votes just like everything else should take time/reflexion.

Comment: I almost never downvote. That is simply and exclusively because of the -1 rep. I feel like I get punished for downvoting and thus only do it if the answer/question is absolutely atrocious. I have 135 up and 3 down. I would have cast a lot more downvotes on subpar content if it wasn't for that -1. It has taken me almost 10 years to get my 784 reputation. I have awarded a bounty and I feel better about loosing rep that way than casting downvotes. -1 is way too much - I would easily have cast 100 downvotes, but I would rather spend that rep on bounties - so I refrain.

Comment: On the point of "removing rep loss on downvote didn't increase downvotes on questions" - I'm not sure most people realise that there is no rep loss on downvotes. I didn't until I read this. I just see the -1 when I downvote _something_ and assume it does that for everything, but I never noticed that downvoting a question doesn't do this until now. I think humans are more likely to notice something happening than the lack of something happening, so maybe the disparity between the two is an issue.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I was explicitly told to do that. Editing would mean basically re-answering all of the many thousands of questions, that's a ton of effort. Deleting is not allowed, according to people on Meta. Downvoting is the only thing left that doesn't take months out of my life for every Minecraft update. And some answers don't even have to be updated, because the question is no longer relevant, because there's now a built-in way to do it.

Comment: @FabianRöling That is wrong. If there is such problem with Minecraft, then you (not you personally) should have additional tag versions so Q/A pairs for old versions can be more easily discarded when searching for solutions without invalidating posts that were valid at the time of posting, and may still be valid for old versions.

Comment: i actually had no idea that there is a limit on downvotes until i read this answer.  is there a limit on upvotes as well?

Comment: @billynoah They share the same limit, it's a vote limit, not an upvote limit/downvote limit

Comment: @Klaycon I'm a relatively new user. I've actually used stackoverflow read-only for years.
At some point I've seen a user with a really useful answer, on a very specific question. He never received approval, nor upvotes. Wanted to upvote, seen you should be registered, then have 15 reputation. Have registered, asnwered a couple of questions, then made the upvote. From then I decided to start using stackoverflow actively. I don't like discussions and only actually talk when I have something useful to say, so I won't get much reputation. Each downvote hurts newbies really badly.

Comment: Re: removing the -1 rep cost of downvoting an answer - replace it with the requirement to provide a brief **for-moderators-only-to-see** comment as to why the answer was downvoted. Moderators can then use those comments during their investigations into complaints about possibly-vexatious downvoting.

Answer (score 306):

Maybe give more *rewards* to downvotes so people will have more reason to downvote. We all know that a lot of users are performing many actions simply to receive badges and rewards (editing, reviewing, etc). This can probably encourage them to do such action more frequently.

I don't have clear ideas, but I would see a few badges like:

- Earn XXX if you downvote 100 posts that are later deleted.
- Earn YYY if you downvote 1000 posts that are later deleted.
- Use at least 20 downvotes in a single day to earn ZZZ
- etc.

A whole set of badges to encourage users to use their downvotes and I am pretty sure a lot of them will do. They won't get bothered by the `-1` if at the end there is badge. Like someone who spent 50 reputation for a bounty to earn the related badge.

---

Since a downvoted answer is a signal that it can be bad, not accurate, low quality, etc., why not push all new negative answers to a queue where we can review them. Again I don't have a clear idea about how it should work but I imagine something like this:

- A new answer is posted
- One downvote is made within the next 12h<sup>1</sup> (a signal for a potential bad content)
- The answer is pushed inside a queue so it has more visibility for other user to judge it (either to downvote it, downvote and delete it, or choose "looks good")

It would work almost the same as the "low quality posts".

When I flag an answer as low quality, it has a good chance to get deleted (because it will be reviewed), but when downvoting an answer, it will not necessarily gather more downvotes, because I will not send a signal to anyone. Of course, it doesn't necessarily need to be downvoted more, but at least to bring more eyes to it.

Currently we have:

> Me: Oh, a bad answer, downvote and move on.
>
> Others: ...

It would be good to have:

> Me: Oh, a bad answer, downvote and move on.
>
> Others: someone made a downvote, let me have a look.
>
> One among the others: He's right, this answer is bad, another downvote.

<sup>1</sup>Of course, we don't do this for all the downvoted answers but only the new ones so they are judged quickly. An old answer may gather a downvote, because it's outdated or no longer works and we don't need to bring more attention to it.

---

I will suggest one last idea: maybe downvotes can give us reputation. If I downvote an answer, I will get `-1`, but if the answer is later deleted why not getting `+2` (cancelling the `-1` and rewarding me with `+1` overall). After all, my downvote led to the deletion of bad content, so it's like I made a good contribution to the site.

I know there is room for a lot of abuse, but we can add some restriction like applying this logic to only users under 5k or limit the earning of the extra +1 to only +X per day, etc.

With this, new users will no more be afraid of the `-1` and will be more *clever* to target *very bad* answers since there is a good chance for a deletion and another `+1`.

Comment: Your last idea is very innovative. And I think it will keep users from downvoting good content just because they want the badge, when they have better options.

Comment: @Scratte even in the badges I tried to bring the *deleted* factor to avoid blind downvotes and correctly grap the answer that really need to be downvoted.

Comment: Definitely more thoughtful than my answer. Putting downvoted answers into a queue is a good idea, but what would the reputation to use it be? Rewarding points for having downvoted posts deleted, is a great idea in one aspect, as in rewarding users for the contribution, but on the other hand, the consequences of abusing this, is potentially worse than abusing upvotes.

Comment: As you read in my answer: I generally don’t downvote answers; that’s because only a few of them get deleted. If more got deleted, I’d of course be more willing to downvote them. Putting them in a queue should be an effective means of making sure they do get deleted, however, we’d also need people to monitor that queue, and we’ve lost many contributors lately. I myself ceased activity for a few months. If things get worse again (we’re not far from that), I’m out, and so are others too. Then that’s even fewer to monitor the queue, but, of course, it would also mean fewer downvoters.

Comment: @Andreas I don't think abusing this can be worse than with upvote especially that the amount is very small so you need a lot of effort to earn reputation if you aim to fraud. It's more a solution to say to users *don't worry about the -1, you will get it back with another +1 if you downvote bad answers*. At then end it's a simple idea I had. It can be improved or we can infer better ones from it. TL;DR from my answer is that we need to reward downvote actions to encourage them. + we consider the queue for more monitoring

Comment: I have to disagree with "They won't get bothered by the -1 if at the end there is badge.", I think for most lower rep users, rep is far more valuable than badges, even if it's only a single point. Though your final idea would definitely help counter that.

Comment: @DBS it depends on users. I have seen users creating bounties as soon as possible for some random good answer and I am pretty sure they have done it for the Badge. Maybe they are confident that they can easily get back the Rep (the same can happen for downvotes)

Comment: Regarding "earning badge (and/or rep) by downvoting N posts that are later deleted", while I can sympathize, I'm more worried of the bandwagon effect (and possibly <s>witch</s>badge-hunting) resulting in an honest NAA getting downvoted to -6 or lower... (personally, I find it too much?)

Comment: *Actually* we have: Me: Oh, a bad answer, downvote and move one. Others: someone made a downvote, let me be nice and give an upvote. One among the others: He's right and kind, another upvote.

Comment: In my opinion your suggestion will only harm the site and encourage people to go on a downvoting spree just to get cheap rep and badges. If we really need to encourage people to downvote bad answers then remove the `-1` penalty for new users until they reach _X_ rep at which point you can reintroduce the `-1` as people generally don't care about that anymore.

Comment: wait, downvoted answers should be deleted? Why not just keeping it and everybody knows that they are bad?

Comment: @Ooker not all downvoted answers should be deleted but only the ones that are irrelevant, very bad, doesn't answer the question, etc should be deleted. bad answer or bad solution can be kept unless the OP decide to delete them

Comment: I think you have some good ideas here, but I occasionally need to downvote highly upvoted wrong answers and I don't expect those to ever get deleted (unfortunately). Also as a low rep user that tries to answer / clean up old stuff there really is a cost (not just an imaginary one) to downvoting. I try and follow up with answerers and give them a chance to correct the content instead of drive by downvoting, I think that helps both parties a lot.

Comment: There is no real confirmation that we need to improve the downvote to upvote ratio. Why should we? All it relates to is the fact that more useful content is posted to the site than non useful content. Altering that ratio by introducing weights (as this answer shows and others suggest) doesn't really add anything to the site. If an answer should be deleted because it is legitimately not an answer (not often statistically) then users should cast an actual delete vote on it. If users need more reputation to cast votes, then perhaps they can contribute more content or cast a flag.

Comment: The issue with putting downvoted posts into queues might be a feedback loop. I already encountered the issue many times that I voted to close a question, the asker or someone else cleared up a misunderstanding I had, so I removed the close vote, but someone else had added another in the meantime, so it stays in the queue pretty much until it's closed for no reason. I have to keep watching the close vote number going up over days, just to wait until it's closed, then vote to reopen again, which again takes days to weeks. (This is on gamingSE BTW.) This shouldn't happen with downvotes as well.

Comment: I trip over the same point as @ooker since unhelpful or even incorrect answers that attempt to answer the question are not to be flagged or deleted. Given that, I’m not sure having a queue would do much outside of creating a downvote factory (to Fabian’s point). My experience is that legitimate _NAA_’s usually get deleted quickly as is. Likewise, with the exception of spam, a lot of newly downvoted answers seem to be the ones that are poor or incorrect guidance, but not answers that should be deleted.

Comment: What about the many answers by newer users, which their owners delete after one or two downvotes? Won't that make it easier for trolls to target them for downvoting rep? That's a question by the way, and I don't have the answer.

Comment: @JeremyCaney again my concern is not to delete answers. Based on my experience 98% of the new answers that get downvoted are automatically deleted by the OP. In 3 years I probably casted 10 delete vote to answers but more than 10000 downotes. I simply consider the deletion as a factor for the badges or for the extra Rep considering that if you downvote an answer then it's for sure a bad one so the OP will delete it because no one want to keep his *bad* answer visible.

Comment: @hat the earned reputation is a small amount, if a *troll* want to do that, he will get tired quickly because he will not become rich with it. Doing random/trivial edits would be better for him as they will get +2. Also if a new user post a good answer he will for sure get few upvotes to counter such downvotes

Comment: I got the message. Starting with downvoting this post, as it does not show real research and is lacking convincing arguments. -1

Comment: I think badges and reputation gains are the right way to encourage downvoting. Also, one could easily tune your system if necessary. For example, "get extra `+X` reputation if `X` or more downvotes are cast after you" and/or "loose `-X` reputation if the **unedited** A/Q gets double as many upvotes than downvotes (minimum `X` upvotes)".

Comment: Your idea of a downvote queue is very good if we can keep it to a manageable size, but what if an answer or question exits the queue for a series of 'looks good' votes?. Should the downvote reversed? Should the downvoter be penalized? What if there are more than one downvote? This point, if resolved in a satisfactory way, could be a very powerful weapon against revenge downvotes that skips the script check.

Comment: @Steve no we should not reverse the downvote or punish the downvoter. After all anyone is free to downvote for any reason. The queue will simply bring more eyes and will be helpful especially for very bad answers that anyone will agree it deserves a downvote. Of course, if a good answer is downvoted and will appear in the queue it may also gather more upvotes since it's a good one and will counter the downvote that can be a revenge one.

Comment: "With this, new users will no more be afraid of the -1 and will be more clever to target very bad answers since there is a good chance for a deletion and another +1"--maybe, but unfortunately perhaps also more clever to simply target answers that have one or more downvotes already, without even reading a word of the answer, with the same goal? Hence this could have a serious detrimental effect. One can almost imagine the gold rush to get points, with a fusillade of downvotes as the marauding mob, spotting a down-voted answer, smell blood and sense another kill!

Answer (score 216):

While this answer touches on a similar subject to other answers, I decided to post it because it comes at the issue from a different perspective.

I come from a videogame design background. Your site, though hardly a "game" definitely falls into the "gamification" category to the extent that it is using reputation, badges, and level-ups that unlock new privileges. And there are some really really really well known things about how gamification works and how it creates incentives (and disincentives) for behavior. And near the ***top*** of that list is the compulsion to raise one's "gamer score", no matter how theoretically "meaningless" that number is. Part of that compulsion has to do with the social nature of the number -- user knows that ***others*** will see the score. And part of the compulsion has to do with the power of the names you give things -- in this case it's *called* reputation. So no matter how jaded many experienced users feel over the supposed meaningless of reputation, it's really important to remember that the mere names of things ***have*** been shown to meaningfully affect user behavior.

So that brings us to downvoting and the -1 reputation cost for doing so. To me as a professional game designer, my first reaction was "I can't believe they actually have to *ask* the question of why they don't get 'enough' downvotes!" Because of *course* if you lower my score for doing so I'm not going to want to do it! You're *telling* me I'm doing an unwanted thing! And then quadruply so by having the thing you penalize being called my "reputation" -- now you're literally telling me I'm being a bad person! Some, of course, will feel immune to the power of the words, and some will have already accumulated so much "gamer score" that they feel free to go spend some -- but I've seen right in the comments of some of these answers that even many folks who have huge scores still "feel that niggling pain" about the supposedly-nearly-meaningless -1 rep.

So this is kind of a "Well here's your problem, Maam" situation. Obviously the -1 rep got introduced for some reason, or seemingly to solve some problem, in the past. And maybe it solves it. And maybe the problem it solves is worse than the fact that there aren't enough downvotes for curation. But anyway that's what the problem is, and it isn't likely to go away while downvotes feel penalized rather than rewarded.

The way we would (try to) handle an intractable problem like that in a videogame would be:

- First, remove the problem feature: so in this case eliminate the -1 rep for downvote.
- Now, try to rebalance using "other means" to prevent the problem that -1 rep used to solve. Some combination of:
  ... perhaps a higher threshold for earning downvote privilege
  ... perhaps make downvotes less visible to create less social stigma (what if the lowest score a question *visibly* had was 0, at least until you reached some higher privilege level to be allowed to *see* downvotes)
  ... lower the amount of social stigma by lowering (or removing) the amount of penalty that users receive for getting downvoted, ***especially*** newer users. (I'm a lot nearer to being a new user than some here, and I can tell you that any time I've put an answer or a question and it got downvoted it, I've instantly deleted it -- don't want the rep hit, keeps me from getting the next privilege, etc.)
  ... If removing -1 rep leads to a massive increase in downvotes, then perhaps change the "net value" of downvotes to bring them in line, e.g. a downvote has half the value of an upvote on the overall score.

So just some thoughts from a game design perspective, and I hope they help some.

Edit: Another brainstormy idea that occurred to me after reading some of your comments (e.g. gold sink), is that if you thought this was important enough for a substantial change, then here's another "classic game design route" you could go down: INTRODUCE A NEW CURRENCY.

- Let's say that in addition to "reputation" I also earn "social capital".
- How do I earn it? Easiest prototype is I earn a point every time my reputation reaches a new high (so essentially 1 point of capital earned for every point of reputation, but no double-earning by going down-and-back up). If you wanted to get all designy-a-new-systemy you could have the social capital come in different size clumps when you tier up, etc, but that might require an overkill amount of extra attention.
- So now *social capital* becomes the thing I *spend* to do things -- to downvote, and probably to set bounties as well, and perhaps there are other "consumable" activities.
- VERY important is that "social capital" is NOT visible to other users. Where as reputation is my "experience level", social capital is now my "gold" -- my toys to play with.
- This accomplishes a couple of important psychological things: (a) It destigmatizes spending (I'm no longer losing REPUTATION), (b) By hiding the social capital values it removes any *social* reason for hoarding the points -- nobody is impressed by how many points I have because they can't see them, and (c) Conversely and equally importantly, I now have a psychological *incentive* to spend this -- because otherwise it's just sitting there doing nothing! Not potentially impressing anybody, just nothing!

Obviously that's a somewhat significant amount of rework of your "game economy", but it does aim straight at the stated problem so I thought I'd share it.

The irony that this will apparently be the most widely-read answer that I ever give on Stack Overflow is not lost on me :-)  But hey, I'm just barely an engineer but I'm extra very much a game designer so what the heck.

Comment: As a game designer you've presumably heard of the term "gold sink", this could be a purpose for the -1, a way of combating inflation? Sure... seems a bit far-fetched, but, food for thought

Comment: While I don't agree with all of this, it does bring a fresh perspective. To the best of my knowledge, the 1-rep cost still exists in order to prevent tactical voting. A higher threshold for the privilege is something that could bring more issues: why should the downvote be so exclusive?

Comment: I similarly appreciate the sentiment like E_net4 but I am also not sure about some of these. The downvote privilege is *already* higher. This actually causes problems. If people have association bonus (+100 rep on all sites), they get the ability to *upvote* everywhere but not *downvote*. This leads to positive feedback loops when visiting the Hot Network Questions: people visit and they can only upvote questions (or do nothing). So popular questions gain even more popularity *even though they might be a bad for the site they are on*. Happens fairly often.

Comment: Your last point - limiting *displayed* negative nett post scores to 0 (or was it -1?) - was actually tried a few months ago. It was very unpopular, as it was perceived to 'hide' the Community's judgement on poor posts.

Comment: The -1 cost is surely something that people consider, especially if they have a low rep number. But for everyone above say 5k, the cost is so small that I think it should realistically not play any role at all. I upvoted this post mostly because of the general insight into the motivational value of naming things.

Comment: @Trilarion I still consider the -1. I have 14k rep. I think twice before downvoting any answer to be sure I think it's worth the -1.

Comment: @Trilarion: "should realistically not play any role at all." And this is the disconnect: people have this annoying habit of acting like… well, humans. Messy, squishy, organic, fallible wetware that is exceptionally prone to both acting and reacting based on a combination of both emotion and rational thought with a highly variable balance, even with the same individual, depending on a wide (and wild) variety of factors. StackOverflow's largest collective sin is, in fact, not expecting humans to act like humans.

Comment: Got a couple more ideas from reading your comments -- added them above.

Comment: I can confirm that the -1 reputation deters me from downvoting, because I have ~1750 reputation and I want to reach the 2k privileges, but I don't gain reputation that fast.

Comment: @Trilarion - Literally the sole reason that I don't downvote more is the -1 rep. I want 10K and I'm not going to reach that if I downvote every bad question or answer that I see.

Comment: @SomethingDark The -1rep is only on answers, not on questions. So you can downvote every bad question that you see.

Comment: @JoelAelwyn "StackOverflow's largest collective sin is, in fact, not expecting humans to act like humans." This could mean many possible things. Not sure what is meant exactly? But on the other hand we all act like humans, we are. It's just that some humans act different from others. Some like it tidy and neat, others just love the chaos. More or less SO works, even though there are quite some problems. Where is the collective sin again? I don't think there may not be one, but I just want to understand exactly what it is?

Comment: @Trilarion - I know that, and I'm not sure why I typed "question or" at all, nor do I know why Stack Overflow doesn't let you edit comments after a certain amount of time, but my point still stands. The -1 is literally the only thing standing in the way of me downvoting everything that deserves it.

Comment: @SomethingDark I could say that this Q&A here probably aims more at bad questions than bad answers or that there is still a daily vote limit that would limit you or that even with some downvoting bad answers activity you would still achieve 10krep for sure (a bit later maybe), but instead let me say that I see your point. For you the -1 is real, for me it never really was an issue. It's a compromise between different goals and not a really bad one, but it definitely also has downsides.

Comment: I would give Brian’s answer +10 if I could. Possibly +100. He suggests how to fix downvoting, explains WHY, and provides a framework (gaming) in which to understand the suggestions. Although I’d like to see @Brian provide a few references, he’s done more than just suggest removing the reputation hit.

Comment: @Trilarion Fair enough, I'll try to clarify. First, an infamous but highly relevant movie quote: "A _person_ is smart. _People_ are dumb, stupid, panicky animals, and you know it."

More particular to this situation: your statement about "should" is perfectly true for a rational actor. However, humans are, on the balance, _not_ rational actors in any general sense. Specific people, under specific circumstances, certainly are.

The "sin" I was speaking of is expecting people to act like idealized rational actors, rather than… well, people.

Comment: Closely related but slightly more pointed would be "Designing for Evil": https://blog.codinghorror.com/designing-for-evil/. In fairness, it is mostly the SO developers who have to worry about actual evil, but the community, if it is bouncing ideas around, should definitely be taking the range of human proclivities into account. Which is, admittedly, *hard*. Evidence to date would certainly tend to indicate that if there is a "magic bullet", nobody has found it yet. But the point @Brian was making is that the current failure modes are entirely predictable as a natural result of gamification.

Comment: @JoelAelwyn Yes, definitely it's an argument. And while we are at it, we could even start paying people for downvoting with rep. That would surely encourage people even more. But if we assume that users are sometimes evil, we then also have to take into account revenge downvotes. Basically saying that not all downvotes are good downvotes and that maximizing only the right kind of downvotes should be the aim.

Comment: @JoelAelwyn There is also the famous Hershey's Kiss experiment where they saw surprisingly large differences between a very small price and offering something for free. It's described in [Predictably Irrational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictably_Irrational), which I would like to read one day. Having said that, I think that the cost of -1rep for downvoting answers doesn't play any role for me, because the personal satisfaction I get from seeing the score of bad answers reduced outweighs the cost for me by far.

Comment: "no matter how theoretically "meaningless" that number is."

Stackoverflow reputation isn't meaningless, it has real world implications in terms of employment.

Comment: Great answer. I'm no game expert, but I was also impressed by the naivety the OP has shown in their statement. We cannot simply ignore the game aspect of all StackExchange sites. "As everyone knows we rate content, not the users". This is simply false. We may not like it, but we *are* rating users, and also being rated by them. To deny that is to ignore the essential difference between StackOverflow and all other now defunct developer forums that used to exist in the past.

Comment: I love this answer, but I disgree with the notion that I would spend (social capital) points simply because others cannot see them.  *I* can see them!

Comment: @Michael It's not that you would spend them because others cannot see them, it's that you *won't* spend them because others *can* see them (and because it's linked to your "reputation"). It's a very sensible concern to have, "why would I do an action that visibly lowers my reputation among my peers? Seems clearly like I should do everything I can to *increase* that number! So obviously the system doesn't want me to downvote, so I will never do that!"

Answer (score 89):

There is an anecdote that, when [Michelangelo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelangelo) was asked about how he made [the statue of David](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_(Michelangelo)), he responded

> "It is easy. You just chip away the stone that doesn't look like David."

When there are 1000 new questions posted per day (in watched tags), then there may be 10 that are actually worth *reading* and *investing time* (and *upvoting*, for that matter). 90 of them may be these "Mehh... dunno..." questions (with no votes). And the remaining 900 are objectively, utterly crappy (often do-my-homework ones), or plain, obvious duplicates.

The latter should be downvoted and closed. Now I could waste 8 hours per day with just reading crap and downvoting.

But why should I do this?

The obvious answer *should* be: "In order to create the best, curated programming Q/A in the world!". Yeah. But... no. Seriously. There's another cultural reference that might fit here, quoting the summary of [Der Zauberlehrling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sorcerer%27s_Apprentice) from Wikipedia:

> The poem begins as an old sorcerer departs his workshop, leaving his apprentice with chores to perform. Tired of fetching water by pail, the apprentice enchants a broom to do the work for him, using magic in which he is not fully trained. The floor is soon awash with water, and the apprentice realizes that he cannot stop the broom because he does not know the magic required to do so.
>
> The apprentice splits the broom in two with an axe, but each of the pieces becomes a whole broom that takes up a pail and continues fetching water, now at twice the speed. At this increased pace, the entire room quickly begins to flood. When all seems lost, the old sorcerer returns and quickly breaks the spell. The poem concludes with the old sorcerer's statement that only a master should invoke powerful spirits.

Stack Exchange called the brooms that bring the flood. Namely users that bring questions - bad questions, and too many of them. They told us to be "nice" and "welcoming", splitting the brooms in half: Users see that homework questions are solved, and the askers (and of course, those who write poor answers to poor questions) are rewarded, attracting even more of them.

For me, the answer to the question of *"What can we do to encourage downvoting?"* is pretty simple:

**Do what is necessary in order to reduce the number of cases where a downvote is *necessary*!**

---

An aside: At least for me (personally), the "-1  rep" that is incurred by a downvote is not relevant. Not at all. I'd be happy to donate even 10000 reputation points to anybody who is stoic and diligent enough to dig through a pile of 1000 crap Q/As, just to downvote them accordingly.

The discussion about how this problem could be solved is probably beyond the scope of this Q/A, because most attempts for solving this would be the *exact opposite* of what SE has been doing in the past few years.

Unfortunately, there is no old sorcerer to help us out with that.

Comment: My observation is the same for the tags I watch. The volume of garbage is truly overwhelming. Downvoting is not going to work. Nothing except drastic measures will have any effect.

Comment: What about filtering the garbage away? Everything that doesn't end up with a score of at least +2 could automatically get deleted after a month or so. The difficulty would then be reversed in finding the content that should actually stay (and that still might be a difficult task with all that garbage floating around).

Comment: @Trilarion But that doesn't change anything about the amount of low quality content in active question lists and queues. Cleaning up a month later does not make it any easier to find good quality content today. Because the amount of low quality material flowing in remains unchanged.

Comment: @Trilarion A low-traffic post is not automatically garbage. That's why Roomba is selective with score in it's metrics. A post has to be bad, not in-lack.of-good or meh.

Comment: @Gimby and Scrattle: Sure, the threshold for high quality content is also tag dependent. The only thing I wanted to say is that auto hiding/deleting everything except for the good things is a bit different from trying to delete/close all the bad things. Currently we are trying to better identify the garbage, but what we really interested in is not the garbage but the pearls. I'm most interested in the pearls, in the garbage only insofar as I need it identified as such. Maybe it's the same really ... not sure.

Comment: @Trilarion I previously suggested that posts from new users are default pending when submitted and only go public when released from the queues where the posts are already in. I found it only natural since all posts in First Posts are from new users, and they seem to be the ones that are in most need of improvement. But.. I don't think it gained a lot of support.

Comment: @Scratte It could be that Meta is not completely consistent, sometimes rejecting things that it would approve at other times. It could even be that the reception depends on details of the proposal. Or it could be that the likely reaction of the company is included in the feedback. If its chances are deemed hopeless, the support could be smaller.

Comment: @Trilarion and Scaratte : That's exactly what the anecdote of Michelangelo referred to: We cannot identify and carve out the good questions by downvoting the bad ones, because there there are too many of the latter. Or to stick with this analogy: That's like carving the statue of David out of Ayers Rock. (Another aspect, unrelated to that, is that for each individually, it's often *hard* to identify *good* questions, but *easy* to identify *bad* ones, but that's something that cannot be adequately unfolded here in the comments...)

Comment: @Scratte The approach that you described sounds interesting. *Very* roughly: Put all posts from <1k users into queues. These queues would have to (somehow) be *organized by tags* (a COBOL expert cannot judge the quality of a JavaScript Q/A). These queues could be worked off by users who have silver/gold badges in the respective tags. This would be a "dispatching" mechanism, analogous to "peer reviews" of publications that are (supposed to...) ensure the quality of scientific works. (For me, this sounds very promising - I'll have to look whether this has been proposed/discussed here already...)

Comment: (@Scratte Found an entry point https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380450/display-review-queues-based-on-watched-tags (with many links to related ones). There are some shortcomings, and some of them are pretty old - I'm considering to take the risk and bring this up again, in a similar (more elaborate) form, but would have to read some of the answers in the related/linked Q/As first...)

Comment: @Marco13 I think you will have to lower the reputation level to under 50 :) So just work with the current First Posts queue, because there too many new Questions, and not enough reviewers :) Maybe also keep in mind that even if you gain support, there is still a long way to make Stack implement it.

Comment: @Scratte We have "Low Quality", "Triage", and "First Posts" queues, and there's *considerable* overlap between these. I'd even say that, to a large extent, they are basically the same. We could add a "Short Posts"-queue, a "Mainly-Code-Posts"-queue, a "Probably-Homework"-queue... just to distract from the fact that the influx of crap is just too darn high. Refactoring the queues and the underlying mechanisms and goals is overdue. I know, it won't happen - that's one of the many reasons of why I'm no longer contributing to the main sites - but we could pretend to still have hope for SE.

Comment: @Marco13 You're right of course. I completely forgot about those. I was thinking about the Close and Reopen queues, which (especially the Close queue) would probably be reduced quite a bit. I'll look forward to reading your feature-request :)

Comment: @Trilarion - good point, but, many times when I face a problem and Google the error message, etc. I find an answer that is perfect, and solved my problem, but has a score of 0 (until I upvote it!).

Comment: @MarkStewart Yes, it's all about differentiating good from bad content. There are millions of questions with score zero. We should work on bringing them to either +1 or -1. But we may not have the manpower. Just encouraging downvoting isn't exactly the goal. A question at -3 is already dead and does not need other downvotes, while some questions also deserve upvotes. The discussion here is a bit limited in that regard. Everyone should just start looking at zero scored questions and vote on them. That would be a very helpful thing.

Comment: Exactly! It's all SE's fault. Just let them go down in fire!

Comment: @baao Quoting from https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/ : **The fastest way to kill any Q&A; site is to flood it with low-quality questions.** (Assuming that there was some irony and sarcasm in your comment: Whose fault is it then? The veterans? The newbies? Or does it have something to do with a wrong strategy, wrong priorities and wrong decisions?)

Comment: @Marco13 totally agree with you

Comment: I don't feel 90% of questions are crap. Very far from that. I would say the opposite, 90% of them are quite good. Of course most questions are not relevant to me but if a question is clear, then it's good. Concerning duplicates I think it's not a problem unless you are the one paying for data storage. A duplicate simply is an alias to another question. If you wanted to achieve collaborative single source of truth you would build wikipedia not a QA website. SO is just a pile of well indexed duplicates that build a web of word-links so any user can find an answer using its favorite search engine

Comment: The goal is to capture most request, which is why the bigger the word-web is, the better for the end user (not the one asking or answering, the one looking for an existing answer via the most accurate words he/she could think of).

Answer (score 86):

I'd like to see downvotes make a more serious difference to OP. I still don't understand how a downvote only counts as -2 reputation where an upvote is +10. I've seen numerous bad questions/answers with more downvotes than upvotes but OP has almost no incentive to remove them because they are still gaining reputation (1 upvote plus 4 downvotes is still +2!). I say almost though as having more downvotes than upvotes does put you further away from a tag badge. I believe changing the downvote penalty to match the upvote reward would result in a lot more self-deletion of bad questions/answers.

I'd also like to see a delete review queue so that questions and answers that hit a certain number of net downvotes are automatically reviewed for deletion in the same way that answers flagged "very low quality" or "not an answer" are. This would hopefully improve the rate at which bad questions/answers get removed from the site and at the same time make it less likely that the -1 **penalty** for downvoting will be permanently deducted from the downvoters reputation.

Comment: I totally agree with matching downvote/upvote cost for answer will be helpful. Or even making downvote change _more_ than upvote. Like +10 / -20. But in case of questions - wouldn't it make people afraid of asking. There are quite many cases when a good question is downvoted, and only upvoted after it has a good answer from a person who really understood the question (there are even badges to reward such answers). Maybe downvote on question should still have smaller impact, like +10 / -5.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev I'm torn on that. I understand your point but I see downvotes on questions as a good way to make posters think more before/while they write a question. And as long as the question eventually has more upvotes than down, the poster will get positive rep from it.

Comment: @Nick I'm not sure this is a good idea. I've removed my one Question. I've been told it was a good Question. It had +4/-2 when I removed it. It got the downvotes long after I posted it and they seemed to come at the **same** time as another spurious vote. I removed it because I don't want to risk a Question ban. Making people more afraid of posting is probably not going to help. I'm less fuzzy about my Answers, because I have a lot more of them. But if I'll get a -1 (-10 reputation point) just because someone doesn't like my avatar or lost his keys, then I'll be less likely to Answer too.

Comment: @Scratte Unfortunately there's not a lot that can be done about capricious downvoting, especially of questions, given that there is no penalty for that. I had all 3 of my questions downvoted within a minute of downvoting someone else's answer. Instituting a penalty for downvoting questions might help that, but I would only want to see that happen if there was a better way (e.g. a delete review queue) to ensure that bad questions end up deleted so that people who downvote bad questions don't get penalised for it in the long run.

Comment: Another point: Some people are reluctant to downvote, because they don't want to hurt other users. I don't think it'll make people downvote more, if they feel they're applying more "hurt". The goal is not to bring down reputation, but to put a better score on the post.

Comment: [This answer in another feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356178) is very relevant and serves as a counterargument to increasing the penalty for receiving a downvote. If downvotes apply such a large penalty, they will no longer be just about rating posts. Reputation harming is a relevant factor that many users complain about.

Comment: @E_net4likesdownvotes, Scratte posters always have the option to delete their post. I just feel that if more people think an answer is bad than think it is good, then the poster should not get positive reputation from that post. Users shouldn't have the right to complain about getting no rep gain for a post voted +1/-4. And if we have a delete review queue, then we can increase the penalty for downvoting to the down voter (which should hopefully reduce capricious downvoting), because we know that truly bad posts will end up being deleted, resulting in no long term effect on the downvoter.

Comment: @Nick We'll have to agree to disagree here, because such a powerful downvote, although we can argue its usefulness, is also very problematic and does not help on _encouraging them_. It disincentivises answers, increases the perception of harm, and even goes counter the concept of the lifeboat badge. At this time, I would rather be in favour of dropping the penalty to the receiving end.

Comment: @E_net4likesdownvotes that's the great thing about meta. We can have these discussions and all air our points of view and vote up/down and it means nothing, because they are *just* our opinions. I think this is a good question because it's bringing out discussions like this. But yes, we are going to have to disagree on this one. To me, a poster writing a good answer has nothing to fear from downvotes, regardless of the penalty. And if it stops some people writing poorly thought out, rushed answers, I don't see that as a bad thing for the overall quality of the site.

Comment: The missing comma made me read the above as "Scratte posters". I had no idea there were a category of posters named after me ;) But.. if you read the post linked by E_net4, this makes it real "weapons of war" against a user, seriously enable users that intentionally want to hurt others. Do we want to limit users that downvote to that group? Especially bearing in mind that those users are probably already downvoting for this exact reason. This Question is about encouraging more users to downvote, not penalize those that receive them.

Comment: @Scratte sorry, was trying to reference two users in one comment but of course it wouldn't let me. I guess I haven't encountered these users who intentionally want to hurt others. I don't downvote answers that much unless they are really bad (and I think a downvote will help get them deleted) because I don't see the point when there's almost as much penalty to me as the person who posted the answer.

Comment: Yes, when you put the argument like that, it makes sense. But maybe the argument/idea should be revised. The "penalty" to you is to make you think about what you're downvoting, so you don't just go on a thoughtless spree. Especially when you're a new user and have a bigger percentage to lose, assuming that new users are less likely to make an accurate call. That penalty is completely unrelated to the penalty to the user of the post you're downvoting, and I don't think it's good to make the comparison. (If you want to compare, the extreem is: Why do **I** not get a +2 when **I** upvote?)

Comment: @Scratte that's why I'm happy to increase the penalty to downvote (as long as there's a delete review queue to help get rid of bad posts). It will make people think more about downvoting, help reduce intentional targeting, and if the posts are truly bad, there will be no long term penalty to downvoting (since you get the rep back when the post is deleted) meaning that it shouldn't discourage people from downvoting bad posts.

Comment: Yes, it is important to outline the difference between the cost of casting a vote and the penalty when receiving one. I also would not agree with increasing the cost of downvoting, for similar reasons. It would do the opposite of encouraging downvotes, making the privilege feel more exclusive to high rep users, and also attract this sentiment: _"The downvoter is evil, they even had to pay rep to downvote my post, what a «expletive»!"_

Comment: @Nick,"... I see downvotes on questions as a good way to make posters think more before/while they write a question." But that isn't what happens is it? Sure it might chase away some bad questions/answer, but it chases everybody else away from contributing as well. What downvotes does now is make people afraid of asking/answering questions, *not more careful* at it. And you will always have a majority of new users swarming around who just don't care. They don't get their answer here (it's quickly downvoted/deleted irregards of quality), they'll just go somewhere else or just go without.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev Most users have a reputation of 1, truer for some tags than others.  Users with low rep don't sufferfrom a severe downvote penalty.  I take notice on the Arduino tags.  Most Arduino questions deserve a downvote/close vote because of the abysmal average quality of questions under this tag.  Many OPs there have never cracked the Arduino source code open or done a google search... or just 'wants the codez". But I do agree that the downvote -2 vs the upvote +10 is a horrible disparity because -4/+1 is still positive gain for what is probably a pretty crappy question.

Comment: @E_net4likesdownvotes just re-reading my comment to you last night, it was a bit flippant. I apologise if it caused offense, it was not my intention.

Comment: @ouflak There's no real reason to let the possibility of downvotes prevent anyone from answering. If posters are careful to answer questions that they really know the answer to (rather than just throw out code with a "Try this!"), the likelihood of the answer being downvoted is small and if the answer is well written, it is far more likely to get upvoted.

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe it would be fairer if the split is -5/+10. But I do like that a post needs many downvotes (indicating it's truly bad and not "maybe bad") before the downvotes start to really impact the author. If we're talking about downvote/upvote trickles where a single upvote can really make an impact then the system simply still needs to do its work more. If not enough votes will be cast to set the record straight... yeah well that's the actual problem then, the reputation impact is just a side effect.

Comment: I doubt that the suggestions in this answer will help to encourage users to downvote more. However, this is one of the few suggestions that I would highly approve. I find it very difficult to make sense of the -2/+10 system: it should be -10/+10. Also, surely, posts with a negative score should be reviewed (this would help to eliminate the possibility of the misuse of the voting feature and, also, remove bad posts for good). I would like to see the suggestions that are made in this answer to be converted to an explicit feature request.

Comment: @user9716869 If these changes were made I would downvote more. I see little point in downvoting where the penalty to me is almost as high as to the poster and there is little prospect that bad answers will get removed by OP because of the imbalance in penalty/reward. The implementation of these suggestions would resolve that issue for me.

Answer (score 51):

When you vote on mostly answers, you get a pop up message saying "You haven't voted on questions in a while, questions need votes too". This was [introduced](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/05/06/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/) in response to a problem of questions not being voted on.

The exact same logic that lead to that pop up being introduced seems to apply to downvotes, implying that it might make sense to add a "you haven't downvoted in a while, low quality content needs to be downvoted too" pop-up.

Comment: Do we have any reason to believe that such nag tooltips actually work to modify behavior, or are they just annoying to everyone?

Comment: I often get these tips on the WorldBuilding site and indeed, they made me to pay more attention to the questions, since they are in fact are what is responsible for so many great answers I upvote there!

Comment: @CodyGray Do you have any reason to believe any suggestions here *actually work*?

Comment: @BartoszKP They work for me....

Comment: @CodyGray I can admit that I've blocked all of these nag tooltips in my adblocker (along with "if this answer helped you please upvote the questions and answers"), so they definitely don't work on me

Comment: @CodyGray: My anecdote doesn’t answer your request for evidence, but I’ll note that the pop up has been effective at reminding _me_ to upvote more questions, at least. I’m still at a large deficit, but it’s something I’m more mindful of each time I get that pop-up. Otherwise, I often find myself forgetting to upvote questions unless a) I have the question too, b) it doesn’t yet have a (useful) answer, but c) it’s well-framed to solicit useful answers. That’s a tall order. With the prompt, I’m more likely to reward thoughtful and interesting questions, or to upvote answered questions.

Comment: fwiw: I'd rather not see a pop-up to remind me to vote for a question.  If I upvote an answer, then in my opinion the question should automatically get an upvote from me.  Likewise, I think flags and downvotes should be correlated.  If I downvote, I should, at a minimum, also have to either select a generic category (spam, doesn't answer the question, etc) or leave a comment.  Similarly, if I flag an answer, it should count as a downvote.

Comment: Every time I open up my PHPStorm there is a Hint of the Day popup.  It's super easy to close/ignore, but honestly there are times when I read it and then opt to see the next one, and the next one, and the next one before starting my work day.  If we can deliver a spoonful of advice/grooming that benefits the whole community, this might be an effective/painless way to do it.  The challenge may be getting everyone to agree on what should be said in the popups and how to condense the advice in 3 sentences or less.

Comment: The 'nag' tooltip did work to modify my behavior. When I got the tooltip 'questions need upvotes too' it made complete sense, but I hadn't really thought about it prior.

Comment: This would be a great feature to see and would be fairly trivial to implement. The nagging reminder does a good job; if nothing else, it at least encourages me to find a post to downvote so that I stop seeing the nag.

Answer (score 49):

I don't downvote as often as I probably should.  One of the major reasons is a situation that happened back when I was a fairly low-rep user (I'm sure I'm not the only one this has happened to).  Rough timeline of events:

1. I saw an interesting question and provided an answer.
2. My answer quickly earned a negative score.  Several commenters mentioned my answer was unclear and potentially misleading.
3. I re-read my answer with a fresh mind and discovered that it was indeed quite confusing.
4. I edited the answer to resolve the problems and improve overall quality.
5. The downvotes remained even though the problems that inspired them were gone.

This changed the way that I looked at downvotes.  Downvotes are only a judgement of the quality of an something at a *specific moment in time*.  Downvoters have the ability to retract their downvotes if the question/answer changes, but this doesn't appear to be something that's actually done very often (I'd love to see real stats on this).  I usually comment instead of downvoting if it feels like there's *any* chance that the question/answer might get improved to resolve the problems.  I don't want to be a drive-by downvoter.  I usually only downvote if something is clearly unsalvageable or in violation of the rules.

IMO, it would be useful if downvoters get some sort of notification when something they downvote gets edited.  I'd be more than happy to retract a downvote when a question/answer is substantially improved.  I have no reasonable way to know when this happens, though.  A simple note that I could click to re-visit a question/answer and re-evaluate it would make me 100x more likely to retract downvotes that no longer apply (bonus points if the link takes you to a diff-type view that highlights the changes).  This would reduce the likelihood of drive-by downvoting and would make people - or me, at least - less hesitant to downvote.

If downvotes are important enough to notify the poster, then I feel like an improvement to a downvoted item is important enough to notify the voter.

Comment: "*IMO, it would be useful if downvoters get some sort of notification when something they download gets edited*" there is an opt-in option for this if you follow the post. You'll get notifications for changes to the post. But also some noise in terms of comments and, if you follow a question, new answers as well.

Comment: yeah, basically the follow feature is a middleground for this kind of notification. Forcing everyone who downvotes to receive edit notifications would be quite heavy-handed, allowing people to opt in to receiving notifications is much less intrusive.

Comment: "*If downvotes are important enough to notify the poster*" downvotes are *barely* forwarded to the recepient. You can sort of guess when you've been downvoted but not with high accuracy and not in timely manner. If you get a downvote *and* an upvote, you'll get a `+8` notification for rep, because it's a `+10` but then it factors the `-2`. You don't get notifications for negative rep. If you look at your notification score, negative rep is also usually tucked away and you only see the positive. Unless you've *only* been downvoted, you might have a `-2` then.

Comment: @VLAZ - In my experiences, the signal/noise ratio is way too low when following posts.  I also wouldn't want every post I've downvoted cluttering the "Following" tab in my profile, burying the *useful* content I'm following.  It would be more user-friendly to be a separate mechanism.  Regarding downvote notifications, it's much easier to detect downvotes if you have the "view up/down votes" privilege, sometime I forget not everyone has that.

Comment: @bta from my experience...[you probably shouldn't worry about downvoted posts swarming you with notifications](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398537/what-can-we-do-to-encourage-downvoting/398689?noredirect=1#comment777894_398681). Although, I would like to be able to select the type of notifications I get for a post. For example, I often don't care about new comments being posted. I may follow a question solely for the answers, for example.

Comment: Oh, I forgot one "fun" interaction with negative rep and notifications. If you get, say, a `-12` rep (e.g., removed upvote, added a downvote) you won't get any notification. If you then get an upvote, also wouldn't get a notification, since you're at `-2` net change now. So, you need to gain enough rep to *overcome* the negative and go into a positive net score before you get any notifications. So, for example, if two of your answers get unaccepted, that's `-30` total, and you'd need at least three upvotes + another rep gain to get a bubble. Only opening the inbox shows a bit more information.

Comment: If you decided to rework your answer you could simply remove the old one and post a new one. After all it is a different answer. You can delete answers whenever you want. All we ask is that you do not delete an answer and repost the same content to avoid downvotes. That is an abuse and can be flagged for mods attention.

Comment: @KevinB: A possibly useful heuristic to maybe notify only when they might want to retract a downvote: notify after edits *and subsequent upvotes from other users*.  Possibly to some threshold like non-negative, or more likely just one or two upvotes after an edit.

Comment: @Dharman - That only works if the answer is completely different, not if it's a modified version of the original (which I'd argue is more often the case).  Also, you'd lose any *upvotes* the original one might have had.

Comment: @PeterCordes - That's a pretty good idea.  IIRC, we used to have a badge for editing a low score answer/question and then it receiving enough upvotes.  That implies the plumbing is (was?) there, it would just mean notifying the downvoters as well.

Comment: Completely agree with this, the whole fix the problem requires those who have down-voted to come back assess and re-vote but a lot of time they don't. I personally try to do this but if a specific tag receives a lot of questions it can get lost in the ether. A notification of changes plus a "bump" (although this could be mis-used) would go a long way.

Comment: An opt-out for notification of changes after a downvote could be easier to manage. The way bookmarking works in Chrome is like this - one click sets the bookmark & also shows you a "remove" button in the same go, so its just one extra click.

Comment: I shared similar sentiments [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189275/228525).

Comment: Here's an SQL query on data.stackexchange.com that returns how many answers are downvoted and edited but the downvotes are never retracted: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1255728/how-many-downvotes-are-not-retracted-after-the-answer-is-edited

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 - I don't think that query will find posts that have downvotes but an overall score >= 0.  It also doesn't differentiate between downvotes that were cast *after* the edits were made as opposed to *before*.  I'm not sure that we can get this data with a SQL query alone.

Comment: @bta Sorry, I'm a beginner at SQL.

Comment: @bta Very good idea, best so far IMO. It should be a popup on the site. Something that goes away when the question/answer is opened or 'x' is clicked, but not something that can be disabled through a setting. No e-mail notification though.

Answer (score 41):

I've upvoted 5,897 times on SO and downvoted 88 times. I downvote when I think it makes sense and don't feel bad about it. I think the reason I upvote so much more than I downvote is that I rarely try my hand at moderating the site, going through new questions, or trying to answer questions for its own sake. Instead, I usually visit to look up the solution for a specific problem I have, and sometimes I browse interesting questions for the fun reading material. This means I mostly see a lot of the already-curated, already-high quality content on the site. And that deserves upvotes!

My guess is that there are a lot of users like me who use Stack Overflow in a way where changing the incentives won't cause us to downvote more often. And I'd guess there are users who love the moderation side of things who will mostly downvote, no matter what you do.

I'm absolutely not saying this isn't an important aspect of the community to think about. Neither am I saying trying to adjust the incentives surrounding downvoting is a hopeless endeavor. This is just a thought that popped into my head reading the question, and I thought I'd leave it for smarter and more experienced community members than myself to consider.

Overall, I'm grateful you're thinking about this and excited to see where it leads!

Comment: When arriving from a search for a specific problem I can confirm that the content is usually well curated and upvote worthy. But you answered also a lot of questions. I wonder how you found them? Usually by looking at unanswered questions in my favorite tags in order to find something that I want to answer I see lots of really bad contributions that would deserve a downvote. Did you not?

Comment: The thing, though, is, that the reason you're seeing high quality, upvoted and upvote-worthy content is that others have previously down voted the low-quality stuff away from those posts. So whilst there may be many people using the site like you do, to keep them happy and able to use the site like that, voting is crucial to sift out the good from the bad.

Comment: This post is part of the problem... 88 down-votes, no wonder there is so much garbage on the site.

Comment: @Trilarion A lot of my answers are from times I couldn't find a good answer to a problem I was having. So when I found a solution on my own, I came back and left an answer on a relevant question. Sometimes I happen to see a question on the front page I can answer, but that doesn't happen particularly often.

Comment: @Adriaan For sure. I get that the fact I can find so much good content is because other users are doing the hard work of moderating the site, and that includes downing garbage posts. I'm grateful for that. There's only all much time in the day, though, and I think my time is best spent doing other things. There are other things in my life that have even more value to me, not that moderating SO is a low-value proposition.

Comment: "Sometimes I happen to see a question on the front page I can answer, but that doesn't happen particularly often." I guess what this question here asks is if you happen to look at the front page and you spot a question that is obviously bad, just consider using your downvote powers on it. It's (hopefully) not asking anyone to spend extra time that they do not want to spend, just to actively use that downvote button if you happen to see bad content while being on SO anyway. I guess that's something we all could do. If upvoting comes naturally, maybe downvoting could become so too.

Comment: @Trilarion That's a good point. I'll glance at posts on the front page more often to upvote the good questions and downvote the bad ones, even if I don't have enough time to answer or edit.

Comment: @Lankymart, "...the problem... (only) 88 down-votes, no wonder there is so much garbage on the site"
That's not fair. The vast overwhelming number of people who visit, or even contribute to, this site will never take part in moderating in any meaningful way. Most won't even register. There are plenty of SE sites where moderation duties just aren't that much in demand (because of the culture, low-traffic, etc...). We shouldn't blame users for their lack of interest in moderating. It's rare that someone truly wants to do it, and from that group there are subsets who take part in different ways.

Comment: @ouflak All excuses, giving a down vote when a question is clearly low quality or poorly researched doesn’t require moderation, just needs you to click on the down arrow occasionally. There is far more to moderation than that!

Comment: @Lankmart, Not excuses. Just simple demographics. People are different. That's life.

Comment: @Lankymart As I wrote in my answer, I do downvote when I come across a post that warrants it. I just don't use Stack Overflow in a way that ends up with me seeing many of those posts.

Comment: Basically I upvote when the code works, I dont need to understand it. Cant downvote when it doesnt work.

Comment: @user3226167 and that is also representative of another problem; you switched your brain off, handed all responsibility for solving your problem over to a man on the internet, didn't understand the response and [pasted the code straight into your app](https://www.theverge.com/tldr/2016/5/4/11593084/dont-get-busted-copying-code-from-stack-overflow)

Comment: I have 3% downvote and honestly I think most of them come from downvotes on questions/answer that should have been removed anyway (so useless downvote in some sense). @Trilarion downvoting will never come naturally, it's against our nature (as humans).

Comment: @CaiusJard You link points to an article of a guy copy pasting some xml, I'm pretty sure everyone on earth can understands xml.

Comment: "downvoting will never come naturally, it's against our nature (as humans)" Just look at the question, there are people will almost all downvotes and not only some but thousands of them. I kind of doubt that downvoting is completely against our nature (or some people just are not very bound by their nature). @cglacet

Comment: @Trilarion the question exposes two extreme examples, but it also says the downvote ratio is 1 to 7.68. Extremes will always exist. People don't like receiving downvotes, so they wont downvotes others. There is nothing you can do (well maybe [not nothing](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Milgram_experiment) but close). Maybe you can influence some people, but the vast majority will keep on responding emotionally (empathy). We should celebrate the fact that this ratio is low and all agree that downvote is not the answer. That's why I really hope that question is not about how to tweak downvote only.

Comment: @cglacet "the downvote ratio is 1 to 7.68" Maybe that is exactly the ratio of good to bad content that people find (on average) when visiting SO. Alone this ratio is not proof that people don't like to downvote. Maybe people who do not curate but just search for knowledge really find more good content than bad content and just vote accordingly. I certainly don't like to receive downvotes but still roughly 1/3 of all my votes are downvotes. I like to downvote (kind of I think).

Comment: @Trilarion Yes, you are right, that ratio doesn't prove anything. My remark wasn't related to that ratio, that was just my opinion. That's just based on my personal feelings (on SO) and observations in real life. People do not like to make negative remarks to others, even if that would be beneficial to everyone (including the "target" of the remark). I don't even think it's some kind of hypocrisy like many people think, I really think that's our empathy that often prevent sending negative feedback to strangers. When you know someone it's a bit different, but on SO we interact with strangers.

Comment: @Trilarion I also think it's very cultural so I might totally be wrong because I'm drown in my own culture (like most of us). In France, negative feedback means you failed, so downvotes I think are often perceived as a failure and are therefore not an enjoyable experience. But I know that in some culture people are more used to negative feedback and take distance with it, which I think is a good thing, but I think it's impossible (or just very hard) to change how people will receive feedback. And in my opinion the way you receive it determines how you treat others.

Comment: @Trilarion That would be interesting to poll people on that "What do you do when you receive a downvote?", "How do you feel when you receive a downvote?", "What is your down/up vote ratio?". I'm pretty sure there would be a very high correlation between how people feel and how they vote.

Comment: @cglacet I'm sure that nobody likes to get downvotes really. I could go and find the most upvoted persons here, find something to criticize (to err is human) and downvote because of that. It might sting, but it would be nothing compared to getting more often downvotes than upvotes. Only contributing negatively (score-wise) should be a devastating experience. In education for example I would readily vote to abolish grades and focus more on the achievements instead. But this here is not a programming school but a library of knowledge. In order to keep the knowledge you have to throw things away.

Comment: @cglacet It's personal for sure because your name stands right to contributions and your rep is affected, but on the other hand somebody has to tell the truth at some point and that is often that many contributions are not useful for the knowledge library. Downvotes increase the signal strength. Maybe if all contributions would be community wiki, then it would sting less. Only then we wouldn't know how to distribute rep. But I guess that downvotes on community generated content wouldn't hurt really. I'm thinking about using community wiki on meta from now on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216938/discussion-between-cglacet-and-trilarion).

Answer (score 34):

The focus of most of what I am saying here is on the downvoting of *answers* but much of it is equally applicable to *questions*. With that said, I would also like to separate  **encouraging** downvotes (as Dharman's title has it) from **facilitating** them; the importance of this distinction will hopefully become apparent as (or *if*) you continue read this post.

Let us separate downvotes into <strike>five</strike> six categories (one could merge some, or even add more):

1. **Revenge Downvotes**: Horrible things! This category needs no explanation and most (if not all) of us will have experienced them. *We don't want to encourage this.*
2. **Spiteful Downvotes**: Huey asks a good question. Louie posts a good answer, and it gets a few upvotes. A bit later, Dewey posts another good answer and it gets more upvotes than Louie's; so, in a fit of pique, Louie downvotes Dewey's answer, just to 'even up the scores'. *We don't want to encourage this (and it is the normal reason given for downvotes on answers **not** being 'free').*
3. **Constructive Downvotes**: I have both received and cast a number of these, in circumstances where an answer is *potentially* good but has one or more readily correctible flaws. Such downvotes should, IMHO, never be anonymous and always be accompanied by a comment explaining the nature of the flaw and, better still, how to fix it. When the criticism has been duly addressed, the downvote should be removed (and even possibly replaced with an upvote). *We **do** want to encourage this.*
4. **Tactical Downvotes**: We see an answer that needs to be deleted, so we flag it as NAA or VLQ (or, if we have 20K+ reputation, we vote to delete it). 'Throwing in' a downvote on top of that delete flag/vote can often expedite/facilitate Community-powered deletion; further, if the tactic works, then the reputation cost of the downvote will be refunded. *Do we want to encourage this? Those of us who are active in site curation probably do, but there could be deeper issues here that Diamond Moderators and Staff may want to raise.*
5. **Critical Downvotes:** A subject matter expert (SME) comes across a well-presented, (highly) upvoted answer and, after some examination, discovers that the solution is *fatally* flawed. What should that SME do? *I strongly believe that we **do** want to encourage downvoting in these cases, even if an alternative (better) answer is posted by that SME.*
6. **(EDIT) Purgative/Curative Downvotes:** [How did I initially 'forget' this category? It is the most important!] Answers that are just plain bad (but do not meet the criteria for NAA or VLQ flags), or those that are posted (especially by high-rep users who should know better) on *unsalvageable* poor questions: duplicates and typos, mostly. *We **most certainly do** want to encourage these!* This category is most likely the focus of Dharman's question (feel free to correct me, of course).

So, how do we **encourage** downvoting for the 'wanted' categories without **facilitating** downvoting for the 'unwanted' ones? Removing the reputation *cost* (to the voter) would probably do both. Increasing the reputation *penalty* (to the poster) would certainly make the Category 6 and 5 votes more effective, and would probably encourage them; it could possibly also help with the Category 4 cases, as it may more often induce self-deletion, and thus save both Community delete votes (a limited resource) and Review Queue time.

Category 3 could possibly be encouraged by removing the voter-cost for non-anonymous downvotes (i.e. when a constructively critical comment is made at the same time); however, removing voter anonymity is a BIG can of worms to open.

The effects of any facilitation of downvoting (i.e. cost-removal) in Category 2 could be removed by preventing downvotes on answers where there is such a 'conflict of interest': i.e. I can't downvote another answer to a question that I have answered, or, conversely, I can't post an answer where I've already downvoted somebody else's - but that then messes up the downvote-plus-better-answer option for Category 5.

Apologies for the train-of-thought nature of this post, and for the fact that it may ask more questions than it answers; however, I hope it brings some useful thoughts into the discussion. And, as a parting thought: I think we need to emphasize **educating** people about the usefulness and *positivity* of downvotes, rather than concentrating solely on tweaking the mechanism(s).

Comment: I'm not sure I'm with you on 6 "or those that are posted (especially by high-rep users who should know better) on poor questions". I agree that it's not preferable to have answers on closable Question, but I can't bring myself to downvote a really good Answer. Some Questions are also not closeable, but just poor, sitting there with a -3 waiting for someone to try their luck with a [Lifejacket](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8841/lifejacket) or perhaps even a [Lifeboat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8842/lifeboat)

Comment: @Scratte Yeah, it's not clear cut. Posting answers to *known* or *obvious* dupes is one thing (and a whole different discussion, here on Meta); but I would place those who post an *answer* when a comment would do in much the same boat. The full "Typo" close reason ends with, *"...this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers."*

Comment: @Scratte To make matters 'worse': I've been 'told off' by high-rep long-timers both for posting an answer that should have been a comment *and* for posting a comment that should have been an answer. Meh.

Comment: It's funny how that goes. The opinion of one user, however seasoned, should not exclusively determine policy. One could even argue that it's bullying. If it's two seasoned users, the argument is really between them, with you as the hostage.

Comment: @Scratte Anyway, I've edited my Category 6 to make it a bit clearer what I meant. Thanks for pointing out the flaw - and you can (obviously) retract and reverse your downvote, now! ‎

Comment: Category 4 is actually OK. As Shog once put it: if you're willing to delete vote it, you'll certainly want to down vote it."

Comment: @Adriaan Indeed! But things could get a bit 'sticky' if one were to cast such a tactical downvote, expecting the post to get deleted, but then it doesn't. Your vote's then locked in and you don't get the expected refund. (But that, of course, shouldn't matter at all.)

Comment: Or, to solve category 2, downvotes could only cost if you've got an answer on the question too (even if you post the answer afterwards). That way, you can still downvote if answers are bad.

Comment: How about red alert downvotes? A simple benign example is when example code in an answer contains a hole, like SQL injection. It is not a reason to downvote the answer because often it is just a simplified form to illustrate how something works, but ho boy will the red alert trigger downvotes and even meta posts. But there is also the next level: actually potentially volatile questions. Writing a virus, exploiting a security hole. Red alert red alert, we may have a question of someone wanting to write malware... but so what? We don't vote on the user.

Comment: @Gimby If no SQL expert, but wouldn't your first case fit into Category 3? If the "hole" can be fixed, then downvote until it is, then retract/reverse that vote. A deliberate and malicious post, though, as in your second case, would probably warrant a Category 6, and maybe even a flag - but that's really another issue, I think. [ Maybe a Category 7?]

Comment: We do _not_ want to encourage downvoting for reasons which merit closure. That's what the closure is for. A question is not poor because it is off-topic, it's just off-topic.

Comment: You forgot no. 7: Downvotes for no reason! You got no comment or hint why your question is bad. Sometimes people don't really read what you were asking. They read it very quickly, don't really understand the problem, and downvote it. It doesn't matter if you have a code example or not.

Comment: @AdrianMole *Revenge Downvotes* how do people know who downvoted them (unless that is made obvious in comments)

Comment: @blackgreen We don't know; but we can often tell when we get them; and sometimes we may *suspect* who's doing it.

Comment: Another category is "Errors" - That is, people who think they are acting what you labeled 3, 5 or 6 but they're actually just wrong themselves.  I see a fair number of those.

Comment: @testing Downvotes are *always* for a reason.  You may not be told what the reason was, and the reason may be good or bad, but it's never correct to say the downvote happened "for no reason".  (This applies to most things, not just downvotes.)

Comment: @Brilliand: I don't agree. Voting is subjective, because people are subjective. Today I received a downvote where I answered my own question. In this question the only solution I could come up with was reinstalling the tool. No other user provided a solution and this solves the problem. What is wrong with this answer? Nothing. There is no "real" reason. Sure there is a reason: the user doesn't want to reinstall and doesn't see that a solution. I also didn't want to reinstall, but sometimes there is no other option. It is a valid answer and voting is subjective. It isn't objective as you state.

Comment: @testing So you know the reason for that downvote: someone thought your answer was bad because it was a lot of work to solve something that "should" be easy (and possibly also because you didn't explain what was causing the problem).  Calling that a downvote "for no reason" wouldn't be correct at all.  In fact I could see myself downvoting such an answer - the reply "just reboot/reinstall/close and reopen" is a standard technical support guess that frequently makes the problem go away, but doesn't *actually* fix it.  I think that counts as a "Purgative/Curative" downvote.

Comment: @Brilliand The reason for the error is a bug in the software. Nobody posted a solution/fix for the problem. Perhaps this is solved in an update. But what should I do? Don‘t post the solution, which solved my problem? I understand your viewpoint, but you don‘t quite get the big picture. The error is for sure not easy replicable, but it is/was there. And since this is/was a bug, there is nothing you could do - other than updating or reinstalling. The solution is therefore not bad. And I never expierenced the bug again. This was my last option - not my first one.

Comment: @testing I haven't seen your answer so I don't know the details, but IMO an answer recommending to upgrade your software should at bare minimum state which version the problem was fixed in.  (In any case you haven't made much of a case at all for adding a "no reason" downvote category.)

Comment: @Brilliand: I see that we agree that we don't agree. Here again you don't want to understand my point nor my issue. Do you think after solving my problem I will try to replicate the error with each update? Only to post that? Should I fix the programm by myself? I have done everything I could do and you would downvote it. Thats the reason why downvoting should not be encouraged, because people not always understand the problem and only vote subjective. That was only one example - I could bring more on the table. But I see that you don't accept any arguments and therefore the discussion is over.

Answer (score 26):

**Remove vote counts from my public profile.**

It might seem pretty minor, but the fact that any random person on the internet and potential employer can see how many downvotes I've cast has discouraged me from casting them fairly strongly for quite a while.

Some might believe having a bad upvote-to-downvote ratio implies you're overly critical, which isn't exactly a good trait. Although I would argue I just have high standards and I've spent quite a bit of time moderating, which tends to skew one towards more of the downvote-worthy content on the site.

I don't really mind the combined number of votes cast ("X votes cast") on one's profile, but what is even the point of breaking the vote counts down into number of upvotes and number of downvotes for all to see?

Comment: I am not sure why would you share this information with your employer. It's true that they are not necessary but they do come in handy from time to time. This should not stop you from voting. Casting downvotes means you are caring and you want to support this site. It does not mean you are overly critical.

Comment: Your up / down vote activity is not visible to the public only you.

Comment: @Lankymart The vote count (total up, total down) [is actually public](https://cln.sh/XcBCpb.

Comment: @Dharman A (potential) employer could see it, and anything else that's public on your profile, if your profile is linked in any way to your real name. This would include using Stack Overflow Jobs.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I am sorry but either you are a little bit paranoid or you have a bad employer who is constantly spying on you instead of organizing work for you.

Comment: @Lankymart Yes, the **vote count**. This is what this answer is about.

Comment: @Dharman I don't think my current employer would care about that at all, but some potential (future) employers may look for, and try to draw conclusions from, whatever data they can find about me online. This seems especially relevant to someone who has little to no social media presence (which limits the amount of data points).

Comment: @Lankymart  You can see the vote count for each user. The screenshot in a previous comment is from your profile.

Comment: @yivi Didn't know that.

Comment: I wouldn't mind seeing this implemented. The site has a history of hiding information which could be used to judge the poster of the content inappropriately (i.e. the acceptance rate), and [judgments on Meta over users' vote ratios](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389014) do happen.

Comment: @dha When you use Stack Overflow Jobs, you don't even have an option **not** to share that information. The concerns raised here aren't about your current employer monitoring your actions. It's rather about getting filtered out from the potential interview candidates based on the information publicly available. That's a valid concern.

Comment: Funny enough, I have a professional reputation for being critical, if not outright difficult—but that’s not reflected in my Stack Overflow voting ratio. Despite using my real name, I haven’t really considered that my Stack Overflow behavior might impact my professional reputation. Thinking about it this way motivates me to downvote more frequently, less my customers and coworkers think I’ve grown soft.

Answer (score 25):

The problem is when users create their account, we have a badge that encourages upvoting. It's the Supporter badge, and it was the first one I earned.

Since downvoting is a privilege that comes much later, it's hard to then shift users towards downvoting again, because they think that upvoting is better.

People think downvotes are a mean thing to do to someone, essentially.

A way to fix this would be to put a paragraph about downvoting in the [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), because currently there is **nothing** that says

> When you see a bad post, **downvote** it!

That would be a **step in the right direction**.

The next step would be to change the tooltip around the downvote button. For instance, instead of:

> This questions does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

We could do:

> This question could definitely be improved, either by users like you or by the OP.

The final step:

New contributors think downvoting is some sort of **attack** on someone, which it is not. The reason they think this is because they lose reputation and get punished, and they don't want others to suffer.

A new contributor could lose only **1** reputation when they get downvoted, but if they get 3 downvotes, then after that they lose the usual **2** rep. This way, questions that aren't completely horrible can be edited by the OP, since he isn't being punished *as* much.

The final step is definitely not perfect, but if we get rid of the downvoting stigma for new users or contributors then downvoting would happen when it should.

Ok, the final final step :)

We could remove the 1 rep cost of downvoting **only and only if**:

1. You have downvoted *before* you posted an answer, and then optionally posted an answer afterwards.
2. You have downvoted because the answer is bad, and then leave.

**However**, we remove 1 rep when:

1. You downvote an answer when you have an existing answer on that question.
2. You downvote an answer which later gets upvoted by 3 or more people. (I don't know about this one)
3. You downvote an answer which later gets upvoted by a dupehammer **or** a moderator. (Also not sure about this one).

I think with these three steps, downvoting will lose the stupid stigma it is around, and finally that down button will be pressed.

Comment: I hadn't considered that.  Maybe a second stage "Welcome!" page that discusses how important the downvote action is once you get the privilege.  It would probably just be clicked through though.

Comment: @zero298 Ya, it would be skipped through :(

Answer (score 24):

Perhaps we could get a number of free answer downvotes each week, instead of each downvote costing -1 reputation every time.

So if we downvote fewer than a certain number of answers each week, we don't lose any reputation, but any subsequent downvotes would then cost -1.

Comment: For users with low rep this could increase the number of downvotes. And it would be a compromise between keeping the cost and not keeping the cost.

Comment: I've considered this, but as @Trilarion has mentioned, it would result in having to micromanage downvotes. A better solution would be to use a ratio of downvotes to upvotes. If upvote I cast outweighed the negative impacts of two downvotes, I could downvote whenever I found it useful, without getting close to the limit. Downvoting answers that appear above yours on questions you have answered should probably count negatively irregardless.

Comment: @ecc521 I like that too. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 23):

- By removing the personal reduction in reputation incurred from downvoting answers. Questions? Oh, hey, I gladly downvote bad questions. Get that garbage away. Answers... Well, I've already lost quite a bit reputation (considering how much I've received). I always wanted more reputation, to gain more privileges, so I could better help contributing to the site. The latest 365 days, though...
- or... by giving me a daily fixed income of reputation. Realistic? Not so much.
- By having the SE company stop insulting me by claiming that downvoting is rude.

I'm aware that removing the -1 penalty opens us up to some pure incorrect downvoting, like targeted downvoting. This is an issue. Therefore, I cannot say that this **must** be done.

Comment: *By having the SE company stop insulting me by claiming that downvoting is rude.* --> when/where this happened?

Comment: @TemaniAfif The past year. They’ve claimed that Meta is a rude and unfriendly place. Downvotes has been marked as a source of «unwelcomeness» for new members, and the community has been blamed for being so rude.

Comment: (Also: thanks to whoever encourages me to be a more active downvoter. :))

Comment: None of the concerns about being rude or unwelcoming have had anything to do with downvoting. It is neither of those things. The voting system is *not* part of the "welcoming" initiative: that has focused on reducing the number of rude comments, etc.

Comment: @CodyGray No, it’s not part of the welcoming initiative, but people do take downvotes as an unwelcoming feature of the site, and so other means are established to counter that.

Comment: I feel highly unwelcomed when I come across a low-quality post that has not been downvoted, despite how many times it's been viewed. It's as if my peers are refusing to help me out by curating or otherwise indicating low-quality content, thus forcing me to look at it anew.

Comment: I can relate to the first point. I've almost never downvoted bad answers before reaching 3k reputation.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Daily; It’s happening daily

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, yes. There are even some bad answers (at the time they were written too) with 50+ net votes. I’ve downvoted some of those.

Comment: You can use a budget so your total reputation points never go down: 1) Make a list of answers you want to downvote 2) After the first upvote in any given week spend some or all of it on downvotes (from the list), but not so many that [the balance](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week) goes negative (search for your user name on that page - the number is the change in the current week (starts Sunday at 00:00:01 UTC))

Comment: @CodyGray Some people do feel unwelcomed because of the downvotes: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180692/why-do-i-receive-downvotes-when-i-am-genuinely-trying-to-learn . I'm not sure why you think that what you feel is a valid counterexample :)

Comment: @BartoszKP I suppose we can't cater for everyone's feelings, right? :) A line needs to be drawn on which feelings are justified and which are not so much.

Comment: @CodyGray typically SE uses ["unwelcoming" or "personal"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction/398469#comment776459_398469) when describing downvotes (therefore linking it to the welcoming initiative) and give a *"use downvotes but really, don't really use downvotes"* style answer (i.e. a lot of confusing, mixed answers/comments like the one I linked which starts as "downvotes are good" and ends in "downvotes will always be personal"). Also, removing "doesn't show research" from the downvote tooltip is a pretty clear ***stop using this*** in my eyes

Comment: @E_net4likesdownvotes But the claim was not whose feelings are "justified" (btw. feelings do not need justification, they just are) but whether they exist or not. My link proves such feelings do exist, regardless of other people's feelings.

Comment: @BartoszKP Sure, and we are not denying those feelings. On the other hand, some feelings are more reasonable than others in this context. I don't think we can cater for all of them because of their dichotomous nature.

Comment: Downvotes is part of why people feel unwelcome, but SE's effort to make people feel more welcome seems to thus far have been limited to what users say.

Comment: As for unwelcoming, I've seen bad questions get down voted to -1 or -2 and closed. And when I look again later they've got -4 or -5 down votes, _with no further explanation._ Piling on = "...and don't come back!"

Comment: @ourmandave as a negative score will automatically delete the answer/question (and close it if it is a question). If this is an issue the answer is not "downvote less" its "provide better options" (when your only tool is a hammer everything looks like nails situation). I personally see the opposite anymore though - answers & questions getting upvotes to counter the downvotes people are giving to help curate. Its worth looking at in SEDE but difficult to query for (would have to be time delimited by voting groupings)

Comment: @E_net4thanksyou Not sure who are "we". And I'm not talking about feelings being reasonable or not or what you can cater for or not. I'm referring to the statement by Cody Gray: "None of the concerns about being rude or unwelcoming have had anything to do with downvoting." which is simply untrue.

Answer (score 20):

This question, I think, misunderstands part of the psychology and workflow of voting in a couple of respects.

This part especially stood out to me:

> Why so many users demand that the downvotes be accompanied by an explanatory comment yet nobody demands an explanation for the upvotes?

I think the answer to that is reasonably obvious:  Most users post an answer that they think is a good one.  So when they get an up-vote that's in harmony with their own view of their answer.  In their own mind there is no mystery and so it's natural that they don't have a question about it.  They thought they posted something useful and someone rewarded them for it.  When they get a down-vote, they are confronted by something they potentially don't understand.  They thought their answer was good and someone is saying it's not.  Even if the community is sure the answer is poor, the person who posted acts from their own perception.  It's natural that they want to understand why and how that discrepancy between their view and the actual result happened.

The other aspect of the voting ratio, I think, comes from how people use the site.  If I come in looking for an answer for a specific problem, I read the question to see if it matches my situation and then start reading answers.  Usually I stop when I find an answer that deals with my problem, which is usually toward the top of list when ranked by votes.  That's great - curation has helped me.  I'm reasonably likely to add an up-vote to the ones that I used, signaling to anyone coming later that I read them and found them useful.  I'm not likely to keep reading other answers - potentially bad answers - at the bottom of the list just to down-vote them if they're bad.  I'm already moving on to the next task in my real job once I get my solution, I'm not staying to read every answer to the question just for the sake of further curating.  The answers most worthy of a down-vote are probably already at the bottom of the list, so I never read them.  To put this more shortly - **Good curation leads to fewer down-votes on bad answers by reducing the number of bad answers that are read.**  I'm not going to down-vote it if I don't read it.

As for potential improvements related to this issue:

- For questions with multiple answers, consider putting the lowest ranked answers into a queue for possible deletion *even if they have positive net votes* after a certain amount of time.  This would make the down-vote more powerful as a curation tool since you don't necessarily need to beat out all of the up-votes to impact the disposition.  The exact flow for this would need to be carefully designed - You could have cases, for example, where the answer to a question changes over time so a new answer with updated information is relevant even if it takes a while for it to match the score of an older answer that was itself good at the time that it was written.  In addition to killing of genuinely bad answers, this may also discourage people form posting repeat answers as we see often, i.e., in the late answer queue.
- An answer that is down-voted *and* flagged, at least in certain flagging categories, should not have the reputation loss. Flagging in those categories should actually automatically down-vote.  If you're putting your name down with a flag, you're probably not revenge voting.  No need for a penalty there to discourage bad behavior.
- Separately limit the number of daily up and down votes.

Comment: Yes - the reason why people get "upset" at downvotes on their answers - or their questions for that matter - seems completely obvious to me. A downvote means "something about this is wrong or bad". Which means "to be right or good, something about this would have to change". OK, so what would have to change? On the other hand, an upvote is saying "this is already right or good". We don't have to be told what makes it good - the thing that makes it good is "it" per se. It's already there.

Comment: <irony>Why the downvote?</irony>

Answer (score 14):

I was a manager for a long time.

One of my standard "aphorisms" was: *"Encourage the person; discourage the behavior."*

i.e., make encouragement personal, and discouragement tightly focused on **only the specific behavior we want to deprecate, avoiding applying value judgments to the person exhibiting the behavior.**

I learned this from teachers (I've had a lot of them in my family).

YMMV, but it worked for me.

Translated to SO:

**UPVOTES:** Adds to reputation, and makes the question/answer more visible and prominent.

**DOWNVOTES:** Has no effect on rep. score; for either the poster or the downvoter. Only affects the specific post; reducing its visibility and prominence.

Might be worth a shot.

I'd also like to see a requirement for an explanation for the downvote, even if anonymously. I've had perfectly good questions downvoted, and have no idea why. I sincerely want to fix the issue, but cannot see it. An explanation would be helpful.

Comment: I do think this is a good idea, however, we'd need to make sure there's actually a downside to being downvoted. As it currently stands, this change would still have downvotes affecting the visibility of the post and the users ability to post future questions/answers, but without clear messaging about this fact being presented to the user receiving the votes, i fear they'll just be ignored since the user isn't visibly losing anything for them. I don't think removing the rep parts of downvoting would have any real impact on people's overall rep.

Comment: There are of course edge cases, for example, i'd all of a sudden have close vote privileges again on meta.se, but i think for the avg user they aren't downvoting enough or receiving enough downvotes for it to really have a major impact.

Comment: I'm sure there are a lot of things that would need to be considered, like upvotes only affecting rep after 0.

I'm just sharing a bit of wisdom that I learned from someone else. Like I said, I applied it in my work, and it was effective.

I do think that it is important to explain downvotes. It's entirely possible that some downvotes I have received were petty (I have a hard time kissing rings, and that doesn't always win me friends), but I am sure that most had some legitimate reason, and it's a shame that I had no idea what the reason was.

Comment: Perhaps the discouraging factor is a negative score on the "work", the post itself. I imagine even high reputation users want their post scores to be positive.

Comment: Another helpful thing, would be to have downvoters notified when the post they downvoted is edited. That way, for example, if they downvote a post because it was not clear enough, can remove the downvote when it is clarified. I think that it would be a shame to have very good questions or answers ignored, because their first draft was downvoted.

Comment: _I'd also like to see a requirement for an explanation for the downvote_. I agree, but there is a problem with this. It's more time consuming for some people, and for a very bad post, there would be repeated comments.

Comment: @KevinB - Isn't the lack of an answer enough of a 'downside'?  When I tackle the question queue in a community other than SO, there is a clear trend:  Bad questions have no answers or up-votes, and bad answers have no up-votes.  Good questions have answers and up-votes, and good answers have up-votes.  There are very few down-votes.  But still a powerful motivation to write good questions & answers.  Like my mom always said: "If you don't have anything nice to say, just don't say anything at all. They'll still get the message.":-)

Comment: @Tracy No, not as long as bounties exist, and as long as rep continues to be skewed heavily toward gaining rep regardless of how crap your contributions.

Answer (score 13):

**SO says: you should not downvote**

It's not about that little reputation point (although it might add up for lower rep users who are very serious about voting a lot).

But *in principle* it still is a penalty! The reputation system implies that good deeds give you badges and rep, while bad deeds make you pay. The underlying signal of that penalty point, is that SO doesn't *want* you to downvote.

*Possible solution: rep as currency rather than performance counter*

Of course (?) rep should be seen more as a currency than just as a reward counter, but there is so little you can spend it on! Maybe there should be more ways of spending this currency. Let people use their rep to buy hats, colored mark-up, other gimmicks, or maybe even more useful features. Instead of automatically handing out more site functions when people gain rep, let them buy it (if they want). That way you can get more into the habit of spending your coin, or just letting it sit in the 'bank'. It will feel more like just another spending if you downvote. You could even put a price on upvoting too. Let the money flow!

**Newcomers say: you should not downvote**

Another thing is being welcoming to new users. This mainly applies to questions.

Being downvoted is a big fear for new users, often expressed in the questions in the form of "please don't downvote me" (sometimes appended with a request for feedback).

This tells me that those users do take it personally, or at least too seriously, and I get the impression that downvotes are part of what makes SO unwelcoming to newcomers. As you say, we're downvoting content, not people, but still there is this perception. That perception needs to be tackled somehow, otherwise there will be an eternal ping-pong game between downvoting poor content and being welcoming, even though they shouldn't be mutually exclusive.

*Possible solution: delayed downvotes, or delayed **effect** of downvotes*

Sometimes I see questions that don't even seem that bad. Even though they might be hard to answer you can at least tell that someone tried to ask a good question, but nevertheless such questions easily got 2 or 3 downvotes in very little time. New users who don't have experience with the speed of SO will come back after a couple of hours or a day, only to find their question is at -4 and is pretty much invisible to anyone.

I don't know exactly how this would work, but maybe there could be, sort of, preliminary downvotes. Like "Downvote this question if it won't improve in 2 days". Of course anything that postpones downvotes may result in some shock if the question goes from seemlingly 0 to -5 at once, two days after it was posted, so there still has to be a way for OP to know that their post was received negatively and needs improving.. Tricky.

Anyway, automatic improvement detection is probably hard to build, but maybe a reminder will do. I'd love to be able to bookmark questions and get some reminder about them on my next visit. 
That way, I can suggest improvements or ask for clarification and postpone my downvote. If I get notified the next day and the question is improved, it's a win for every party. If it isn't, I can still cast a downvote. At least the asker has been given the chance to work on their question.

Sometimes I've used the 'favorite' feature for that, but it feels wrong. I've also bookmarked specific questions in my browser, but that feels cumbersome (especially since I'm working on different machines). Since both don't really work well, I've been refraining from voting when questions were 'not great but not very bad', hoping that OP would fix them up in response to comments.

*Possible solution: emphasize that it's not personal*

If someone revisits their question and it received a couple of downvotes, maybe show a notification explaining again that it's not personal. For example: "Downvotes are not personal. They usually indicate that your question is lacking details or doesn't reveal the research you have done. Turn the tide by adding relevant details to your question."

Also, let them undo the rep loss for instance by self-closing their question as duplicate of another question.

Comment: *"Downvote this question if it won't improve in 2 days"*: That would complete defeat the purpose of preventing answerers to waste time on bad questions. If I don't see the score of a question until two days later, I have to read all questions in the new question feed and can't use judgement of others to focus on questions that are worth the effort.

Comment: @BDL Yeah, that part is tricky. Of course the downvotes themselves are valuable feedback. It's just that, if you managed to attract 3 downvotes first, there is virtually no way to turn that around. Your question drops in the rankings, people who downvoted won't revisit it, and others often won't even see it. I think it's that effect that make posted dread downvotes, and makes votes feel sorry for downvoting (and not voting as much as they would).

Comment: I always wonders why SO displays both, the score and the content creators name, so prominently next to a contribution. I think that makes it very personal. Maybe the combination of content-creator-score should be break up into content-creator and content-score to make it less personal.

Comment: It has nothing to do with unwelcoming. I still get downvotes on question with no obvious reason. Hey I don't know how I should improve the question if you doesn't write a comment. Perhaps the person had a bad day and thinks through downvoting they can get rid of it.

Comment: "preventing answerers to waste time on bad questions"  -- I might suggest that /good/ answerers don't waste time on bad questions.  /Bad/ answerers -- those that rapid-fire low-quality answers to low-quality questions in the hopes of gaining reputation -- are wasting the time on the bad questions.  Of course, even if I'm right, that doesn't really help solve the problem...

Comment: @BrianA.Henning They have to read the question and assess whether it's worth answering. Sure, that typically won't take as much time as actually answering it, but in the current setup, the visibility of a question is lowered after some downvotes, so the first couple of downvotes protect others against having to make the same assessment.

Comment: I like this answer because it seriously considers the effect that downvotes have on _other new users_ who are considering contributing. The anxiety new users feel about this may well be driving away good contributors, leaving mostly contributors who don't care about being downvoted — thus making the problem _worse_, not better.

Answer (score 11):

I disagree with the premise of the question that we need to be encouraging people to downvote more.

The question states that there eight times as many upvotes on Stack Overflow as downvotes, as if that were necessarily a bad thing. I don't think we should be aiming for 50% upvotes 50% downvotes.

Comment: *I don't think we should be aiming for 50% upvotes 50% downvotes.* --> true, we should be aiming for 20% upvotes and 80 downvotes

Comment: @TemaniAfif, And such an approach would probably wipe a lot of good content from low traffic tags right off of the site. And it would crush some of the beta sites.

Comment: no it won't, the good content is far from being the most present one on the site. We get *one* good answer within at least 50 answers (and even more). After all, we don't give blind downvotes but we do if for bad content. If we only had good content, then there is no reason for downvotes but we are far from this.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, you are using some numbers here in your comments. From where they are? I was told above what the problem with lack of downvotes is in rare-tags area (with low traffic). Is it so? Can it be potentially fought (like really, if there is little people, can you improve anything)? What impact change is going to do on high traffic tags (e.g. [tag:c#]) ?

Comment: @Sinatr they comes from my experience and the tags where I am active.

Comment: Interesting fact from corporate teams: "The average [praise to criticism] ratio for the highest-performing teams was 5.6" ([source](https://hbr.org/2013/03/the-ideal-praise-to-criticism)). So the 8.0 ratio seems about right to me :)

Comment: You are right Flimm, there is absolutely no basis shown for what the ratio should be or why the current ratio is problematic. All that follows is pointless conjecture. This community is so caught up with removing content it forgot how to create it. A large reason why the majority of high frequency content providers have largely stopped contributing.

Comment: @TravisJ Wait high frequency content providers or high quality content providers?  We have a shortage of the latter; I don't think we have any shortage of the former.

Comment: If it wasn't clear, I am talking about those who answer questions. Asking them, while important, doesn't necessarily have to be qualitative; on the other hand, answering them always have to be qualitative, for the most part. If you are unaware of the overall situation, perhaps doing some research would be beneficial.

Comment: Having had a lot of time to mull it over I sort of agree with this answer now... except not in the way this is argued. What I disagree with is that encouragement is needed to downvote. What is needed is encouragement to vote, in general. If downvotes are warranted then that should naturally lead to more downvoting happening. It sends out the wrong signal to hammer specifically on downvoting, that is what makes people on Youtube go "See!? Bunch of toxic aholes". Correct wording is more important than ever.

Answer (score 10):

Let me first clarify that I am all for encouraging downvotes. That said, I have concerns about couple of suggestions in other answers;

- There's a suggestion here that you should get a badge or reputation if your downvotes result in certain number of posts getting deleted.

95% of my downvotes result in the post getting deleted, mostly roomba'd. But I always keep this in mind that we are instructed to steer clear of downvoting to trigger roomba. Downvotes should be merely used based on quality of the posts  <sup>1, 2</sup> . Let's assume a bad question which has a quality answer. Considering the thread altogether, one decides that it should be deleted. IMHO, the right path is casting close votes and delete votes later. While the suggestion above encourages downvoting the question and the *quality answer* to trigger (abuse) roomba.

<sub>1. [Clean-up by downvoting? A ridiculous user experience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307009/clean-up-by-downvoting-a-ridiculous-user-experience)</sub>

<sub>2. [Downvote in order to be able to vote to delete. Is it acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351969/downvote-in-order-to-be-able-to-vote-to-delete-is-it-acceptable)</sub>

- There's also a suggestion about removing *'-1 rep cost of downvoting an answer'*.

The issue here is with people abusing their downvotes. If we remove the cost, people would downvote their competitors (other answers on a post which they've posted an answer to). There's also an issue of revenge downvotes, which without that penalty, would rise to the roof.

#### So What can be done?

As I said, I have concerns about these suggestions, but I don't think they are completely out of place. We do need to encourage downvotes instead of penalizing users for using their downvoting privilege (same as the way we encourage upvotes with badges like <kbd>Supporter</kbd> and <kbd>Sportsmanship</kbd> or other ways which are mentioned in the other posts).

I think if we could increase the level of monitoring on revenge downvotes and other abuses, it'd be helpful to move forward with the suggestions above; but it is much easier said than done. I very much liked the restrictions suggested by [Temani Afif](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398546/6461462) at the end of their answer, which I quote them here.

> *I know there is room for a lot of abuse, but we can add some*
> *restriction like applying this* logic (M--'s comment: giving back extra reputation when a post gets deleted) *to only users under 5k or limit*
> *the earning of the extra +1 to only +X per day, etc.*

---

---

As I referenced Temani's answer, I want to point out a major issue with one of their "proposals": *'pushing all new negative answers to a queue where we can review them'*.

I believe we already have enough review queues and adding yet another one while there are many issues with the current ones (e.g. triage), doesn't seem great. Let me point out that in a perfect world (world: SE communities), that would not be the worst idea. But beside the issue with other queues, opening a new one for downvoted answer has a prime difference with VLQ queue. Generally, one does not need domain knowledge of the subject to evaluate low quality posts. On the other hand, a user usually needs to be subject matter expert (or at least familiar with the issue) to fathom the problem with the post and decide whether to downvote or not. Good or bad, we do not still have any restriction on the reviews you can attend based on your knowledge of that tag (i.e. reputation, in the context of SO). So pushing downvoted posts to a queue doesn't seem to be appropriate, at least at the moment.

Comment: to extend your last point: we need to add restriction based on knowledge and tag activity like I explained here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393400/8620333 .. reviewing a downvoted answer or a closed question requires you to have at least a minimum activity in the related tag.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Agreed. As I said, "at least at the moment". But it seems you are one step ahead of me :)

Answer (score 9):

My two cents.

As I see it the main reason some users abstain totally to down vote is because it has a penalty attached (for downvoting answers). In my experience, when you down vote a post **your post also get down voted**. Never seen anybody who takes being down voted well. It is seen as a personal attack of some sort.

For low reputation folks like me, losing reputation means you don't get the next privilege or something. It may look silly but that is the way it is.

So no wonder some people just stay away from it.

Comment: This is more of a statement than an answer to the question. Do you have a proposed solution to tackle this?

Comment: @Adriaan The proposed solution is most probably to remove the attached penalty. I agree that the answer is a bit short.

Comment: On the contrary, people who post here are too attached to overly wordy answers!

Comment: Can you change it (by [editing your answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/398602/edit)) to be more clear? By penalty, do you mean reputation points penalty for the voter only? Or more broadly (for the receiver of downvotes)? It seems to be the former, but it could be more clear. (There isn't any reputation points penalty for downvoting *questions*.)

Comment: That's true for beginners with low reputation. Believe me, with few thousands rep (and constant income from old answers) you just don't think about `-1` anymore. I have few hundereds rep on another site and there I don't care about my rep at all, constantly casting downvotes to wrong answer.

Comment: @Sinatr Right. But I have been down voted by a guy with 32K reputation because I down voted an answer that was clearly a [non-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36089456/indexing-columns-in-a-csv-file/46253244#46253244).

Comment: @agcala, if you get [serial downvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28756/299295), then just flag one of such posts with custom flag and write more details to moderator. Single downvote doesn't prove: 1) it was the guy you think 2) it has anything to do with your downvote.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Sorry. Yeah I mean you usually gets down voted by the person you down vote. Some people with low reputation like me think it twice before down voting someone if you are going to get down voted as well.

Comment: @Sinatr You can decide by yourself [looking at it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36089456/indexing-columns-in-a-csv-file/46253244#46253244) No I have never been serial downvoted.

Comment: @agcala, I can't see who casted downvote. It could be him and it could be a [revenge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398605/1997232) downvote. Just ignore it. Over the time wrong answers tends to get less upvotes and more downvotes than correct ones.

Comment: @Sinatr I have got over it long ago, :) It was just the only single time that happened to me. But I have seen it happening to other people as well.

Comment: @PeterMortensen But there is a penalty for downvoting _answers_

Comment: _It is seen as a personal attack of some sort._. +1 because that is completely true. Downvoting is seen as some sort of cyber attack :)

Answer (score 9):

### How I generally feel about downvoting

**If the post will end up getting deleted, closed or heavily downvoted**, my downvote probably isn't necessary. There just isn't a significant difference between -10 and -11, and closure and/or deletion already provides a fairly strong signal to the system about the quality of the post (for question bans and things). Of course if everyone feels like this, nothing will get downvoted, but that knowledge doesn't make my own downvote feel more effective.

**If none of those apply** (i.e. it's an upvoted post, when my downvote is more important and I probably care more about it), some others will likely disagree with my downvote and actively counter it with upvotes, meaning my downvotes have the opposite effect. It has happened to me multiple times that I downvote a post and someone posts a comment explicitly saying they're upvoting to counter the downvote of myself and potentially others. I understand that people will disagree with me about whether something should be downvoted or upvoted, and that's fine, but there's a huge difference between people upvoting in isolation and them doing so due to my downvote (when they wouldn't otherwise have upvoted). The latter just undermines the exact reason to downvote in the first place. I also doesn't help that my downvote plus even a single countervote ends up giving the question/answer 3/8 reputation, often at the cost of my own hard-earned reputation. (This might be a problem on the subjective sites like Interpersonal Skills or The Workplace more than the technical sites like Stack Overflow, but my feelings about downvotes doesn't change from one site to the other and the more technical sites tends not to have such a big problem with upvoted posts that should be downvoted, or at least I just don't care that much about specific instances of such posts)

**Downvotes also aren't particularly actionable** by themselves. The tooltip seems pretty clear to *me*, but it is pretty generic and more specific feedback is generally more useful. I have seen *endless* examples of people complaining about downvotes they don't understand or asking for an explanation. Downvotes does quantify *how bad* a post is, which could provide a wake-up call for some. But overall that doesn't seem super useful and just explaining what's wrong using a comment (or closure) is probably sufficient. I could downvote *and* comment/close, but that doesn't change any of the reasons I don't downvote listed above and below.

Add to this the fact that **getting downvoted just doesn't feel good** (for me and for others, based on what I've seen them say). We can preach all we want that we vote on content and not users, but that doesn't make it feel much better. I don't want to do things that makes others feel bad (and not much else, as per the above).

**If someone posts something in good faith**, even if it's low quality, it seems nicer and more effective for me to just leave a comment about how to improve the post (even if those get ignored like 95% of the time) or just fix it myself, if able. And, of course, I would vote to close and/or delete it if it doesn't belong on the site in its current state.

**If someone posts something in bad faith**, there are usually other better means available to deal with it, like closing, flagging or ripping it apart with an edit to turn it into an appropriate question (if they post a bad faith question that ends up being a great question, joke's on them).

### What will help?

Honestly? I don't really know.

A number of the suggestions posted here to encourage downvoting might improve things, but I feel like there's a fundamental problem with how downvoting works.

Don't get me wrong though. I do understand the purpose of downvoting and I wouldn't propose just getting rid of it. There just seems to be a disconnect between that theoretical purpose and how it works in the real world.

I also know how controversial requests to change how downvotes work usually are (even if I feel like some of them might have some merit), so I wouldn't want my feelings on the subject to get drowned out by a focus on some specific suggestions. I'm sure you can find plenty of suggestions on the subject here on Meta if you felt so inclined.

Comment: *There just seems to be a disconnect between that theoretical purpose and how it works in the real world.* I totally agree with this and blame the *be nice* policy. Even high-reps are wary of causing any trouble to avoid permanent ban / temporary account suspension / being called out on meta and thus they often refrain from downvoting or giving any other kind of negative feedback.

Comment: @oguzismail I don't know how much the "be nice" policy has affected how others vote, but my feelings on voting doesn't have much to do with that. Yes, I do mention not wanting to make others feel bad, but that's less about following a policy that says I need to be nice and more about wanting to be nice.

Answer (score 8):

I like the already presented ideas to improve the downvote process but I think that we still need to de-demonize the concept of downvotes for *affected users*. In my opinion, this would in turn encourage downvoting on all sides.

Most people are used to voting systems on various Social Media sites. I feel that those votes always mean something personal: "I like your post", "What's with this trash post?", "I'm on the same page as you are".

So it's no wonder that those people also see something personal in the voting system SO has integrated, even though it is actually targeted at the *contents* and *usefulness* of a post. (Blablabla this has been discussed to death!)

Furthermore, many new users don't actually know how SO works and they really don't care. They have a problem, they want it solved, done! So it's no wonder that many feel attacked, when more established users downvote a question/answer into oblivion (and somtimes, downvotes are cast simply because there are already some downvotes). Those users simply don't know what the actual goal of downvotes is.

I have two suggestions:

### Look at Reddit

[image: Reddit voting]

I guess this has been suggested already...

New posts don't show their votes for the first 1-2 hours to prevent influence voting. Not displaying the votes immediately might prevent the OP from feeling discouraged. Additionally, other SO users might be more inclined to leave comments to notify OP about their action and the reasons behind it.

Established users with >= 1000 Rep would still see votes as they are displayed today though.

If the question gets closed before votes are made visible, it might encourage the OP to actually improve their question because they are not intimidated by that -X on the left side. They have more time to follow the suggested links in the close message.

### Show downvoted OP a banner

Maybe something along the lines of:

> Oops, it looks like the community decided that your post does not follow SO guidelines and downvoted accordingly. Remember, **downvotes are not targeted at you**!
>
> To improve your post, please go through [various Help links]...

I don't know exactly when it would make sense to show this banner? After the first (invisible) downvote? After the votes have been made visible? Don't show it anymore after the question got closed?

All in all, I think this might take out the "personal" component of downvotes.

Comment: Reddit is not a Q/A site dedicated to programmers, and up/down votes there represent rather whether the content panders to majority than the quality, so it cannot serve as an appropriate model in this context. And I really didn't get how hiding the post score from its author will help encourage downvoting.

Comment: @oguzismail How is this any different? It's two arrows with a point instead of a number? The only difference is that on Reddit the point sometime reveals the actual number of votes. Then it's the same thing as on SO. Of course, Reddit's (or any other social platform's) model builds on personal opinions, not quality rating. But that's what I've been writing. New users might think SO's voting system works the same way as Reddit's **when it actually doesn't**. Hiding the score increases voting-independence, anonymity and obscures any relation between downvotes and comments.

Comment: A downvote alone sends a clear message to the author that their question/answer does not meet the quality standards of the site. I like how straightforward that message is. If downvotes were invisible I would have to leave comments on how to improve/what's wrong etc., which is boring, and really hard to do right. Copying this stupid concept from Reddit would not encourage me to downvote, it would accustom me to low quality content.

Comment: "New posts don't show their votes for the first 1-2 hours to prevent influence voting." that seems like a very good idea, even if that's not really related to the question.

Comment: It is definitely a good idea for Reddit, a site which is absolutely not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8):

All of the other answers are correct in their own ways, but I do believe that the reason why downvoting is not as common as upvoting, in the Stack Overflow site, is because of the result that comes to the downvoter. If one downvotes an answer, they will lose 1 reputation. For many users, reputation is a big deal. For users that have less than 1K reputation, it is easy to track the exact amount, and know when that amount has gone up or down. I myself am not against this result, as this moderates the users that are "downvote-happy", but if this could be changed, there may be a more stabilized amount of upvotes and **downvotes**.

In addition, to help this cause, I believe it would be more efficient, to not take of reputations per every downvote, but rather, have the first 10 or so downvotes free of reputation loss, and then subtract reputations after those 10 downvotes are done. These downvotes are counted daily (I'm guessing SO uses UTC time), so each day, the number of downvotes reset. For example, if one downvotes 15 people on the first day, he will not lose reputation on the first 10 downvotes the next day.

The above, I hope, will effectively encourage downvoting, but keeps people who downvote just for the fun of it away, as they will still lose reputations after the first 10.

Also, in other answers, I have seen people suggesting to reduce the number of reputations taken away from the **poster**. This will not work, in my opinion, because people do not choose not to downvote because of the effect on the poster, but rather the effect on themselves. The effect of losing 1 reputation point  on the voter, makes them feel as if they did something wrong, and have to pay for it. This is not the way SO wants its users to feel (I hope). If a question or answer is bad/incorrect or poor in quality, people will downvote. But the only thing that prevents people from doing so is the effect on them, not the effect on the person who posted that incorrect question/answer. This effect normally takes the form of an answer, as people do not lose reputations when downvoting **question**.

Comment: Downvoting questions does not cost rep.

Comment: @philipxy Sorry, I forgot to mention that in the answer. I'll edit that in.

Comment: so, to make downvoting easier, we remove the cost for the first 10 **answers** ppl downvote in a day. That doesn't invite downvotes on question, and that brings back the issue we had when downvotes on answers didn't cost a thing...

Comment: @Patrice Sorry, but I'm not understanding what you're trying to get at. Could you clarify?

Comment: @IPSDSILVA well if I get your answer here, you are proposing that the first 10 answers **I** downvote don't cost me rep (or I'm grossly misunderstanding you). Two concerns: a) if we're looking to encourage downvoting, making a part of it free, then the rest not 
won't encourage much. At best, we'll get <10 per user (and even then, only on answers).   b) there is a reason for downvotes costing something when cast on answers. Changing the system brings back the issues the cost was supposed to fix (ie: people downvoting competing answers just to get better scores themselves)

Answer (score 7):

I just want to give some cautionary feedback as a peruser of low traffic tags and Beta sites. If the consensus here does grow to the conclusion to go on a mass witch-hunt style downvote spree, please please please take into the consideration the tag and your understanding of the topic. Those of us on the low traffic tags, who I think have made some positive contributions this site, would potentially get clobbered by this approach to 'clean up' the site. Just because there is a simple question (no code example, or familiar tech speak) on an obscure topic, doesn't mean you need to downvote it into oblivion. I know and understand that there is a lot of warranted frustration with the river of low quality content that poors in daily. But those of us on the low traffic tags/sites don't necessarily deserve the wrath from that. Just try to keep this in mind.

Comment: Nobody wants to go on a downvote spree, doing so would be bad! It shouldn't matter if a tag is low traffic, though. A bad question is a bad question. On the contrary, low traffic tags naturally attract less downvotes than high traffic ones because they get less views. That won't change.

Comment: @ModusTollens, The only reason I posted this answer is because, from some of the comments, that's clearly what a good number of commenters want to do. I don't actually have a problem with this. I agree that the site needs more downvotes. But from the talk of badges, and people saying that they will upvote less, and increasing the potency of a downvote, I can quickly see a good number of tags getting buried by (perhaps) well-meaning downvoters. I don't even think it is that much of a stretch to see that. And that would be a shame.

Comment: A good number of commenters want to go on a downvote spree? I'm sorry, you must have misunderstood. A good number of commenters here are annoyed by obvious bad posts getting upvoted due to users not knowing better or pity upvotes or a misguided sense of downvotes being "unfriendly". Or by users who do not wish to spend the downvote penalty. All they're saying is that downvotes are important, too, and sensible downvotes should be encouraged.

Comment: @ModusTollens, "...sensible downvotes should be encouraged." Which is a moderate point of view I agree with entirely. This answer isn't a response to that mainstream approach. This answer is in response to the more fringe comments I've seen here, which I can see driving the content of low-traffic tags (of any and all quality) right off the site. And I'm just throwing out some cautionary consideration to be held in mind with whatever approach ever comes to fruition.

Comment: I suspect though that as this answer gets itself buried by downvotes, whatever actually happens (if anything ever does happen), will: 1) Be extreme 2) Be unilaterlly implemented by StackExchange without our previous input/feedback 3) Try to be too careful not to hurt anybody's feeling and 4) Not work anyway. Oh well.... I'm starting to think I've been around this site too long.

Comment: In low-traffic-tags (maybe one of a niche language or a new framework), the *criteria* for what is an "up/down-vote-worthy question" may indeed be **vastly** different than for the mainstream tags (I'm looking at you, `JavaScript`). There are many interdependencies, though. One of them being that *using the right tags* can already be a (crucial) criterion. Another one is that for "old/famous" tags, it's hard to come up with a really *good* question that is *not* a duplicate. So *"consider... the tag and your understanding"* is the advice that should underpin all actions anyhow.

Comment: @Marco13, Well stated. Unfortunately, ""consider... the tag and your understanding"" isn't a very popular idea for this topic. Fortunately I've built up a bit of street cred, so I don't mind being one of the lone voice of caution here.

Comment: As another user of low traffic tags, I support this answer 100%.  Too often, questions that are perfectly clear to me have been downvoted to oblivion by drive-by downvoters who don't really known enough about the subject.  Glad I'm not the only one who has noticed this.

Comment: @user1725145 A question that is perfectly clear to you can still be off-topic on Stack Overflow. Do you have an example of a good, on-topic question that has been downvoted to oblivion in a low-traffic (or any other) tag?

Comment: @ModusTollens several, but I don't feel like hunting them out just to make the point for you.

Comment: @user1725145 This happens all the time I ask for examples of downvoted, but good and on-topic posts. Please, _do_ feel like hunting them down for me. I want this point to be actually made for once.

Comment: I really think we should avoid a "Show me an example" discussion here. It just diverts from the topic at hand. If you guys insist, maybe take that to chat?

Comment: @ouflak Yes, but after years of never getting an example of such a post I am getting a bit miffed. If users can't provide proof, it's best to not mention posts like that.

Comment: @ModusTollens, That's fair enough. But after years of being on here, the 'example' discussion usually goes: 1) Someone digs up an example 2) Someone else says, 'I see your point on that post - I'll correct it' 3) Small speech about how that shouldn't have happened 4) It gets forgotten until the next time the topic comes up. There's nothing wrong with that process of addressing specific examples. It just seems to never actually address the underlying problem. That's what the OP's post is about. And I'm responding to an unsettling response to that I see building here. Just want to stay focused.

Comment: @ModusTollens I liked [this how-to java Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61239755/extracting-characters-from-a-string-following-integers-while-adhering-to-the-ord). It was closed, re-opened, re-closed, downvoted to oblivion and when I get my 10K (if I ever do), I will revisit it.

Comment: @Scratte, Unfortunately, despite my being active on this site for almost a decade, including taking on moderation and maintenance actions, my rep doesn't allow me to see that post. Another topic I think needs to be addressed by StackExchange some day.

Comment: @ouflak Well.. it was part of my point, to be honest. These examples that are usually deleted, so what's the point of asking for them if one doesn't have the ability to see them? :)

Comment: Sorry, I am busy.  And it is not important.

Answer (score 7):

## Displaying the button flexibly for different audiences?

Let's call Alice the downvoter and Bob the answerer who gets a downvote from Alice. Here they are:

[image]

The premise here is that newcomers will **automatically, unavoidably associate** downvotes with having their effort being not accept by the social. I bet that anyone in here still find [social rejection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3UTXsJzAj4) a pain in real life. Arguing with a behavior that is **proved to be crucial to our survival in million years of evolution** is unwise. Therefore:

- We must not assume that Alice and Bob won't have this association
- We must assume that even we say "downvotes are not about you", the fear of being rejected still overwhelm them
- We must understand that people need detailed reasons to happily accept a rejection*
- We must take our role to teach them to abandon this association
- We must understand the differences between Alice and Bob's perspectives in order to teach them effectively

Here is my proposal:

- On Alice's side, display the downvote button as text like "not useful". When she hovers it, there will be more options for her to choose: confusing/unclear, doesn't answer/miss the point, wrong, inapplicable, etc. Think of it like Facebook's reactions. She can choose to click those options, or just simply click the general button and move on.
- In Bob's side, display the downvote as sentences: This answer seems to be confusing to one person, this answer seems to be miss the point to two persons, etc.
- After a while of using the system, and the users have learned to de-associate the two, we can display it as arrow if we want

Bonus point:

- People who don't downvote, but see the reasons given by other downvoters, will be nudged to help explaining the reasons clearer. (Come on, we require questions to be as clear and as detailed as possible, but yet allow votes to be ambiguious?)

## Important note

This proposal doesn't mandate downvoters to provide feedback, hence this FAQ doesn't apply: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/3416774)

<sub>* Read [How to Write Rejection Letters Which Make the Rejected Like You - Kletische](https://kletische.com/write-rejection-letters/)</sub>

Comment: It's a decent solution. However, it also requires implementing feedback that can be chosen when downvoting, so Alice can downvote and say "confusing". Unless the reasons shown to Bob are automatically picked from a pool, perhaps but that seems less useful.

Comment: I wanted to say something along these lines.  As the recipient of commentless downvotes, I learn nothing.  We definitely don't want to require a comment along with a downvote, as that would definitely further reduce the number of good downvotes due to the trouble (and possibly repeated comments).  But if clicking downvote popped up a short list of "why" options, then the downvote is /educational/ to the recipient instead of just (potentially) insulting.  If we are better educating users in how to ask good questions, that seems like a win to me.

Comment: I'm being really picky but is it appropriate to distinguish a "down-voter" from an "answerer" by gender? What about using User A and User B?

Comment: @Lankymart using gender pronouns (he, she) is convenient. The assigned genders are arbitrary

Comment: I am also not a fan of the arbitrarily and unnecessarily gendered example. But I like this proposal. Unlike many other answers here, it seriously considers the possibility that downvotes have a downside, and tries to mitigate the legitimate harm that downvotes can cause (while preserving the capacity to provide important feedback and moderation signals).

Comment: @senderle the technique to construct this answer called "steelman argument" I believe. Anyway, why do you "downvote" the idea of using genders? It brings more life to it than just A or B.

Comment: @Ooker because it's not relevant to the issue, and raises associations that some people are going to find disagreeable or uncomfortable. Even if you don't see things their way, this distracts from the real point of your post, and undercuts your argument.

Comment: I think this is a *fantastic* idea, with the caveat that we will inevitably get people angrily commenting things like "How on earth does [downvote reason] apply to my question/answer?!!"

Comment: @F1Krazy having a satisfactory explanation will always require time and effort, which the downvoters may not have. Plus that I think it's also beneficial to not require them to explain. The point here is to **encourage more downvotes**, not settle angry comments. (This doesn't not mean that this answer doesn't aim to solve the confusion of being downvoted. It seriously tries to.)

Comment: This is just a thinly veiled "require comments/explanation with downvotes"

Comment: This might be a better answer if it didn't try to throw yet another barrier in the way of downvoters.  The idea is to encourage downvoting, not add yet another task that doesn't apply to upvoting.

Comment: You are operating under the misconception that downvotes are meant to provide feedback to the poster. They are not: their purpose is to signal to everyone *else* (e.g., future readers) the community's opinion regarding the quality of the post. If someone wants to provide specific feedback to the poster, they can always do so in a comment. That is intentionally distinct and disconnected from votes.

Comment: @CodyGray again, "we must not assume that Alice and Bob won't have this association". Even if the system doesn't slightly intend to do so, I would say not seriously consider it will fail our goal to encourage downvoting here

Comment: @KevinB you may say so. But if the goal here is to encourage downvoting, then I just simply point out the reason why people don't do this. If you insist that we should not force downvoters to explain (which I totally understand and accept), then the goal will fail. What do you want?

Comment: @fbueckert which task that you think a barrier to the downvoters? The hover stuff? That's not a barrier I think

Comment: But your proposal *subverts the very purpose* that downvoting attempts to serve.

Comment: @CodyGray Subvert? I think it's correct to a degree, but it doesn't attempt to subvert it. Words like "not completely focus" seems better. Again, the proposal bases on a premise that *the very purpose of downvoting against million years of evolution*. Plus that I still don't get why we can't provide easier options to downvoters to provide detailed feedback? What is the harm of that?

Comment: Please see [the FAQ on that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436). The problem with this proposal is that it presumes the purpose of downvotes is to give feedback to the user who posted the content. That is not the case; that's what comments are for. They're a separate mechanism. The purpose of downvotes (and upvotes) is to *rank content*. Your proposal here does nothing whatsoever to rank content for the benefit of other viewers.

Comment: "which task that you think a barrier to the downvoters?"  Literally *anything* that upvoters don't have to do.  The more you make downvoters do, the less downvotes happen.  That will skew voting towards upvotes even more heavily, and that's something we've been over time and time and *time* again.

Comment: @fbueckert just like you can press "Like" on Facebook without needing to provide detailed reactions, one can downvote without needing to provide detailed reasons

Comment: But now there are more options for the downvoter.  And no extra for upvoting.  That's a problem.  Why shouldn't upvotes have the same?  That translates far better to Facebook reactions than downvotes do.

Comment: @fbueckert yes, upvote's "reactions" can be implemented as well. Here I just focus on the downvote

Comment: @CodyGray This proposal doesn't mandate downvoters to provide feedback, hence that FAQ doesn't apply:

Comment: @Ooker *"When she hovers it, there will be more options for her to choose: confusing/unclear, doesn't answer/miss the point, wrong, inapplicable, etc."* is that not mandating providing feedback? can't downvote without selecting a "reason"?

Comment: @KevinB sorry, I mean she can choose to click those options, or just simply click the general button and move on. Similarly to the "Like" button on Facebook

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why I bother adding a 30th+ answer but what's wrong with:

Discounting the reputation penalty when there's consensus. The higher the ratio of downvotes, the less reputation hit you get.

Comment: It's only -1 rep for the voter and -2 rep for the author. How do you imagine this to work?

Comment: fractions ? I guess they could be hidden/rounded up in display.

Comment: The reputation loss is already so small it goes unnoticed for the most part. Fractions would be just completely useless. I like your fresh idea though, I don't think anyone came up with this yet.

Comment: @Jeffrey I think this won't be worth it, not only because of the mentality of fractions but also because this would cause people not to be the first to vote, as they don't want to lose the most amounts of reputations. If no one wants to be first, there won't be a first, and eventually, no downvotes at all.

Answer (score 6):

A downvote must be seen as some form of critique. And for critique to be constructive, an explanation about the "why" is somehow mandatory, even if I'm not saying it should be required by the system. I think it's ok as it works now.

I'm not a new user, but I feel really frustrated about a downvote without an explanation. It's not the -2 reputation points; it's just that it doesn't help me (and the future readers) unless there is something obviously wrong which I've overlooked. I want to know *what's wrong and improve it*. I think that's just natural.

But yeah, at the end it's up to the users to comment or not. Some may be just afraid of a discussion, even if they are right. Some may not have English as their native language, or simpler, they may just don't have time for a discussion because they are busy. I understand that (even if it hurts me :) )

Short answer: I think the current system is ok in terms of encouraging downvotes. A zero votes post, in combination with many views, also says something, IMO. Of course -1 may be more obvious sometimes. At least in the tags I'm currently in, really wrong answers, or bad questions also get a -X. But it the depends on the tags / area of Stack Overflow for sure.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and I like what you are saying, but I downvoted because this post does not offer a good suggestion how we can encourage downvoting. We know that it's already a problem that people expect a comment and some decide not to vote because of this, but the question is what we can do to improve this situation. There are clear cases where the downvotes are needed but for some reason the post was viewed 30 times and not a single downvote was cast.

Comment: This is simply because I don't think we should encourage people to do that. :) The current situation isn't problematic enough to risk difficulties with social interactions within the community. At the end it's a trade-off, and there is a risk. I would do nothing.

Comment: @Dharman Oh, I overlooked this: You say: `We know that it's already a problem that people expect a comment and some decide not to vote because of this`. Are there numbers to prove this? Speaking for myself, I'm not afraid, even if I don't like it myself :P But yeah, would like to know if this is a data driven investigation result or an assumption. In the latter case, I'm not sure if it's right to assume that

Comment: @Dharman “I downvoted because this post does not offer a good suggestion how we can encourage downvoting” ... This answer is merely pointing out that the original question starts from a false premise, that more down voting is necessarily a good thing.

Comment: Yes, false premise. Downvotes without a word of explanation may often be cast by people with less understanding than the questioner/answerer of the subtleties. How prevalent can we ever know that is? Even when multi-high-reppers downvote, that can nonetheless be the case. For the most silly type of bad questions or answers a simple link to an explanation about "what category of bad this is" would suffice. For others, at minimum a few words explaining the problem. The downvotee would then potentially have a chance to address the accusation. Downvotes with no explanation should not be possible.

Answer (score 6):

If we downvote answers, we get reputation taken away from us. That discourages users from downvoting.

Comment: I agree with you, so catch my upvote, but this doesn't really add anything new to the answers. It has already been mentioned previously.

Answer (score 5):

[To preface my remarks, may I say that this is perhaps the most important issue to be grappled with regarding the basic functionality of Stack Overflow. It's no secret that I'm a major downvoter, not because I'm an ornery curmudgeon but because I'm devoted to rational curation of the site. My power as a downvoter, however, has visibly diminished; the increasingly poor quality of the site continues to grow exponentially, far outpacing the ability of curators to keep it clean. That is what needs to be corrected.]

Here is a set of proposals; please consider them from a distance and as a unity, but also bear in mind that they are tentative and intended as a starting point for discussion and tweaking.

- **Raise the bar to entry higher** before downvoting is permitted at all. Reputation to permit voting down must be much higher — in the thousands — *and* the user must have earned at least a bronze badge in one of the question's tags (even if what is being downvoted is an answer). In this way we attempt to ensure both the *bona fides* and the qualifications of the downvoter; downvoting should require expertise.
- **Give dupehammer holders instant closure powers.** This applies, obviously, to questions only. Right now, downvoting questions is often just a way of getting attention: you downvote to discourage the OP and vote to close, and hope others come along and agree. But if I am qualified to judge closure on the basis of being a duplicate, I am qualified to judge closure on the basis of the question being poor in general. How is that related to downvoting? Because it would reduce the need to downvote questions in the first place, which is how I spend most of my time on SO at the moment.
- **Redress the balance** between the rep awarded to the poster for receiving upvotes and the rep subtracted from the poster for receiving downvotes. If the upvote is 10, the downvote should be -5. (This sounds dramatic, but hear me out; keep reading.)
- **Increase the penalty to the downvoter** accordingly. Right now, the penalty is a mere -1, and only for answers. The penalty to the downvoter should be far greater, perhaps even the same as whatever the penalty is for the poster. The idea, obviously, is to discourage wanton downvoting and encourage thoughtful, qualified downvoting, in conjunction with the other proposed changes. Combined with the higher bar to entry, this also helps to ensure that downvoting is done only by people who can afford it.
- The **penalty to the downvoter should be retractable**. This is true now, but it needs to be extended. The downvoter penalty for downvoting a question (which would exist under my proposals) should be retracted if the question is deleted, but also if it is merely closed. The downvoter penalty for downvoting an answer should be retracted if the answer is deleted, as now, but also if the *question* is deleted, and also if the post *subsequently* accumulates some threshold of downvotes, such as 3, proving that the downvote was justified and useful. The idea here is that the downvoter is *lending* some reputation to the effort to the curate the site, in the hope and expectation of retrieving it later when the effort succeeds.
- **Clarify the grounds** for downvoting. Right now, I have a mantra that I recite to myself in judging whether a downvote is justified. This ensures that I am downvoting rationally and not because I'm bored or angry or something. This mantra does *not* look identical to what the site itself proposes (for instance, it is much more penetrating than the "unclear or not useful" formulation). I won't tell you exactly what it is, but in the case of questions it has to do with what I call "bad faith", and in the case of answers it has to do with either "bad faith" (e.g. plagiarism) or outright incorrectness. The site itself needs to promote right thinking in evaluation of whether to downvote.

I am not outright opposed to the proposals in some of the other questions that the faithful downvoter should be *rewarded* in some way, but at present I am not persuaded that that's necessary. I do not need encouragement, I need downvoting to be made more effective and rational in and of itself.

Comment: For the first point, what do you do if there are insufficient users with the privilege to downvote for a given tag? Some of these suggestions seem like they would effectively further discourage downvoting by making it very inaccessible.

Comment: While some of the points that you mentioned are certainly worth a thought (or further discussion), the connection to what you considered as the main problem isn't immediately obvious for me (and the first point, as GoodDeeds mentioned, may even be "counterproductive" in some way). Specifically, you referred to "*poor quality ... outpacing the ... curators"*, and I doubt that (what one could somehow dismissively call) "rep-tweaking" will solve this. A -5 for the downvoted and (retractably) for the downvoter could act as some sort of "lever" here, but I wonder whether it's long enough.

Comment: I am close-voter myself (rarely downvote, but also rarely upvote, except answers to my own questions). But I like your idea to prevent access to up/down-vote priviledge from newcomers. They are inexperienced and are expected to make mystakes. It doesn't matter if there  are lack of those who can downvote and thousands of questions, new users should not be involved into voting until we can trust them, until they get comfortable with the system. I also like your idea of "paying" for decision and if decision was correct one - get what you have payed back. That's fair.

Comment: @GoodDeeds That's just a matter of detail or degree. That is what I mean when I say my proposals are "tentative and intended as a starting point for discussion and tweaking". Perhaps the rule should be that to vote down you need _either_ a bronze badge in the subject _or_ a certain minimum rep. Perhaps the bronze badge idea cannot work (though I think it can, and I think it would help). That's neither here nor there, as it is all to be worked out. And please attend to the overall purpose of my suggestions; downvoting will be encouraged by making it _meaningful_ and _authoritative_.

Comment: *And the user must have earned at least a bronze badge in one of the question's tags*. Some questions are obviously unclear and wrong. I don't need to have a bronze badge in [tag:html] to know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62334404/puppeteer-pdf-horizontal-scrolling-print) question is very low quality.

Comment: "Reputation to permit voting down must be much higher — in the thousands — and the user must have earned at least a bronze badge in one of the question's tags" What about low traffic tags that are a benefit to the site, but might have * *no* * users who have that tag badge (or ever will)? Those tags get their share of crap questions as well. 
"But if I am qualified to judge closure on the basis of being a duplicate, I am qualified to judge closure on the basis of the question being poor in general."
While I generally agree, this is not logical and not necessarily true.

Comment: "If the upvote is 10, the downvote should be -5. Increase the penalty to the downvoter. The penalty to the downvoter should be far greater, perhaps the same." This has the potential to kill low traffic tags getting downvotes from people who may not understand the topic (and the actual quality of the questions/answers). It would certainly discourage people on those tags from downvoting even the most aggregious content. 
"The penalty to the downvoter should be retractable." I like this. The only issue with low traffic tags is that delete/closure happens ***slowly***, if at all on these tags.

Comment: If the post will end up getting deleted, closed or heavily downvoted, my downvote probably isn't necessary. If none of those apply, some others will likely disagree with my downvote and actively counter it with upvotes, meaning my downvotes have the opposite effect. So I'm already barely seeing the point of downvoting. Taking away more of my hard-earned rep as a penalty for doing it is certainly just going to make me even less likely to do it. A number of these suggestions would make people *less* instead of *more* likely to downvote. Is that intentional?

Comment: You miss the point. I've cast plenty of what I believe are very VALID downvotes, although many of them I've cancelled after deciding -1 rep wasn't worth it. I could care less about reputation - not granting me additional power just makes it harder for YOU. I'd like to be able to help out. But I'm not going to go out of my way to amass reputation just so I can. I did it for 125. I'm not doing it for 5k.

Answer (score 5):

It's clear that voting feels personal to many people (both vote givers and vote receivers) regardless of the intent of the voting system, which is to grade content and not people.

One approach to separate posts from users is to anonymize the posts, at least for a minimal amount of time after creation. Hide the user card on a post for perhaps an hour or a day or until it receives a vote. This would force voters to evaluate the content alone, since there is no additional information to act on.

Perhaps more importantly, this could eliminate the perception of new users who feel they are being voted on, rather than their content.

To take the thought experiment a step further, what if the only way to view the user card on a post is to vote? Could that encourage voting and eliminate the perception of bias at the same time?

In summary, since voting *feels* personal, and that deters many voters, let's make it unequivocally impersonal.

Comment: Are you suggesting that people vote by looking at the user who posted instead of the content? Why would anyone do this?

Comment: I'm definitely suggesting that people vote by looking at the _rep_ of the user who posted; but I'm also suggesting that people hesitate to downvote because it feels personal, and people feel personally attacked by receiving downvotes.

Comment: Would new users *know* that they are anonymised? Would they *care*? Because I think that wouldn't really reduce the rate of complaints.

Comment: @VLAZ, the anonymization would need to be blatant enough to not be overlooked (so an hour may be insufficient). But the perception of bias will exist as long as voters have both the content and the author available to act on.

Comment: @Dharman Revenge downvotes are **real**.

Answer (score 4):

**Allow people to donate reputation to delete bad answers**

---

[image]

---

**How would this work?**

In addition to a downvote you can offer some of your reputation to show how bad you think an answer is. This should hopefully highlight particularly bad answers.

**What happens to the poster?**

The poster would get the usual `-2` rep loss - 5% of your own rep loss.

Example: I offer 200 to delete an answer, the poster gets `-12` rep loss.

*Perhaps there should be a cap on how much one can donate.*

**What happens when the answer gets deleted?**

You are considered for a new set of badges:

- **Patron** - Donated rep resulting in the deletion of 5 answers.
- **Advocate** - Donated rep resulting in the deletion of 10 answers.
- **Philanthropist** - Donated rep resulting in the deletion of 25 answers.

Comment: Well..... it's certainly a novel idea

Comment: I don't understand .. you will offer your Rep but you will get it back when the answer is deleted?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yep similar to the `-1` when you cast a downvote and get back when the answer is deleted.

Comment: so how it's different from what we have actually? offering X and getting back X is the same whataver the X is

Comment: Quite exploitable.Will moderators be able to review such quickly deleted questions and what actions can be made for users if they overuse it? Would love to see slash in rep and long ban.

Comment: @TemaniAfif It is if you chose to just see that. I think my post is a bit more elaborate though. Anything you think I should clarify?

Comment: I don't understand why I should get back my Rep if I am offering it to delete bad content. With my 138K I can easily use 10K to delete your answer and you will be obliged to delete it because it will hurt your Reputation then I get back my 10K. I can easily delete any kind of answer I want since at the end I will get back the Rep and I am sure I will always do because the OP will be losing a lot and will always delete his answer

Comment: @TemaniAfif Fair point. I'll remove that bit.

Comment: I am a bit confused why there is so much emphasis on deleting answers. Downvoting is definitely useful and necessary, but is it necessary to remove such answers (unless it is a clear NAA or VLQ)?  Especially when it comes to other Stack Exchange sites where the answers are more subjective, it would be helpful to have keep differing opinions. And on all sites including Stack Overflow, won't examples of "bad solutions" and "what not to do", indicated by their negative score, also add value?

Comment: @GoodDeeds SO is not about opitnions. Sometimes you have non-working answers or answers giving *very bad*solutions (Ex: solving a simple CSS solution using jQuery) and let's not forget the repeated and trivial answers to trivial duplicate questions. We don't need to have the same answer repeated a million time, we need one canonical answer dealing with the issue. That's why deleing answers is *very* important.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I agree with you on duplicate and gibberish (VLQ/NAA) answers, and those should certainly be deleted. But apart from that wouldn't votes be a better tool to judge technical merit? By using deletion, it is possible for a small set of users (who need not even be active in that tag if I understand correctly) to decide if an answer is bad, rather than letting votes from the broader community judge its merits. There may be several ways to solve a given problem, and votes can show which ones are great and which ones are very bad.

Comment: @GoodDeeds delete is also a way to judge an answer. 3 users are needed to delete an answer and you can only cast a delete vote on answers having less than -3. If 3 differents users decide to delete an answer then probably it doesn't deserve to be kept as the solution is completely wrong or have no merit to stay around. By the way (based on my experience) the deletion of answer is very rare and is not done so much. In 99% of cases the deletion came from the OP because of the negative votes and this is what we actually want.

Comment: @GoodDeeds This is most likely another bad idea of mine anyway. What I like about this is that it offers people a way to give back to the community. They recognised your contributions with rep and now you have an opportunity to do something positive with your fake internet points ;) Definitely not to be implement as is, but maybe a step in the right direction? Who knows?!

Comment: Do we have a problem with answers that have a negative score? There are a few of them hanging around, but they usually don't cause many issues and it usually isn't a big issue to delete them. High rep users can already directly vote to delete answers with negative scores. We might have a bigger issue with 0-score answers, but the issue there is that no-one has voted on them, which this won't address.

Comment: I can't really support features that start to treat reputation points very similar to money. This effectively makes it possible for "the rich" to pay to have things removed that they don't like. That'll stir up the toxicity discussion.

Comment: @Gimby Yeah that's a possibility. I'll remove that. Thanks

Comment: That's surprisingly similar to what I wrote here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction#comment776613_398371 - and as the comments here already show: It's not simple, and could be abused if it's not balanced *reeeally* carefully (and is not really encouraging downvotes, by the way - except for maybe attracting attention to a particularly downvote-worthy instance)

Answer (score 4):

Place a daily limit for downvoting without a penalty. Say 5. After these five votes, user can be charged a reputation of 1 or more if the limit is higher. This will encourage people to downvote, but only for useless posts.

Comment: Downvotes on questions are already free, IIRC. It's only downvotes on answers that cost rep.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about answers

Comment: Yes but it's only one fake internet point, so who cares?

Answer (score 4):

> Do we have any ideas about what we could do or change to encourage people to spend a little bit more of their votes on downvoting posts?

This is always something what is hard to achieve. Get people to do something explicitly. Anyone has their own opinion and someone's signify explicit intolerance or disagreement about something with don't do something.

One of the only attractions to encourage somebody to do something in particular is:

"*If you give me this, you will get that.*"

In fact, one downvote is lowering your reputation, so it is more like:

"*If you give me this, I'll take that too.*"

There is an unbalance, obviously and the desired effect of the person who asked will high-probably not be achieved.

Even for myself, I would ask:

"Why should I do that if lose X when doing so?"

So in truth, It is not beneficial for someone her-/himself to downvote. That's the point.

---

One quite obvious solution is to give someone something back or at least doesn't take something from them if they don't do.

In such a community like this, that seems to could be only accomplished by providing more additional collectives/bonuses (f.e. badges or privileges) and/or omit the reputation loss  when downvoting.

Other ways seem for me not successful on to how really encourage somebody to use the voting features.

The same should be for upvoting. Give the people more bonuses and a decent part of them will use these features more.

Easy as that.

Answer (score 3):

Just my two cents as a user with some rep that rarely downvotes (2920 up vs 43 down currently). For me, it's not about receiving a penalty for downvoting, but about damaging the rep of another user. I only downvote in really bad posts, and even then sometimes I just vote close or flag. I think the reason is simple, if you can give another user some rep by doing an action that is free for you, why wouldn't you do it? Okay, maybe if it's a bad post you shouldn't encourage that, but there is a difference between not upvoting and "punishing" the user with a downvote - because that is kind of how it feels for me. I frequently have the doubt that maybe I will downvote it and then the user will edit and improve the post and then the downvote will be undeserved, but I don't want to be responsible for that (note the opposite would be very rare, a good post becoming a bad post after editing). And in general I don't feel very comfortable with that idea of punishing for a bad post. I know it's not really about that, but about keeping the site clean and the content relevant. But the moment you have the rep game, and the privileges and so on it becomes like that to an extent.

I do agree that there should be more downvotes in many cases, I keep seeing a lot of posts that are just not really good, maybe not to the point where they should be closed or deleted, but just not good. I'm not sure what would be the best solution in general but, for me personally, one idea that could be worth trying is this: **remove downvote penalty for the poster (and voter) *but* only add reputation for the total positive score of each post**. So, if you get 3 upvotes and 2 downvotes, instead of `3 * 10 - 2 * 2 = 26` you get `max(3 - 2, 0) * 10 = 10`. If you only have two downvotes, you get `max(0 - 2, 0) * 10 = 0`. This way:

- You don't feel you are "subtracting" rep points from the poster, just making them "earn fewer points", so the downvote would be more about curation than punishing.
- Low rep users will not see their rep damaged by a bad post, and hopefully not get very discouraged, but they will not get points if they get 1 upvote and 4 downvotes.
- Effectively, downvotes will have a cost of 10 points for the poster (as many people claim should be) in all but bad posts. I think this is fair in the sense that, when you are better at posting content, and probably more seasoned, then you are in the "hard" or "real" rep game, and bad content has a more significant consequence.

Of course, users who don't care about rep at all will never bother with any of it either way, whether downvotes are -2 or -200 points. There are other interesting proposals in the other answers. I think it is logical that an upvote does not require an explanation, it just means "this is good", which rarely requires a comment why that is, but a downvote most likely has a specific reason to it (although sometimes it should be pretty obvious), and an explanation may help the user improve the post. I wouldn't require a comment with a downvote, but maybe could be encouraged. But honestly I don't think that really addresses the question posted here, which is about getting people to downvote more.

Comment: If the user's who post mediocre or bad answer get downvotes it should motivate them to write better answers in the future. Most do not care about the reputation however. You should not care about it either. They are meaningless points and people will not be hungry just because you subtracted two fake points from them. Besides this is called reputation. Users' reputation should tell us if they post useful content or trash.

Comment: @Dharman I understand your point, but just stating that people "should" or "should not" care about something does not make it so. Also, what you say is a bit contradicting, I think. On the one hand, rep points give you privileges, so they are not really "meaningless". On the other hand, as you said, "this is called reputation" and "should tell us" something about the user and their content. Most people would agree "reputation" like this is not meaningless. Everyone wants to have a good rep, and for some (myself included) rep is a significant part of the motivation to post (answers mostly).

Comment: I meant in gives you nothing in real life. Reputation is a total of all your contributions. If people only give you upvotes and never downvotes we don't know if you are truly are posting good information. You also don't have the motivation to learn from this. I like your idea, but I disagree that we are punishing users with our downvotes. Users are punishing themselves by posting low-quality posts. Our job is only to rate the posts. If you like it then upvote, if you don't like it then downvote. The rep gain/loss is not the goal, it's side-effect.

Comment: I don't even think about the user when I vote on content.  I don't look at their name, I don't look at their current rep score, I don't acknowledge if they have the "new user" tag on their post.  I read the post and consider whether the post is good/bad/editable and then vote/flag/edit accordingly.  The user's rep comes from the accumulation of votes on their own content.  We are encouraged to vote on content, not on users.

Comment: @Dharman, could you back up your replies with data?  "If the user's who post mediocre or bad answer get downvotes it should motivate them to write better answers in the future." Okay, why? "Most do not care about the reputation however." MOST? How do you know that?  Did you conduct a survey? This is not an easy thing to determine. "You should not care about it either. They are meaningless points and people will not be hungry just because you subtracted two fake points from them." Are you sure? Why?

Comment: I can support the idea to change the reputation calculation based on the net positive score. It feels (to me) like it more closely correlates the users' reputation scores with the trustworthiness of their information. And it removes the incentive to leave bad content up (1 upvote plus 4 downvotes stilles leaves the author with a net reputation gain). If it also helps users lift their hesitation to downvote poor content, I'm all for it.

Comment: As a new user I am grateful for this post explaining downvote importance.

Answer (score 3):

One way to encourage people to cast more downvotes would be to make downvotes *not bad* for the downvoted party. The people who like downvoting will probably continue to downvote anyway and the people who dislike downvoting because of its effects on the other party will be more inclined to do so.

If a downvote didn't affect the user receiving its reputation at all or if a downvote was worth a modest positive amount like `+1`, but *did* make the question less visible to others, then I think users would be more inclined to graciously accept downvotes as constructive-but-nonspecific negative feedback from the community.

I think this would reinforce the idea that *downvotes are not personal*.

People's natural inclination is to treat all criticism as personal, and counteracting this inclination requires the consequences of the criticism to be *clearly isolated to one particular issue*.

Comment: If someone's answers get 50 upvotes but 1000 downvotes, do they really need to gain 500 rep for that? That's as much rep as someone who got 50 upvotes and 0 downvotes. One idea would be to place a minimum bound of zero rep on posts.

Comment: @Flimm: Can you write out your calculation? 50*10 - 1000*2 = -1500 (a reputation points ***loss***)

Comment: The idea of making a downvote actually give the user rep is an interesting one. Obviously it would be super easy to abuse or encourage wrong behavior, but the idea of looking into a way to give the user something positive while still curating the content I think is worth exploring. It's kind of like giving a kid a lollipop when they're about to get a shot -- we can tell people all day that downvotes are helpful and not personal and so forth, but to some people that will be the same as telling a kid a shot is helpful and necessary, they still won't appreciate it. Something sweet helps.

Comment: @PeterMortensen the answer suggested that downvotes should cost whoever got downvoted nothing. So the calculation would be: 50 * 10 - 1000 * 0 = 500

Comment: @Flimm In your example, the user's reputation change would be `+50 * 10 + 1000 * 0` or `+50 * 10 + 1000 * 1` depending on whether receiving a downvote is worth nothing or a modest positive amount.

Comment: Wow. When I suggested positive rep on a downvote, I got hammered. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373455/315052

Answer (score 2):

TLDR; nothing has to be done. It's fine as it is now.

> Do we have any ideas about what we could do or change to encourage people to spend a little bit more of their votes on downvoting posts?

I didn't understand why exactly it is a problem. What problem are you trying to solve by encouraging downvotes?

Offtopic questions get downvoted enough. Wrong answers - too. Everything seems fine to me.

Are you talking about old answers which become invalid?

> There is almost 8 times more upvotes on Stack Overflow than downvotes.

So what? The sum shouldn't be zero.

Personally if there is an offtopic question, I am trying to close it first. If it's worse than just that (where OP is in hurry or even worse - demands quick answers) then you can be sure it will get my downvote.

I rarely cast downvote on question if it alreay has few downvotes. Why? Simply, I don't see a point in downvoting it more. Sometimes I cast downvote on a question with -10 or even -20 downvotes, if it's that bad.

Are there rules to always downvote? Nope. It's subjective. What you think is bad for someone else may looks not so bad. Unless we all think the same and then downvotes are rising.

> Without our downvotes, users might never know that their 0 scored answer was not useful

That's the point. Usually *any* answer what attempt to answer even with what looks very obvious and easy to you could be useful to someone with much less experience. Only *wrong* answers deserve downvotes to indicate that to future reasons.

Once you get some big amount of reputation you stop thinking about not loosing reputation on bad answers. So removing `-1` for downvoting answers is not really needed.

Do you want *beginners* (those who are new to site) downvote more? Really? For seasoned users it's not a problem to loose that bit. I often find old question where I just downvote several answers for varios reasons.

So again, what exactly problem you want to solve by removing `-1` reputation penalty for downvoting answers?

Comment: `Offtopic questions get downvoted enough`: In high volume tags, maybe. In lower traffic tags not so much. In my tags, I often enough find answers which are more than a month old, are totally wrong, have a comment stating that they are totally wrong but have a net score of 0.

Comment: @BDL, I was not aware about low traffic tags. Shouldn't the question be edited to indicate that fact or are there more problems with downvotes?

Comment: I see there is a comment stating another problem with [upvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398537/what-can-we-do-to-encourage-downvoting/398614?noredirect=1#comment776864_398537). And while it may be relevant, to me it's not clear why downvotes are the problem at all. 5:1 upvotes shows people are agree "there is a problem", but which problem exactly???

Comment: The issue, as I see it, is bias. The incentive for upvoting and downvoting is different, yet there is no visual cue to convey that. Indeed, the site's visual layout does everything to hide that. It displays a sum of votes, as if they came at the same cost to the voter, and even when you can see the split score, the numbers are displayed using the same font, font size, font weight, color. That paints a skewed picture of the real value of a contribution.

Comment: @Sinatr One problem in the Java tag, e.g., are bad and/or off-topic questions getting upvoted. On questions from new users this happens often after the post getting an initial downvote, sometimes accompanied by a comment scolding the downvoter because we should be "nice to new users".

Comment: @ModusTollens, I am not a big fan of welcome initiative (I simply stay the same, trying to be objective and neutral, talking to a colleague, without adding that stinky "welcome to SO" in comments to new contributors). But isn't it the problem with upvotes? Of course you could try to solve it with downvotes, but it's just wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable, I didn't understand what is the problem. Upvotes gives more rep, but score is sum. How is that matter? To who? If I am looking for the answer, then I have absolutely zero problem with current system. So why more downvotes? Why biasing?

Comment: What's the cost of an upvote to a voter? What's the cost of a downvote to a voter? Are those the same? If not you should understand, why the scores are biased (and towards which end of the scale).

Comment: @IInspectable, as I said I don't have problems to find answers. The system just works.

Comment: I don't have problems finding answers either. Finding answers isn't the scoring system's job, though. The scoring system's job is to differentiate between *quality* content, and the rest. I frequently see it fail at that, presumably due to a strong bias towards upvotes.

Comment: @Sinatr I don't want to "solve it with downvotes". I don't want to downvote posts just because they got an undeserved upvote. What I want instead is for more users to grasp the value of and reason for downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

**If you really want people to increase the downvote/upvote ratio, make it mandatory.** I am one of those who cast more upvotes, probably because I find downvotes pretty harsh.

You could start nagging users who have cast, say, 5 times as many upvotes than downvotes, and let them not upvote any longer if the ratio is, say, 10. Judging from my own motivation I think I would cast the occasional downvote just in order to be able to upvote. Even the nagging could help: I payed more attention to question after I was nagged.

Comment: Probably forcing them to vote is going to cause random downvotes. However, nagging them to consider downvoting too, could help.

Answer (score 0):

**In short... Effort**

Let me preface this by saying I think the ratio should always skew toward positive in the long term. The goal of closing questions with downvotes for editing is generally to rework/improve the question. So hopefully some downvotes trend into upvotes.

That said, I think the issue here is effort required. Look at how we use upvotes; we're basically saying "Everything is great, no notes." So that's it, you're done click the button for the digital equivalent of a thumbs up.

However with downvotes we suddenly heap on the responsibility. When you downvote there's the expectation that you address *why* you chose to downvote (typically in comments) and so the very usage of a downvote implies a bit more paper work on your part.

I've seen some other answers hint at sort of canned options for downvoting, and I think that might help. Perhaps downvoting isn't just one bucket of negative votes? Maybe you cast a -1 in certain areas? So if I see a good question and the only thing it's missing is code samples. I can hit the downvote button and put my -1 directly into one of the categories we expect; presumably this would be based on what we look for in a good question. In effect this moves downvotes from a single number with no context to several numbers that define a context... which we can total together for easy display? Sort of like the difference in [GPA](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/GPA#Noun) and a report card. GPA is the overall, but each subject has its own grade.

Answer (score -1):

Well, my first thought on this would be to leave the -1 Rep for downvoting, but when the question or anwser actually gets closed/deleted, then just give like +2 Rep to the downvoter, because it seems like the downvote must have been reasonable in this case.

Edit:
As VLAZ mentioned, the +2-Approach would most likely attract gamblers, which seems true. Another approach, as already mentioned in the comments, would be to just give +1 Rep instead, so that it evens out at +-0. This would certainly encourage people, and especially low-rep people, to downvote, as they are less likely to suffer a reputation-loss, as long as they downvote reasonably.

Comment: Seems a bit like gambling. You wager your rep to potentially gain more rep. My issue here is that it removes incentive from removing downvotes. Indeed, it encourages them *too much*. Example scenario: an answer is wrong and attracts, say, 2 downvotes -> the answer gets corrected. The original downvoters are better off leaving the downvotes there just in case. And for other users it would be profitable to downvote even more. With a score of -10 or less, there is pressured into deleting the post and all downvoters *win*. For a *now correct* answer. I can see flocking to negative scores.

Comment: @VLAZ Well, that sure is right I guess. Well, to remove the gambling-part, maybe just give a +1 Rep then, so that it evens out at +-0 on a reasonable downvote. This way it wouldnt encourage gambling for gain, but still make it more reasonable to downvote if you feel like it should be done. This would certainly encourage a lot of people, since they are less likely to suffer from it, especially low-rep people for whom it actually matters.

Comment: This has already been suggested in [Temani Afif’s answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398546/4642212).

Answer (score -1):

## Maybe don't

> Downvotes are a strong signal both to future readers and the author of the post that something is wrong and the experts on this site deem the post to be of little value for future readers.

OTOH, they say absolutely nothing about *why* someone considered the post to be of little value. **A downvote says "this sucks". They tell the poster "we don't like your post but we can't be bothered to say why." Which is not much different than "go away".**

> Many new users get very offended by a single downvote on their question, yet they have completely no objection for the upvotes. Why is that? Why so many users demand that the downvotes be accompanied by an explanatory comment yet nobody demands an explanation for the upvotes?

I've been on Stack Overflow since it was in beta. **I'm not a new user**. I still get offended by someone downvoting my question with no explanation.

I understand that you have to curate the site, but having received some mystifying downvotes, I'm not sure I want to incentivize people to be quicker to throw stones.

Maybe you could encourage upvotes instead? If a lot of people look at something and fail to upvote it, maybe that's an implicit indicator that it's not very good.

Comment: Encourage upvotes? Please don't. People are already more disposed towards upvoting just to be nice. I've seen some terrible, crash inducing, code only answers upvoted. It makes curation a nightmare.

Comment: The downvote says quite a bit more than "this sucks"; it says the post is not clear or not useful (or a question did not show research effort). If all it says is "this sucks", then the upvote only says "this rocks" so why do we need any more of that?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I just posted a Q&A at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62540506/how-can-i-make-safari-not-use-a-cached-version-of-a-page, solely to help future readers, having found the solution myself.
It's clear: I explain in great detail the problem and the solution. It's useful: prior to my posting it, there was nothing on Google matching the message shown in the network tab "(inspector override)", and it took me several hours to figure out. And it's been down voted without explanation.

Comment: So you got one random downvote on a self-answered question? You have to know that some people just don't get that those are encouraged on SO: [How do I ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314165/215552)

Comment: @Heretic Monkey it may be that someone downvotes because they don't like self answered questions. If that was the case then Nathan can't do anything to change the question or answer to satisfy this downvote. However because there is no comment, he doesn't know that is the reason and he breaks his head over what is the downvoters problem with the question. That doesn't help anyone then, except maybe the downvoters own ego fighting self answered questions.

Comment: Just because the topic was important to you does not mean others must also like it. If there are enough people who like your question and think that this is an interesting fresh problem they will eventually upvote it. I have also posted self-answered Q&As and it can happen that the question has score less than 0 but the answer has more than 0. These are just people's opinions what they like and do not like. It needs no more explanation. If you want people's feedback you can always ask for it.

Comment: For transparency, I've deleted several comments here that complain about the lack of comments to go along with downvotes, and other comments that praise users who left comments to go along with their downvotes. All of these are inappropriate and based on a flawed premise. Comments should *never* accompany votes. Downvotes are *never* expected to leave a comment. They're two completely different actions. If you have constructive feedback, then you can leave a comment. If you think the answer is wrong, unclear, or otherwise not useful, then you can downvote.

Comment: They might go together, or they might not. But [posters have no right to demand that downvoters leave comments, nor to complain when they don't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436), because that's simply not how it's supposed to work. Comments lambasting 'downvoters' for not leaving comments are straight-up inappropriate. Do not leave any more, either here or on the main site.

Comment: @HereticMonkeyit's more likely looking at the close flag that the vote is related to the fact that people believe the question doesn't belong on [so].

Comment: I do think "don't" is a pretty viable answer here. But "encourage upvotes" is not a great idea. The issue is that ill-informed people can drive up an easy-to-implement but really bad, even dangerous answer. Downvotes provide an important way for experts to express consensus that an answer has issues without having to post a bunch of redundant comments. Encouraging upvotes would make that (even) more difficult.

Comment: @CodyGray as a number of answers here have asserted, there are a lot of people who dislike downvoting without providing feedback. So maybe that's how its supposed to work in some theory, but the premise of this question is that it isn't working, so I find your logic somewhat circular...

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs The premise of this question is that we need to find some way to encourage more downvoting. Attacking downvoters in comments and/or insisting upon reasons makes downvotes *less* likely. Thus, it works against the aims of this question. More importantly, it works against the site rules. The feedback associated with a downvote is visible in the tooltip; hover over the downvote arrow to read it.

Comment: @CodyGray if everyone agrees that we must encourage downvotes then it's not an open question anymore and it's very unlikely that a solution would arise from discussions. If the question actual intent is to know "What can we do to encourage downvoting?" then it's very weird because it would mean the OP assumes it's a good system, which is clearly not the case otherwise even this surface question wouldn't arise. I think the title is just a click bait title to the actually more profond question "Downvotes do not work, why? What can we do? Let's talk about this to understand the subject better."

Comment: @CodyGray But maybe I assume wrong and the question is what it literally says. If that's the case then I feel it's not an interesting question to debate (as it is way too specific).

Answer (score -3):

#### Replace Downvotes with Hidevotes

**Stack Exchange downvotes are psychologically badly designed.** From what I believe I understand about incentives in online interaction, the average downvote of a question or answer will *always* be taken personally by the author. Because even bad ones have been created with at least some (subjective) effort and diligence – after all, the author thought it's worth publishing that. Being ignored is one thing and people can live with it, but any action that actively discredits that effort (i.e. downvotes) will feel like failure.

I agree that criticism is important to grab somebody's attention (and that's how SE wants downvotes used), but it has to come in the right proportions:

> The average [praise to criticism] ratio for the highest-performing teams was 5.6 (that is, nearly six positive comments for every negative one). ([source](https://hbr.org/2013/03/the-ideal-praise-to-criticism))

Users getting too many downvotes at once will feel instead discouraged from ever posting again, and not encouraged to improve and become masters of Q&A over the longer term. So I'd say that the current downvote system is psychologically a bad design choice for a platform that wants to be welcoming for new users because it has no mechanism that can ensure such a healthy praise to criticism ratio for individual users. (I hardly ever downvote because of that.)

**Stack Exchange does not need to delete low-quality content, either.** Having ones content deleted also does not feel "welcoming". And it does not help Stack Exchange as a system, either. Let's analyze that statement for the two main types of Stack Exchange users: those who eagerly wait for new questions to answer, and those who use a Stack Exchange site as an almost complete knowledge base (and contribute answers to old questions and to own questions after figuring something out, to make it even more complete for the next person coming along).

- The first group will always have to deal with low-quality content because the content they see is fresh – better downvotes won't help *them* because that content is unvoted on yet. In return, they get more reputation than people in the second group who only deal with older questions that don't get much attention anyway.
- For the second group, it does not matter at all if a Stack Exchange site also hosts low-quality questions and answers as long as they don't see that in search (either search engines or the site search with default settings).

**Hiding content from search seems preferable.** From the above, it seems to me that hiding low-quality content is all that Stack Exchange sites need to be a great knowledge base. A system of hide-votes is also easy to explain in such a way that people don't take it personally: "This question *(resp. answer)* is hidden from search engines by default. Other users on this site estimate that it is not a re-occurring problem *(resp. a generic enough answer)*, so it did not become part of our canonical Q&A knowledge base."

**How are hidevotes different?** Hidevotes are not the opposite of "upvotes", so they can be presented as "something about the relation of content and search engines". Users won't care emotionally much about *that*. Also when placing a hidevote, nearly all consequences would stay invisible, preventing any "unwelcoming" effect: (1) a hidevote would not be shown or notified to the author, (2) it will not result in any reputation impact for author or voter, (3) the current tally of hidevotes will not be shown to anyone anywhere, (4) the only consequence is that the 15% of content with the highest hidevote tallies are automatically removed from search engines, again without notifying the authors. (The note I proposed above would only be visible when authors re-visit their own content.)

Comment: I'm not sure how "hide" votes would be considered any more welcoming.

Comment: @tanius I disagree. When I first started using Stackoverflow, I hated it because all my questions were downvoted. I thought: *"What kind of people are those, always downvoting my questions"*. Now I know, and I encourage downvoting questions and answers that are low quality. This should be a platform for experts and people who want to become it and content should be as such.

Comment: @zero298 They'd have (nearly) invisible consequences only. I added a section explaining how I imagine it.

Comment: "*...and authors expect recognition for that. Everything else will feel like failure.*"  Well, we're not in the business of participation prizes.  Expending effort doesn't automatically mean you will, nor should, receive praise for it.

Comment: @fbueckert Yes, agreed. Adapted the answer to be more precise in that section now.

Comment: If there is no negative feedback for behavior with negative consequences, why would a user stop the behavior? If I post an off-topic question, and it gets 1000 "hidevotes", and one answer (which gets 100 "hidevotes"), I've got my answer, and I don't care if no one else can get the answer through a search engine. My rep is exactly the same as it was before I asked it, so I see that SO is fine with it. The person who answers receives no negative feedback, and might even gain rep from the OP from the acceptance of the answer.

Comment: Eh.  I don't think your edit has changed anything.  The act of effort does not entail reward.  The world doesn't work that way.  You need to be able to accept critique, and realize that perhaps your work is lacking.  That's a part of life.  We do no one any favors by withholding that judgement.

Comment: @fbueckert *"We do no one any favors by withholding that judgement."* – If the amount of judgement would otherwise be overwhelming and discouraging, it's better to withhold some (which is not equal to giving a reward!). It's human psychology that critique is a force for good *only if in the right amount*. I had thought that part would be clear with the edit.

Comment: @tanius, you so accuratly noticed: "those who eagerly wait for new questions to answer". That make everything clear for me - this group of users just saying they need the tools to clean thier incoming flow. Clearly, that is not about quality of site content.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, if question get answer, and useful answer for author, that means all these 1000+100 downvoters made a huge mistake and just waste thier time. The eager to control others behavior is in full contradiction with Code of Conduct.

Comment: @EgorBEremeev Please point out the specific language in the Code of Conduct that downvoting violates. Or, stop using the CoC as a shield to allow whatever behavior you want. Stack Overflow was founded precisely to enable the contribution of high quality questions and answers that help more than one person over time.

Answer (score -3):

For me, zero votes mean either `wrong` or `not-seen enough` answers. And dealing with these kind of answers are time-consuming (mostly I just look at them as fast as possible).

When you want to downvote zero-voted answers, you should process:

- Am I sure this answer is wrong?
- It doesn't work for me, but is it really wrong? Maybe it works for others.

So it takes time to process and downvote them.

If you highly encourage people to downvote (for example +5 for downvote), it's dangerous because a lot of people will use it before processing what's going on.

But I think the first step is to remove the -1 score we get when we cast a downvote (I think it's because we should cast a comment to say why it's wrong. But most of the times we do downvotes because the answer doesn't work. So it's stupid to ask for a "it doesn't work" comment every time).

But for the next steps, I'm not sure. It's hard to process and downvote answers. Maybe adding a popup when we hover on downvote button would be a good idea, with these buttons:

It doesn't work for me | hard to read answer | it's totally wrong | I just don't like it

Then we can just say why we don't like this answer, without actually downvoting it (because most of the times we're not sure about down-voting).

And also a notification for the answerer (congaing the username) may be a good idea. So the answerer can try to improve the answer, for example by asking: Don't you use an old version of node? Because my answer is for new [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) versions. (Though these conversations are annoying, because this may become long and time-consuming.)

Comment: With the idea of buttons for the common downvoting reasons, there was actually a [proposal a while back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253531/7795130) which drew up a similar mock-up for questions.

Comment: @DavyM that's similar, but it has a problem: that way i should cast a downvote, then i should tell the reason, but: 1. mostly i'm not sure about downvote 2. it's time consuming to tell the reason. my suggestion was: saying : "it doesn't work for me | not well explained | ..." without actually downvoting. benefits: 1. this way i shouldn't process if the answer is really wrong or not 2. i doesn't take my time. so like a quick negative feedback about answer.

Answer (score -3):

Just a simple thought, remove the direct link between votes and reputation. In my view, the content curation is important enough to give in on some of the community goals of being more welcoming.

A reward from an upvote may be in the form of reputation points, but there's no reason why downvoting needs to result in the loss of reputation points. Let reputation be more of an activity gauge, how much they personally contribute to the knowledge base, let downvotes be a way of curating the content for accuracy.

No reason they need to be linked. I realize you are going to have those who will game the system for reputation, but you pick and choose your battles. Correctness of information is more important.

Comment: Sounds good but if you post an answer which gets 1 upvote and 100 downvotes, you will not have any reason to delete it, because you are still getting positive +10 points

Comment: *"an activity gauge, how much they personally contribute to the knowledge base"* - But if they "contribute" a lot of bad content that gets sympathy upvotes, how is that gauge useful for anything? Let alone for giving them moderation tools?

Comment: @Dharman the hope is that a good answer will come along which will practically hide the bad content. Again, we would have to shift thinking away from linking reputation directly with content curation

Comment: Reputation is linked with curation. The more reputation you have the more curation tools are available to you. If nobody teaches you how to differentiate between good and bad content then you will not be experienced enough to use the curation tools. I want my reputation to go down when I receive downvotes. It's the negative feedback that shows me what is useful and what is useless. It's how I learn to improve my posts.

Comment: @Dharman So don't delete points associated with a post when it is deleted.  If one person thought your answer was useful, why take that away?  There is still the loss of those points if that user gets deleted, although I think this should only be for abuse (e.g. sock puppet accounts solely for the purpose of creating karma like this)

Comment: Maybe there is something unusual with my train of thought, because I've predominantly downvoted the high vote answers here and upvoted the negative ones. @Dharman I think this answer is spot on and for the most part you asked the wrong audience. You should ask your question on psychology.se, rather than posing it to a bunch of "see the world as binary" computer scientists. Most people are saying "abolish the penalty for my negative actions" but that is wrong; actions have consequences in the real world. Downvotes have psychologically negative connotations and you must remove the connotations

Answer (score -4):

Downvotes could get more constructive by giving them a category like

- Not an answer/question
- Badly formatted
- Wrong
- Duplicate

That would make the vote more useful for the poster and thus feel better to give.

Combined with a previous suggestion of notifying voters when a post is edited should also remove part of the bad feeling from giving a downvote.

(High-rep users could opt-out to be able to moderate the site, but for most (?) users there is no way to downvote enough posts for those notifications to become spam.)

Considering the (probable?) ratio between high-rep users and people below say 1k rep where reputation for the next privilege is an issue the cost of downvotes should not be ignored.

Comment: You are confusing closing and flagging with voting.

Comment: "Not an answer/question" is a flag or a close reason. It often overlaps with downvoting but not necessarily. "Duplicate" is also not a downvote reason *by itself*. Some dupes are really good can serve as excellent signposts to a canonical. Others are indeed low effort. I often find a duplicate to a question by literally googling the title of that question. That, I consider low effort, especially if the body shows nothing more than a work request.

Comment: @Dharman actually I'm not confusing them, the flag is for a moderator, the downvote is for the poster/reader. A random downvote does not tell the poster anything, except that someone read my answer for less than a minute and didn't like it.

Comment: @VLAZ yes, my example categories are probably bad, but I was trying to illustrate the thought of giving more feedback in the anonymous vote, without having to post a public comment.

Comment: Which is exactly its purpose. We don't need to confuse others by specifying more reasons for downvotes. You downvote when you found the post not useful. You can post a comment if you think something is not clear. You can vote to close as a duplicate when it has been asked before. You can flag as NAA when the answer is not really an answer. These are all different things.

Comment: I don't see how this suggestion makes it *easier* to downvote.

Comment: @fbueckert It might make people who avoid downvotes because they think they're too mean more likely to use them, since it makes it more explicit that a downvote doesn't mean "You're bad and you should feel bad!"

Comment: It also might make people vote less because now they have to do more than they would if they upvoted.

Answer (score -5):

1. Make it so that the poster can respond to a downvote, which can trigger the voter to review the post and retrieve their rep by reversing their vote.

   > we want to encourage poster to write better content, and its probably better for them to fix it rather than the rest of us.
2. Create a flag on comments that separates comments or discussion about the OP's technical issue and comments about the style/structure/content of the specific post.
3. Make downvotes more visible. Either show the totals in the tooltip when you hover or show a count of downvotes in a smaller text next to the vote summary. if we can't see downvotes, what is the point, no one really clicks on the vote total, its an extra click that you can't un-click to return to seeing the total, so your downvote is all but invisible.
4. Add a bounty for improving an answer. If I find a low quality post that looks like the poster has the knowledge or the content is on the right track, I can add bounty that initially contributes to the downvotes in a bulk fashion, (cost to my rep is equal to the downvotes), if later the post gets deleted, then you get the rep back, however if someone improves that response and I approve, that editor is awarded the bounty and the downvotes removed.

   > again, encourage that the content is improved overall, not that we simply delete content that is no longer relevant to us.

> As the poster (either question or answer) I genuinely want to know what I can do to improve my post, and I want to be rewarded in some way for actually improving my post. If the voter gets a notification "A post you downvoted has been edited, please re-vote" or review, then I have some hope that my responding to community pressure will be rewarded.

This will incentivise people to downvote, because there is a greater chance that they could get their rep back, especially if over the lifetime of the post my downvote resulted in a post being improved an ultimately being upvoted.

Yes, this might generates more "why downvotes" style comments, but that's not a bad thing, it encourages an interaction within the community that will ultimately result in better curated content.

> If comments can be flagged into comments that are discussions about the topic, vs comments that are specifically about the quality of the post, then these targeted messages between the community acting as moderators and the poster, that are about the improvement of the post, can be filtered out of the main feed when the issues raised in the comment are addressed in the post.
>
> > This helps over time to remove the many comments that become out of date after changes are made to the post. If the poster of the comment can tick a box to say they are satisfied that their issue has been addressed, thus retrieving their -rep and downvote (they don't have to upvote) then the public default view of comments is now sanitised of the superfluous fluff.

Ultimately a downvote only has an impact on low rated questions,
From a simple point of view I see these issues around votes that prevent down-votes:

- -1 rep, this is a non-trivial cost to low rep users, *who make up the majority of SO users*, but in general SO is a competition where we are compared on our rep level, and even ranked by week/month/qtr/year on how much that rep level increases so choosing to spend that rep means we have justified the cost to our rep, or we think we will get that rep back (keep reading)
- Upvotes however are further incentivised at the lower level with badges for prolific up-voting, so those of us achievement hunters will upvote because there is a badge and because we hope others will find our own posts useful and will upvote them. This leads to our swarm mindset of upvote posts that already have lots of votes because we remotely agree with them, which stays with us out of habit once we have achieved the badges.
- There is little point to down-voting a post that has a higher number of votes, even 10 becomes a barrier that seems too high. A downvote becomes lost, and is practically invisible, this post that was 10, is now 9... which compared to zeros or negatives in the other posts, this is still the answer that everyone else agrees with, so it will keep receiving support from the community. Even if there is no further support from the community it's still going to take 10 other people to agree with me that it's worth the rep to get this post below zero, meaning my contribution has little effect on the system until other people agree.

  - If 10+ people like this post, chances are I'm not going to get my -1 back.
  - Not only am I alone in my downvote, no one can support me because no one knows it might be worth a downvote. SO is all about participating and encouraging the *right* behaviours and responses, but my measly -1 makes less of a difference as the current vote count increases.

> The current pack-mentality around downvotes does actually encourage downvotes, much in the same way that a positive posts will continue to receive upvotes, once a post goes below zero, it gets more negative attention and critical reviews that will likely receive more downvotes, we either agree slightly with the previous downvotes, and vote because we have or are giving support to the community (and are likely to get our rep back) it is only when we strongly disagree with the downvotes that we will upvote the post.

### Is there really an issue here?

A positive vote is "I find this useful or clear", which can attract an upvote for being clear, even if I know anything about the subject matter, however I can only really downvote if I understand at least some of the context behind the subject matter, because I can't make a good assessment of the structure of the response if I don't understand it at all, its not fair to downvote simply because I used the wrong query terms and are reading a post that is not relevant to me, or because solutions or versions have evolved and that post is not relevant to me, but may still be easily relevant to other users.

There is also statistical fact that over the lifetime of a post, a post that receives enough negative attention gets deleted or closed, which will no longer receive any posts, other than positive ones.

> Couple this with the observation that we wont generally downvote a post that has a positive vote count, meaning only zero or close to zero posts will *ever* attract downvotes

So there is a ceiling to how many downvotes any post can realistically achieve, conversely there is no limit to the upvotes a post can achieve so it makes sense that overtime, in a properly moderated site, only positive or neutral posts should remain in search responses, meaning that over time we actually expect that there would be an exponential difference between the number of upvotes and the number of downvotes.

---

I consider myself a representative of the general population, 1.2K up, 33 downvotes. I've only recently been granted the privilege of closing, so really I feel that this question directly targets me and people like me...

I upvote on good questions because "I found it useful" and the same for good answers, I hope that other people will vote my posts up in a similar manner.

I then have an internal hateful wrath-type response to any downvotes I get, because it's hard to attract the positives on specialised or technical tagged content that doesn't get many views, but also because I spend a lot of time on my posts, and I'm angry that even if I improve my post, that downvoter is not likely to come back to review my change, let alone spend the time to recast their vote, so the reality is that because the potential time delay and workflow between a downvote, and a potential improvement edit are so far removed that there is not a lot of point in trying to improve my post once I'm done, there isn't a great deal of benefit to myself or to those who downvoted in the first place, I've spent my time on that issue and moved on.

Answer (score -5):

I think part of the problem comes from the inability to distinguish between bad faith questions (low effort, clearly homework, etc.) and good faith questions which don’t fit the site (someone who clearly doesn’t know correct terminology or where to start/ too open ended, etc.)

Maybe move the "needs improvement" flag to its own button under downvote and give it some more specific options to why it's not good enough.

I know that I see questions frequently where I don't downvote it because it's not bad faith, but I would definitely tag it "too little info", or "unspecific".

Comment: You are confusing closure with voting. Votes are your opinion of the topic. Closing is a way for you to tell OP what needs to be improved. Besides, how does this apply to answers?

Answer (score -5):

> Many new users get very offended by a single downvote on their
> question, yet they have completely no objection for the upvotes. Why
> is that? ...

> Why is their perception of our voting systems so skewed?

**Imagine you were born and raised in a country where showing a middle finger is an extremely rude insult.** Then you go to a (fictitious) land where a middle finger signifies that you have dirt on your face, or that your zipper is open, and signals that you need to check yourself in a mirror. You leave your hotel to explore and people start giving you the finger. You are shocked and confused. A random person smiles and tries to hand you a pocket mirror whilst giving you the finger. You might run back to your hotel!

Yes, this traveler should have researched the 'documentation' about this country before visiting. But most people will not do that, or they skim through the guidebook and focus on the restaurants. Stack Overflow simply cannot change that behavior. Do you want to endlessly sigh about and be frustrated by new user behavior, or do you want to influence it?

**After a lifetime of using YouTube, Reddit, Facebook, etc., you can't expect users to 1) start reading user registration documentation before posting, and 2) immediately understand the different meaning of a Stack Overflow downvote.**

Further, it could be argued that to expect such adoption from new users means that *your* view is the skewed one.

What if you clicked on three dots or a hamburger, and instead of a menu you got a contact form? What if clicking on a heart didn't turn it into a red "like," but instead morphed it into a skull and crossbones? **When you see a thumbs-down, minus sign, or down-arrow, it means negging or dislike. It's a widely-used visual convention which has been employed for years.** 99% of the time, clicking on a down-arrow does NOT mean "not useful," it means dislike. So what? Who cares about the expected behavior of an icon/button...

Remember when the MS Windows 10 update dialog on Windows 7 introduced a different behavior for the red "X"? Users were upset and confused. They had been trained for years that a red "X" meant close the dialog and do not apply changes. Now suddenly the red "X" closed the dialog AND agreed to the changes.

Users need to be re-educated on the red X (the down-arrow) or they will be upset and confused. Stack Overflow fails at this because they place this education in the user registration/agreement, etc. -- this will be skimmed or not read at all by a new user.

> Do we have any ideas about what we could do or change to encourage people to spend a little bit more of their votes on downvoting posts?

Most users *skip* the Stack Overflow user agreements/documentation -- think about when you register for a Facebook account or an Amazon account: who actually reads the terms of use, behavior policy, etc.? Most people whip through it -- "blah blah, no sexy posts, no foul language, we may track you, blah blah, now click 'OK'" -- because they presume it is boilerplate.

**But Stack Overflow user documentation contain the vital piece of information that voting on Stack Overflow is** ***not*** **like voting on the rest of the web. It gets skipped/skimmed because it is assumed to be just part of the usual boilerplate.**

**Find a way to *put it in the user's face* that Stack Overflow downvotes are completely different in meaning than other sites.** Some rough ideas to get the brainstorming going:

- Make them go through a quick training before posting, where they must
  correctly up/downvote sample posts on a tag of their choosing, or give rep for passing such a
  training
- Grey-out certain functions until they pass a short quiz on the documentation about voting, or something equally attention-grabbing (or award avatar hats/caps like the winter caps for passing the quiz)
- Gamify the documentation on voting -- popups with "one of these
  things is not like the other"-type comparisons between an Stack Overflow downvote and other sites

TLDR: Stack Overflow must manage the expectations of new users, who have been trained by years of using 'voting' icons/buttons on other websites. Simply railing against new users' perceptions will accomplish nothing since these visual conventions are deeply ingrained -- innovative changes to the registration and voting processes are needed to ensure understanding of voting.

Comment: *Most users SKIP the SO user agreements/docs* This is their fault, not SO's. Encouraging laziness is not a good idea in my opinion. And *docs* are already gamified, you earn a badge when you take the tour.

Comment: You can't upvote until you gain some reputation. You can't downvote until you gain some more. We would need to change how we give people the privileges so that they would be better understood.

Comment: Are downvotes considered "rude" on YouTube, Facebook, Reddit, or any of the other sites you listed? I've never considered them to be such, and I wasn't aware that anyone else did. On YouTube, for example, they just mean "I like this" and "I didn't like this". That's not altogether different from what the vote arrows mean on Stack Overflow. I don't buy the argument for a culture clash.

Comment: *"Remember when the MS Windows 10 update dialog on Windows 7 introduced a different behavior for the red "X"?* Yeah, and people were pissed; Microsoft was deliberately altering the functionality for this one scenario.  Before, and since, it's *always* closed the window.  That doesn't work as an example because we're not changing the meaning.  People are just assuming it means something it actually doesn't.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't think I ever said that downvotes were considered rude on other sites?

Comment: @oguzismail Go ahead and completely ignore user behavior, then. Yes there is a badge -- obviously it is not enough to overcome the conventional meaning of a down arrow icon (otherwise we would not be having this discussion)

Comment: @fbueckert SO is not changing the meaning of the down arrow icon, correct -- on this site, a down arrow has never meant dislike. BUT for a new user who has been surfing the web for years and using down arrows everywhere to express dislike, it is a sea change.

Comment: @CodyGray I see where you got that idea. It's only an analogy with the middle finger substituting for a down arrow icon -- as I stated, a middle finger would be rude, and a down arrow means "dislike". I never said that a down arrow is rude. Many other sites use down arrow icons -- SO is the only place (that I can think of) where a down arrow isn't supposed to imply dislike. Do you think that could confuse a new user?

Comment: The downvote arrow definitely implies "dislike" on Stack Overflow, so that's not different. Yes, I got confused when you related the downvote button to the middle finger.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't see the word "dislike" on this page anywhere. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down If you are using the down-arrow in the same way as a Facebook thumb, perhaps you are overusing it. -- yes, those words are in the tooltip.

Comment: Nor do I see the words "unclear", "not interesting", "not useful", "lacks research effort", or any of the other dozens of reasons why someone might downvote a post. That page doesn't provide, and isn't intended to provide, a comprehensive list. Downvotes have meant "dislike" since literally their introduction, just as upvotes have meant "like". It's just that on Stack Overflow and other technical Q&A sites, we generally have a *reason* that we don't like something: for example, not useful, not clear, no research effort, etc.

Comment: @CodyGray If I "dislike" a reddit comment, of course I have a reason -- I didn't like the tone, maybe I don't like their username.  An SO "like" supposedly has nuance, deeper than social media REACTION buttons. SO retains the same old iconography as social media, then expects NEW users to get the different nuance! >sigh< Four separate buttons labeled "unclear", "not interesting", "not useful", "lacks research effort" would be more objective. "Dislike" is subjective.

Comment: There are no nuanced differences; that's the entire point of my comment. People regularly downvote things on Reddit because they are unclear, not interesting, not useful, etc. Yes, the expectation of research effort is slightly different, and our quality standards are higher here, but that isn't a property of the *voting* system. Even on Stack Exchange, all votes are subjective: they represent my opinion about the quality/usefulness/appropriateness of the post.

Comment: @CodyGray SO's UI utilizes one of the most universally-accepted internet icons for "dislike for any reason you choose" (second perhaps only to the thumbs-down,) but then expects new users to click it strictly when signifying "unclear", "not interesting", "not useful", "lacks research effort", "egregiously sloppy", "no-effort-expended", "clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect". 
Only confusion can come from such a dichotomy! smh... Good night and may the force be with you, Cody.

Comment: No. You keep reiterating a claim that I have denied since my very first comment. The downvote arrow means "dislike for any reason you choose". Users are literally allowed to vote, either up or down, for any reason they choose, as long as they are not committing vote fraud. There's no confusion here; you're just concocting a bunch of arbitrary stipulations on what votes mean that simply aren't there and were never intended to be there. The explanation that downvotes typically mean unclear/uninteresting/lacks research effort/etc. are just that: clarifications. They don't bind the button's usage.

Answer (score -5):

As a normal user, I just won't bother myself to downvote because I have no benefit from it even if I'm right. I would consider downvoting if:

- Remove the -1 on downvoting
- Add +2,5 if the post was somewhat closed or deleted.
- Some badges too

Comment: Isn't giving a signal to future readers a good enough incentive?

Comment: I would be in my way doing my work, it is just too much to switch my attention and make a decision if there's no reward.

Comment: Curation is generally a thankless work indeed.

Comment: @E_net4thecurator [not for me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386671/839601), "...To me, Stack Overflow is a tool. I use this tool in my job and I just need to keep it sharp."

Comment: Sometimes I stumble back on posts that I had referred to in the past and my downvotes/upvotes help me remember which answer worked for me. Sometimes the 'future reader' that @Dharman mentioned in their comment could be you yourself! Isn't that a good enough reason to downvote, considering that it will only take a fraction of a second now but could save you hours of re-reading ;)

Comment: I kinda like these - though perhaps not all at once. Downvoting seems to have a stigma attached that is *just* bad, and the rep system currently sends the same message. Having *some* effect that shows downvotes are encouraged, not just tolerated, could be useful - even if it might not be significant for the people who downvote.

Comment: Being 100% extrinsically motivated is one state of being. It is probably the reason the gamification on Stack Overflow on the whole works so well. But do consider the benefits of intrinsic motivation.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Remove the -1 on downvoting"*? That downvoting an ***answer*** should not cost one reputation point (unlike questions)? Or downvotes should not be shown or count? Or something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes, it should not cost anything

Answer (score -6):

This question contains multiple questions. This makes it hard to give a complete answer, which is why such questions are usually closed as too broad and downvoted. I'm surprised this one is not. So I will attempt to answer some of your questions.

> Many new users get very offended by a single downvote on their question, yet they have completely no objection for the upvotes. Why is that? Why so many users demand that the downvotes be accompanied by an explanatory comment yet nobody demands an explanation for the upvotes?

I will first focus on downvotes on questions. I think you are confusing close votes and downvotes. Unless questions are beyond hope and should be closed, downvotes are a signal to the writer that he should improve his question. In order to do this, the writer usually needs input on what the problem is with the question. However he does not need input for an upvote, as it does not require him to change anything.

Now to answers. Here I think downvotes without explanation are appropriate, if the answers in your opinion is wrong. However if the downvote is given to a correct answer, because you want the answer to contain more information/sources or something, then you should tell the writer. Otherwise this correct answer that could be very useful will be on the bottom of all answers and grayed out and that does not help anyone.

> Do people really value the fake Internet points so much or is it about acceptance by strangers? Why is their perception of our voting systems so skewed?

I and probably many other people value downvotes and upvotes so much, because they influence how many people will see their text.
If I ask a question then I hope for an answer. Early downvotes without explanation will lead to less people seeing my question and therefore I have a lower chance of getting an answer.
For answers I personally care less about downvotes. However I can feel some effect, if I posted an answer I put effort into finding the information or at least writing the text like this one. If I get downvotes that means that it is less likely that people will see it and the effort was less worth it. Again, if the answer is wrong then I totally think downvotes are appropriate.

Comment: Nope. I answered many questions after downvoting and editing them. Strange move, but I expressed an opinion that I think the question is a poor question, but it is answerable and the answers can help others in future. If I wanted OP to improve the question I would vote to close.

Comment: It is kind of the point that if we downvote we are sending signal for future readers that it is not worth reading in our opinion. -1 or -2 on a question is not the end of the world, because people still open such questions. At least I do. What makes me stay away from is the title and tags. If you can't write a good title and the question is at zero it is likely you will not catch my attention.

Comment: Meta works a little differently. Here questions can ask for opinions and sometimes be quite broad. However, I asked a simple question "*Do we have any ideas about what we could do or change to encourage people to spend a little bit more of their votes on downvoting posts?*" Sub-questions were mostly to spark a discussion.

Comment: @Dharman That is confusing. So you downvote a question because it is poor, but you do not want him to improve it? Why? And you mark for future readers that it is not worth reading in your opinion, yet you give an answer because it may help others in the future?  How can it be not worth reading but at the same time helpful?

Comment: The downvotes aren't for the poster, @findusl.  They're for *everyone else* that comes after the poster, so they know it's not a good question.  That's why voting doesn't require accompanying comments for improvement.

Comment: You should evaluate the usefulness of each post in separation. Bad question does not mean answers are bad. I don't think there is more room for improvement with the question and it is answerable as is.

Comment: @fbueckert then why would you not close it? For me a question is either useful in future or it is not. If it is not, then it should be closed, if it is then it should not but then the downvotes don't make sense either. I seem to miss something here. Do you have an example of a question that you think should not be closed, is not good and cannot be improved?

Comment: Questions are not like answers. I totally understand downvotes on this answer, which indicate you think I'm wrong. However a question cannot be "right" or "wrong". As you probably heard in school so often, the only stupid question, is the one you are not asking. Of course there are exceptions (duplicates, too broad etc), but those should be closed.

Comment: A bad question doesn't automatically mean an off-topic question.  They're two different actions that can sometimes overlap, but don't have to.  Up/down voting is for post utility.  Close voting is for questions that meet one of the close criteria.  Quite often there are questions that nominally meet the criteria for being on-topic, but are so poorly written or just plain bad that they need downvoting.  You don't close a question because it's bad.  That's what downvoting is for.

Comment: @fbueckert how can a question be "bad" but not by any of the closing categories? Do you have any example? Just because you don't like the programming language used in it or why?

Comment: @fbueckert badly written questions can be improved. Read Dharman's first comment on this.

Comment: Yes, bad questions can be improved.  But you don't vote on what the question *might* be.  You vote on what it *is*.  For bad questions that are not closeworthy, peruse any high traffic tag; you'll find many low-effort questions that scrape by just enough to garner downvotes, but not close votes.

Comment: @fbueckert Exactly. So downvotes should be used on questions that can be improved. And therefore it is completely understandable that people would like to know what they should improve, when downvotes are cast. My point in this answer. However Dharman in his first comment mentioned "If I wanted OP to improve the question I would vote to close". And then I no longer understand what downvotes are for.

Comment: All of this comes back to our primary purpose: to be a high quality repository of programming knowledge, meant to withstand the test of time.  Downvotes are a very important part of that to ensure that what we have can last for a long time.  They're meant to impart that to the potential millions of future readers that the post isn't very useful, but since it's still there, it might have some info worth keeping.

Comment: No.  Downvotes *are not to help the poster improve*.  Never have been, and never will be.  We are not a help desk.  People definitely want help, and often get it, but that's a byproduct of how Q&A works; we build the repository through people asking for help, but make no mistake, that help is, and always will be, *secondary* to our primary mission.

Comment: @fbueckert I never claimed that they are meant to help the poster improve. I claim that downvotes request the poster to improve. That is a difference.

Comment: That's a misunderstanding of their purpose.  They don't request anything.  They provide a judgement of the post's utility.

Comment: @fbueckert That is only partially true, because close votes fulfil the same task. To me the difference between close votes and downvotes is, a closed voted post is so bad it can't be fixed (duplicate, off topic), a downvoted post is theoretically good, just badly made. And the latter could be improved to be made good. Do I get that right?

Comment: No, close votes don't fill the same task.  They prevent answers to questions.  They don't judge utility.  They are two orthogonal concepts that work in tandem, but for different purposes.  Often questions are closed because they will attract bad answers until the poster has a chance to improve it, and then it can be reopened.

Comment: @fbueckert I feel like we are just stuck on some word specifics. You yourself wrote "Yes, bad questions can be improved". Therefore a downvote indicates that an improvement to this post could be made. Whether that is now a "request" or not, doesn't really matter. It is indicated that an improvement could be made, therefore it is imho understandable that the original writer would like to see an explanation accompany it, a "help". Yes of course it is not the primary purpose of this site to provide this help. However It is completely understandable that the writer would like to have it.

Comment: Given that, I do not understand your statement about "The downvotes aren't for the poster". I can see how some bad questions cannot be improved, like duplicates or off-topic questions, although even for those it might be possible by reformulating the question. However if none of these close reasons apply, then a question can imho always be improved, and therefore the down vote is an indication ("request") to the writer to do so. It can also be information for future readers, nobody says it can only do one job. (I will now go to sleep, please do not feel offended if I do not answer)

Comment: Downvotes don't mean improvements can be made to the post.  They mean the voter found the post not useful.  The post itself may or may not be able to be improved, but that's irrelevant to the purposes of voting.  It's there so people in the future know that the post has problems, not that the problems can be fixed.  The *primary* reason people complain about downvotes is because they don't understand what they're for.  There are such things as bad questions, unable to be improved; that's why the question ban exists.

Comment: If downvotes were not originally for the poster, then as a community we have certainly adopted them for this purpose. I find the close vote process a bit obnoxious for feedback to the poster because posts are generally closed quicker than OP can respond and after a change they are very rarely re-opened. Downvote as feedback fits the timeline better for the average duration that it takes OP to respond and the mechanism allows for recast after an edit, all that is missing is a notification that an edit occurred, would we like to review the edit and recast our vote.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Care to point out, where, exactly, the community has adopted that sentiment?

Comment: @fbueckert I'm one user who has always assumed this to be the case, but a simple review of the posts on this question shows a general divide in sentiment that other users have either come to this conclusion, or they share yours. It probably originates from the triage queue, where we cannot vote to close yet, but we are encouraged to downvote if a post needs improvement, upvote if we think it is a good post. The wording has changed slightly over the years, but that's our first exposure to the mechanism in terms of users performing moderation, perhaps that's a good place affect change?

Comment: @fbueckert why would you keep posts that are not useful and cannot be improved. those should be simply closed. That is what close votes are for. That is also why such people are question banned, as you noted so nicely yourself. The site does not want their questions. Downvotes are not for such questions that we don't want. downvotes are for bad questions that can be improved, not for non useful questions. Non useful questions should be closed as they are of no use to the site.

Comment: @fbueckert I just fail to see how a question cannot be improved but at the same time should not be closed. There are certainly questions that just based on their intent and content are of no use to the site, but then those questions should be closed. What is the point in keeping them open? You seem to be messing up the downvotes and the close votes. A question ban has a similar effect as close votes, it can be seen as preventive closing all questions from the user. That is not technically correct, but it would have the same effect, in the sense that the question will not show up.

Comment: No, that is *not* what close votes are for.  Close votes are an indicator of *topicality*, not utility.  Often there are questions that are both bad (downvote), and fit one of the close reasons (close vote).  But they are *two different systems*.  They're not meant to achieve the same goal.  Downvotes are for bad posts.  Whether it should be closed or not is *immaterial*.  Whether it can be improved is *irrelevant*.  If a post is bad, downvote it.  If it meets one of the closure criteria, vote to close.  They can be combined, but are not required.

Comment: Again, *look at questions in popular tags*.  There are likely plenty of questions that are nominally on-topic, bad, should be downvoted, *but not closed*.  [tag:vba] is usually a good place to find some, too.  The point in keeping them open is because they don't meet the close reasons; they can potentially garner answers that help build the repository of knowledge, and thereby help future readers.

Answer (score -7):

**TL;DR** I think downvotes should be [renamed](https://youtu.be/UANN2Eu6ZnM?t=437) and completely reworked in their logic. The current name and design will necessarily imply negative feelings and will therefore never be used as extensively as it could (emotions > pragmatism).

---

After reading answers here I can say one thing: Even people on meta don't agree on what downvotes on questions are made for. We should work on that first. Otherwise every discussion is pointless.

#### Lack of decision implies lack of clarity

People hanging out here are far more informed than the average Stack Overflow user and still it doesn't seem like a consensus is emerging. Therefore it's very unlikely that there would be a consensus in the broader community of active Stack Overflow users (and even less likely over all Stack Overflow users).

Which means: **people have no clue about what is expected from them**.

The question is even broader than that and I really feel like the problem is related to poor communication on the expected behaviour. I think the rules cover too many subjects and also are too specific. If the site's macroscopic intents were clear, then only people who haven't read the rules would disagree on the general intents of Stack Overflow. But in reality **even meta-users still argue on what Stack Overflow is** (not what it should be because that would be totally fine). Someone need to make a decision. Consensus is only good when it can be reached in a reasonable amount of time. And decisions should be communicated widely and clearly, Stack Overflow lacks authority and "positioning" (at least that's what I perceive as a simple user).

#### Where does this problem come from?

I would say from the root of the problem is in the [*Help center* page](https://stackoverflow.com/help). It's cool if you search for an answer, but **most people will never ask themselves how they should use Stack Overflow**. And if they do, they want a short, simple answer that covers all subjects at once. Not a very detailed description of all possible sub-cases.

#### How can we communicate Stack Overflow intents better?

That's the real question here I think. For example, to encourage downvotes, the first thing needed is to **define what a vote is** (what it's made for and what's its intent). It's not even worth arguing before this is clear.

This is a very hard question to answer and there is no perfect solution for this. But there is one thing I think could help. I think the [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) should start with a vision, a short presentation of Stack Overflow's intents (similarly to what have been done in the [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), but for [how to use the tool](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), not how to behave like a human being).

I know many people won't ever go to this page, but the simple fact that it exists could be a tool for us to agree on something simple enough that it can be read and approved quickly. It would also be a communication tool. If someone clearly is off-topic, you could send them to this page so they have a rough idea of the philosophy in a few seconds. I feel like this is something Python managed to do quite well with [The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) (the idea [isn't quite new](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Ten_Commandments), but it has proven to work well in practice). It doesn't necessarily define precise actions to take, but it draws a clear philosophical line, starting from that people have their own interpretation, but at least they all move in the same direction, each acting in the best possible way to fit to the "Zen".

We could use some of the *guiding principles* from `this` to describe Stack Overflow's intents. In particular I think these apply in this case:

```
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Flat is better than nested.
Readability counts.
Errors should never pass silently.
```

#### What about downvotes!?

I won't talk about communication too much, because that's really not my strong suit.

On the other hand, I'll point out problems and provide some leads to possible answers. First, I don't know what downvotes on questions are intended for so I will only focus on downvotes for answers (questions should be closed or edited. I don't see a middle-ground having any sense here). For answers it's a bit clearer because answers can be wrong (while questions can't). But yet my opinion is that downvotes on answers are not made to say "this answer is wrong" (I'll come back to this).

I would suggest to rename answers' downvotes to **not ideal** or something similar conveying the same idea (for example, as [Raymond Hettinger](https://github.com/rhettinger) loves to say: [*There must be a better way*](https://youtu.be/UANN2Eu6ZnM?t=437)). Let me explain why. There are several kinds of "bad answers" and each of them already have a corresponding action:

- Faulty/wrong (or worse) answers should be flagged (and later deleted).
- Inaccurate/outdated/unclear answers should be edited to add the missing details.
- Non-exhaustive answers should be quoted in the answer you are about to write to cover the missing parts.
- You feel like the answer is bad, but you are unsure then comments are very useful. Same if there is some ambiguity/subjectivity in the answer.

The only thing that remains are answers that are **not ideal**, pieces of code that work, but they are not very performant/elegant or are not representative of how people usually write it … You get the idea. These answers aren't really bad; they are just not the best you could imagine. The only thing we want for them is to not appear first, thus the "downvote". The downvote says "ok, this answer isn't bad, but there is a better way" (at least that's how I use it).

[Words are very important](https://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2015/12/the-book-of-human-emotions-language-feelings/420978/) and when you "downvote" an answer it's necessarily negatively perceived by the other. I mean it has "down" in it. How could it be positive or even neutral? The same goes with the icon associated to it, a down arrow. That's maybe one of the worst possible images you could have in your head. (Changing the name of answers' downvote would inevitably come with rethinking the icon.) We are empathetic creatures, and if we don't like "down-stuff" we don't use "down-stuff" on others. That's why downvotes are so rarely used.

Rewarding someone will not turn him/her into a "monster", so that's probably not a viable solution either. Getting `-1` rep is nothing compared to the risk of causing pain. Most people probably don't care about the `-1`, unless maybe people that don't tend to ask/answer questions. If you hate receiving downvotes, you won't give downvote. It is as simple as that. (I'm sure we could observe a correlation between the two.)

Going back to the renaming idea, I think finding the right name/design is far from being easy and it should be tested (new users would be perfect A/B-test subjects). This should also come with communication around the intents (same as before, if the intent aren't clear and simple, it won't be used as expected and negative feelings may arise even from the best design/idea).

It would also be interesting to have dynamic triggers, for example, if the user have:

- not upvoted any question in the thread
- marked a question as "not ideal"

It would trigger a small popup with message to invite him/her to either write a better answer or to pick an existing better answer (this of course will only show occasionally and could be deactivated for more experienced users).

In general I think we should also invite people to interact more with other peoples' answers (quoting/answering problems from other questions). But that's another topic.

Answer (score -10):

If a user hits the daily reputation cap, they can spend, for example, 10 downvotes on low-quality answers, not-an-answer answers, etc. and then they'll be able to earn the 10 rep back when their post gets another upvote non-disturbed by the reputation cap.

Often such downvoted answers get deleted, returning the reputation spent by the ones who downvoted them, so to encourage users to downvote: Downvoting is already a way to get more out of the daily reputation cap.

Comment: How often an average user reaches the rep-cap? Once a year? Perhaps twice?

Comment: An "average user"? Probably closer to "never" than "once a year", I guess.

Comment: As hinted by the other comments, we would prefer an incentive which applies to most users, and not just to those who regularly hit the reputation cap. Not to mention that those who do (hit the rep cap) already have a lot of reputation to spare.

Comment: Any user who regularly gets rep-capped is surely clever enough to not care about meaningless internet points.

Comment: @yivi That makes me above-average. I'm not ready for that

Comment: If you get 200 rep a day then surely it's not a problem for you to spend 40 points downvoting answers.

Comment: it's relatively hard to stay in the negative from just casting downvotes. I've probably thrown away 10k+ rep at this point... the problem isn't getting people who are active and willing to downvote downvoting... it's getting those who'd rather leave a comment and take no action at all to actually use the tools available to them.

Comment: Heck, I get like an upvote a week and I downvote about 20 answers in 3 to 4 days. I've lost a good amount of reputation. And also, if you hit the rep cap, downvote answers and hit the rep cap again, you just landed back in square one. So how does it motivate high rep users to downvote if they don't gain reputation?

Comment: @10Rep Included in my post... *"such answers often get deleted, returning the rep"* :)

Comment: @AnnZen for instance, if I downvote a post at the 200 rep cap, I now only gained 199 rep that day. Then when the answer gets deleted (not guaranteed to happen all the time) I just get that 1 rep back. There's no _actual_ gain, meaning this isn't guaranteed to motivate people to downvote for rep. And anyways, having people downvote for rep seems like... a bad idea, no? :)

Comment: @10Rep No no, I mean downvoting after we reach the daily rep cap will allow potential upvotes on our posts to fill in the gap. So say we received 20 upvotes; we downvote 10 times, and then when we get another upvote, the rep cap won't disturb the 10 rep. Addressing the *"having people downvote for rep seems like... a bad idea"*: reasonable, but the highly agreed on "Remove the -1 rep cost of downvoting an answer" is also a similar concept.

Comment: Your idea would work for some users but there are lots of 10k users who wouldn't see the benefit. (I could personally name some users who wouldn't care). But I do get your point.

Comment: @10Rep I know, I can name many users too :) Actually, another 10K+ user made me aware of this, so I just thought I'd share it.

Answer (score -12):

#### This is a misguided question based on many false premises.

> Downvoting ... plays a crucial role in keeping the content on this site clean.

1. You're assuming it is clean... actually, some of the unclean stuff is highly over-voted, IMHO.
2. Like other answers suggest, downvoting has many reasons, some justified, some - not really or not at all.
3. Closure and deletion has a more crucial role in keeping the site clean.

> Downvoting is our most powerful tool for us, non-moderator users.

You also have other tools - close votes and flags; not the same purpose as downvotes, but these are pretty powerful. With downvotes you just get a lot of "ammo" and nobody can second-guess you.

**edit:** Actually, upon reflection, I'd say the *comment* is a more powerful, and more versatile, tool than any of the above. (Especially if it's one of the first comments on a post.)

> Downvotes are a strong signal both to future readers and the author of the post that something is wrong

On other Stack Exchange sites, maybe. On SO - downvoting is more often a sign of a newbie being ganged up on for not realizing how things work around here.

> and the experts on this site deem the post to be of little value for future readers.

Almost any user can vote, so - it's really not about the experts.

> As everyone knows we rate content, not the users.

That's at best half-true. I'm sure most newbie users would say otherwise.

> Votes are not meant to be friendly or offensive.

They are effectively, usually, friendly (upvote) or offensive (downvote). Trying to deny the psychological aspect of this action is sticking your head in the sand. Also, what they're "meant to be" doesn't matter that much; they are what they are.

> There's no shame in using the downvote button just as there is no shame in using the upvote button whenever you like.

I've seen a lot of shameful downvoting here on SO. I've also seen some semi-shameful upvoting, but that's more rare. Anyway, either the first or both these statements are false.

> It is our own personal choice how we rate the content

And yet, here you are asking for this supposedly personal choice to be socially manipulated...

#### Bottom line

- Do downvote - but with care, not with ease.
- Leave a comment explaining your downvote.
- Help users (especially new users) improve their posts rather torpedoing them immediately with your downvote.

Comment: "*You can cast close votes.*" not on answers.

Comment: @VLAZ: You're right, there are also flags.

Comment: Most of said flags on answers would be declined as not what flags are for.

Comment: Which flag is the preferable one for an answer that *tries to address* the question but is flawed in its implementation? How do I flag low effort answers that are technically correct but are posted under the Nth dupe to the same thing that shows up at least three times a week?

Comment: @VLAZ: I didn't say flags should be used instead of downvotes. But - you should also not use downvotes instead of flags.

Comment: You should use flags with downvotes. Use close votes with downvotes.

Comment: @Dharman: Oh no, it's the opposite! Don't downvote because of a closure reason.  off-topic != bad.

Comment: @einpoklum: I highly disagree (except for duplicates). An off-topic question should be downvoted to show other users that there is a problem with that post and that they might be wasting there time with it.

Comment: @BDL: Until it has been closed as off-topic, a question has "grace"; leave a comment explaining the situation, but don't downvote it... remember: "Downvote ... question if you find it unclear or not useful." If, other than being off-topic, it doesn't meet this criterion, it doesn't merit the downvote. Also remember, that if users find it, it likely means they were looking for something similar to it. So it is not obvious they will be wasting their time.

Comment: If it's off-topic, it's inherently not useful. People founding questions doesn't make it on-topic or more useful. I could post a question about cooking, which people could be interested in, nevertheless it's off-topic and not useful on SO. I can also post a debugging question without code which is for sure not useful.

Comment: @BDL: It's not been declared as off-topic. What if it doesn't gather enough close votes and stays up? And - if it's _obviously_ off-topic, then people don't need your downvote to realize that.

Comment: All the more reason to also down vote, because while the close vote ages away, the downvote stays to indicate that you did not find the question useful.

Comment: @cafce25: On the contrary - that's all the more reason not to downvote, since if the close votes do not amount to a close and age away, that means the post should _not_ have been closed, and the downvote due to close-ability was unmerited.

Comment: You've got a twisted reasoning there, the vote is yours, others not agreeing on the CV does not bear any influence on wether your down vote was valid at all.

Comment: Also close votes aging away is often just because there are too many questions and to few moderating them, not because the question shouldn't be closed.

Comment: @cafce25: If you downvoted because of a close-reason, rather than finding the post otherwise unuseful, then you concede your vote being invalid and are just sticking it to the user. And if you downvoted because the post is not useful even when considered as on-topic for the website, then it doesn't matter that you also think it should also be closed, and it's a perfectly valid downvote - which you should possibly also complement with a comment.

Comment: As I posted above, my point has been completely proven with this post being downvoted to hell despite making points that are actually correct. SO is NEVER going to change as so many people are in denial about its problems. You identified them and then just did nothing to fix them. How many years since that fateful blog post?

Answer (score -13):

"downvotes are treated as toxic behaviour" because often enough, they are.

I've seen plenty of good questions get downvoted for no apparent reason; what's the OP supposed to do with that? Next time the same OP considers downvoting a Q/A, s/he may think back to own experience and figure that an explanation is warranted for a downvote (thus not bother), or be more lenient. I've also seen questions get upvoted that perform clearly worse per same criterion that users cited for downvoting/closing.

So it's a "luck of the draw" depending on who's watching the question at a given moment - and the effect is *powerful*; if first two votes are positive, the rest of the votes are likely to be positive - and vice versa. Existing votes appear to have clear influence on future voters. Thus, downvoting can be legitimately perceived as outright destroying a question - so if a user is to cast one, there better be a very good reason for it (as opposed to upvoting).

I haven't run analytics on my own claims, you're free to validate; they're based on observing the `python`, `keras`, and `tensorflow` tags. I also haven't tracked every single example I've come across, but I will paste two:

---

> [image]

"More focused" is hardly a valid reason here; the question clearly asks for one thing. The "real" reason for this response is the lack of apparent effort put into the question - fair enough. What isn't fair is the first-time poster's question getting torn apart within the very first minute of posting; to you "SO veterans" this may seem like nothing, but just ask the average low-rep user of *their* experience.

---

> [image]

Now *this* should've been downvoted and closed for the exact cited reason the above question was. Plenty of questions were closed for asking users to effectively "write software" (chunks of code to meet a goal) for them - this is what the question's doing, yet it's positively received, and [it still is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60016011/10133797), 100+ views later, agreeing with "positives stay positive". Why's it positive? Because other [Chainer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chainer) users wanted to know the same answer. Then, users look at this question and see it upvoted, then compare to their own much higher-effort, better-articulated question, and see it downvoted, and call bullsh!t - and I agree.

Comment: *Now this should've been downvoted and closed for the exact cited reason the above question was* --> so where is your downvote and your close vote on it?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Fair question. My answer isn't exhaustive - let's just say at the time I had a net-reason against doing it, and now I just didn't touch it to keep my screenshot and argument valid.

Comment: *and the effect is powerful; if first two votes are positive, the rest of the votes are likely to be positive* --> this is not true, I was able to close/delete question highly upvoted that doesn't meet the quality criteria or are trivial duplicate. I also did it for HNQ question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59559606/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif Good - doesn't always happen. And for my tags, far from "always" - and that's the problem.

Comment: You are argument can be *more* valid if you casted a close vote and it was still open and upvoted. Maybe you close vote will pull it to oblivion

Comment: Downvotes are mostly a signal to everyone, not just the poster. And the fact that the scores of some questions may seem completely random is yet another reason to bring more downvotes in, to counter the excess upvotes. The experience around the tags that you mention are skewed because they receive different moderation attention and are also a bit more likely to attract low quality questions (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352404). That last screenshot shows a question that would indeed be downvoted and close. The meta effect ought to take care of that now.

Comment: Still you didn't give us a potential solution to this. You pointed a problem but what do you suggest to solve the misuse of downvotes? or how to increase the use of downvotes on question that deserve it?

Comment: I'm not sure if it was accidental or intentional, but **this answer is a very good example of why we need to encourage more downvoting**. That second question, as with many other low-effort questions that don't meet our quality standards, should have had more downvotes.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I agree on a need for a solution, and I have one in mind - though unsure to edit it in this post or make a new one, as this one's already going downhill. It's a fairly simple yet far-reaching proposition, and can easily take up a Q&A of its own.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use *"bovine fecal matter"*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Whatnow?

Comment: @CodyGray, perhaps I misunderstood, but I took the point to be that encouraging downvotes will just magnify this trend without changing it at all. In other words, things that get downvotes will get more downvotes; things that don't get downvotes will still not get downvotes. In general, I find it difficult to understand why people assume that more downvotes implies better downvotes. Is there any evidence of that at all?

Comment: @sen If there are more downvotes overall, why would you assume that their distribution would be uneven? Why would they not be scattered across all eligible posts? Certainly no one has said that more downvotes implies better downvotes. I...don't even know what "better" downvotes might be. What I see here is simply evidence of a low-quality question having been missed (i.e., having received no downvotes), and thus a failure of our quality control system. If we are encouraging more users to downvote, that increases the odds that one of those users will see questions like this and downvote them.

Comment: @senderle We don't claim that, but evidence shows that upvotes are cast much more freely even when not that warranted for the post at hand. In the tag I follow most, one may often find quick upvotes on questions which do not even have a minimal reproducible example. This is one of the main reasons for encouraging downvoting.

Comment: @CodyGray it sounds like you're saying that encouraging more users to downvote will increase the odds of those users seeing problem questions. What's the causal mechanism there?

Comment: @CodyGray or, to put it another way, you ask "why would you assume that their distribution would be uneven?" To me it seems confused to assume otherwise. If their distribution now is uneven, then it most likely will remain so.

Comment: I honestly don't think this answer should have been downvoted so many times. Anyone can disagree, but I see a lot of value of discussion in it, even though I may not agree with it as a whole.

Comment: @PaimanRoointan People are free to vote as they see fit. Saying that it has received enough downvotes leaves the idea that any upcoming votes, and therefore the opinion of the rest of the community, is unwanted. For what it's worth, the voting culture on Meta _is_ different. We can embrace it or give it some new directions. Perhaps you would like to [be able to use the "thank you" reaction on this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398550)?

Comment: @E_net4likesdownvotes yes the voting culture on meta does seem different.I'm not against people's freedom of voting, but downvoting makes an answer greyed out. Out of meta, this means the answer is useless or wrong and I normally ignore them. I was actually surprised by this answer greyed out.

Comment: @PaimanRoointan For what it's worth, [that used to be worse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268071).

Comment: I agree to the "self-amplifying effect" that you described, and also see it as a problem. And I cannot profoundly *judge* the examples that you posted (which is one of the main reasons why I rarely downvote, by the way). But considering the text and tags(!), the first one is a question about something that looks fairly trivial and might be covered in a "Hello, World"-Level Python tutorial, whereas the other could be a tough question about a common problem with the (highly specific!) techs that are involved, looking for a "good" solution. Is that perception wrong?

Comment: _“‘More focused’ is hardly a valid reason here”_ — the old wording for this close reason is “too broad”. Since the close vote reasons have changed (for the worse) some users have stated that they would pick a reason at random and cast a close vote with it.

Comment: @CodyGray, when we talk about quality we must consider not only Q and A but also Search Query and Search behavior. The "less quality" Q are harder to answer but does may still be effective to translate the same "less quality" search query to "qualiy" answer. As downvoting affects ranking mechanism it's encouraging may destroy this not so obviuos power of Stackoverflow. The quality will increase by constructive and creative steps not by subjective criticism as  downvoting is.

Comment: @Egor If I understand you correctly, what you describe is exactly why we keep around questions that have been closed as a duplicate. The idea is that these questions serve as "pointers" to the main question, as they use different descriptions/keywords that might make the content easier to find. Such duplicate "pointers" are not necessarily useless, and therefore may not deserve downvotes. However, there are plenty of other types of low-quality posts here (questions and answers alike) that *do* deserve downvotes but don't receive them. This discussion is trying to solve that problem.

Comment: @CodyGray, exactly, the matching the less quality Q with the better ones is more efficiant way to improve both the quality and the search experience. Form my side I fill lack of instument to mark obvious dublicates, may be my reputation score is not enough for that. Matching is a constructive, creative approach avoiding us from any form of subjective and potentially hate behavior. Probably, downvoting should not have a publicity visible effects, instead the downvotes should be used in internal researches, labeling data and developing automatic matching mechanisms?

Answer (score -14):

Possibly a radical idea here, but how about we **don't?**

The question says:

> As everyone knows we rate content, not the users. Votes are not meant to be friendly or offensive...
> Many new users get very offended by a single downvote on their question, yet they have completely no objection for the upvotes. Why is that? Why so many users demand that the downvotes be accompanied by an explanatory comment yet nobody demands an explanation for the upvotes? Do people really value the fake Internet points so much or is it about acceptance by strangers? Why is their perception of our voting systems so skewed?

First of all,

> As everyone knows

Not everyone knows, especially not new users.

> we rate content, not the users.

That doesn't ring completely true. The ratings on content aggregate up to a rating (rep score) on the user. Upvotes and downvotes directly affect the user's rating in the community and ability to participate more fully.

> Many new users get very offended by a single downvote on their question, yet they have completely no objection for the upvotes. Why is that? Why so many users demand that the downvotes be accompanied by an explanatory comment yet nobody demands an explanation for the upvotes? ...

At its core, anonymous downvotes without explanation say "You have failed to meet our community standards in some way, but we won't tell you how, or give you any clear indication of how you can improve to do better next time."  That's the opposite of welcoming; it sends the message that the person and their contributions are not wanted in the community: not in their present state, and not even though they are willing to improve if they only knew how...the community doesn't even think it's worth working with the person to welcome them in with corrections to minor shortcomings.  That may not be the message the downvoter intended to send, but it's often the message received, especially by newcomers.  Experienced users who recognize this won't click the downvote button to send a message they have reason to believe will likely not be received as sent.

Upvotes, with or without comments, send the message that the contribution is valued in the community and encourage contribution of "more content like this" which the contributor already knows how to do, so they would not feel a need to request additional details.

Stack Overflow Inc's goals and direction for the site seem to be focused on "welcoming at all expense, regardless of what the veteran users might think or want," even overriding/violating established policies to kick out people who have served generously with many hundreds of hours of dedicated service because they think doing so might make the site possibly (not necessarily truly!) a bit more welcoming for people who aren't even active contributors.  Trying to encourage downvotes, especially without comment, would go directly against that direction and goal.

Comment: *"the community doesn't even think it's worth working with the person to welcome them in with corrections to minor shortcomings"* That is pretty much what it means. If we think the post can be improved then we edit and/or comment. If we think the post is not useful then we downvote and move on. Next time please post something more useful.

Comment: *At its core, anonymous downvotes without explanation say "You have failed to meet our community standards in some way, but we won't tell you how, or give you any clear indication of how you can improve to do better next time."*  Well, no.  They don't exist for the poster.  They *never have*.  They're not supposed to.  The system needs to be a better job of explaining that.

Comment: "Not everyone knows, especially not new users." Then the solution is that we need to better communicate the purpose of downvotes to them, not to discourage content curation.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery: Declaring downvotes have a certain purpose does not make them (only) have that person in practice. Downvotes mean what people use them for + what people interpret them to mean.

Answer (score -15):

I think the problem is kind of imbalanced.

"This answer is useful" => how to answer that? Yes, for me it is useful, so there is at least one person for which the answer is useful, so I can upvote and know that this is a right action.

"This answer is not useful" => ok, for me it isn't. Should I downvote all answers which are (currently) not useful for me? How can I tell, that this answer won't be usefult for anyone else? There might be some hints, but from statement logic's points of view, I can't tell whether "this is not useful" from my subjective point of view.

Similar for question's tooltip of upvote/downvote. "Research effort" looks completely different for beginners and domain experts. Where's the limit?

It is easy to tell "I like that question/answer" or "This question/answer helped me" and it is still easy to say "for me, I see no worth in that question/answer".

But it is hard to tell "there will be nobody who gets any help from this question/answer". This includes the question, whether I have enough competence to detect whether a question/answer is meaningful or not. That's not always the case. But if you, in general, support downvotes, anyone who is disappointed from some posting could harm someone, who has spent time and maybe has given an answer that is useful for many others. Sounds discouraging to me.

Why should I discourage anyone on asking questions? Why should I discourage anyone on answering, even it it's only opinion-based?

I like the gamification aspects, mentioned earlier here, that you could get reward from downvoting, once a question is closed (I would split a total reward to all the downvoters, but that's a detail). However, there are still possibilities to exploit this.

Comment: _"Why should I discourage anyone on asking questions? Why should I discourage anyone on answering, even it it's only opinion-based?"_. Because adding noise to the repository makes it less valuable for all the future visitors that come for existing answers. It's about benefiting the larger group of users: future visitors.

Comment: @yivi: is that opinion or fact? I've already gotten valuable information from negative voted answers and I've already successfully answered negatively voted questions. And now, I dont even know whether my posting here was downvoted because someone doesnt like these two aspects in my answer, or the general idea, that there is some imabalance in "is useful for me" (upvote) vs. "is in general a bad answer" (downvote). If I would downvote all Q/A which are currently not useful for me, I would have to downvote 99% of all the questions, some of them I would have to upvote in a few years again...

Answer (score -15):

I checked the huge number of existing answers and was surprised that nobody already spoke my point of view.

I'm wondering if this question is not totally missing the point. Downvoting is a kind of hammer and the question is asking how to make it a bigger hammer. But the actual problem to solve is curation of the site content, specifically getting rid of bad questions and bad answers. Should that problem be solved using a bigger hammer or a screwdriver?

First I'm quite sure **the answer isn't the same for questions and for answers.**

Downvoting is a very efficient mechanism to clear bad answers. Also because of the gamification system most contributors whose answers are downvoted will delete them quickly when it's happening. And I would plead this is indeed what we want and that it makes the site content better. The only drawback on the downvote on questions is for opinion based questions, but these are not welcome on Stack Overflow anyway. It could lead yet lead to troubles on other Stack Exchange sites.

On the other hand downvoting on questions is at least partially conflicting with the closing mechanism. For someone who has both rights, it is not obvious why a question should be downvoted rather than closed. OK, you could say that downvoting is about question visibility and closing about genuinely bad questions that we don't want altogether for some reason. But hey! What does that mean. Obscure subjects are already hidden because fewer people are voting for them. Henceforth, is it about questions we don't want to be answered on popular subjects? How arrogant! In the end I'm still scratching my head as what downvotes on questions are actually meaning in the current system. Also in many cases I feel like a bad question should really be neither downvoted nor closed, but **deleted** at least until its content is improved.

I'm quite sure I'm not alone and that the first thing that would help downvoting on questions would be to clarify its meaning. I could be quite radical here:

OK, there is my actual proposal:

- **make 10 downvotes (or another figure) means the question is deleted**.
- **Users aren't losing reputation points when downvoting questions: make it clear the system is different for downvoting questions and answers** This would help because if you believe question does not belong to Stack Overflow and should be deleted you can express yourself, the current method is mostly aesthetic (hiding downvoted questions). This would help reduce the amount of garbage in the queues that need to be processed by reviewers: no more need to harass users with close vote level or moderators; the downvoted questions could directly be removed from queues. We could also remove the close option except for duplicates. Enough users think it's a bad question should lead to deletion without other control gate needed. Basically, if it works well, the only remaining reason for "closing" should be dealing with genuinely good questions already answered as duplicates (thus "close" could be replaced by "mark as duplicate"). This would also solve a fundamental issue related to "close". Curators are actually taking the high hand on people willing to answer blocking any possible answer. Making the question less visible, and eventually removed, would remove the need for that.
- **for downvote of answers change nothing. It's working** (or maybe also give the reputation points back to the downvoter if the answer is deleted)

Comment: It already works like this. We already have delete votes. We can delete really bad questions and answers. We close questions that should not be answered. Downvotes are not a replacement for either of these things.

Comment: @Dharman: So it is even less clear what downvotes are for. Could your share your lights on this ? The main problem with downvotes is that their purpose is totally obscure for questions. Is it about genuinely bad questions that should not be asked ? If so why keep them *at all* and use another system to remove them while adding to the burden of already overburdened curators of the site. If this is not about questions we do not want, what are downvotes about ? The only non overlapping part I can see between closing and downvoting for question are duplicates.

Comment: It has already been explained extensively here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: And also here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251735/is-it-appropriate-to-downvote-a-question-without-closevoting-it/251743#251743

Comment: @Dharman: Actually your links don't provide any insight of why any questions should be donwvoted but neither closed nor even deleted. If close is a bigger hammer than downvote but basically the same, and delete an even bigger hammer still for the same purpose, let the full job up to deletion be done by the smaller hammer.

Comment: The question can be deleted only by using down votes, close votes, delete votes, or combination of all of them. They are all different tools. If the links I provided do not explain it to you what is the difference I can't explain any more clearer than that.

Comment: That is not true https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions actual deletion of questions needs manual moderator action or votes from users with close/delete privileges. Merely downvoting questions won't lead to question deletion without harassing some high-rep user or moderator. That's the whole point of my proposal. You want more downvote, make them actually count for site curation. In their current state close votes are merely decorative (and the rep is indeed a non issue for questions).

Comment: Yes, they do. Plenty of questions get deleted by the system just because they have a negative score. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba As I said in the question, downvotes are our most precious tool. They have so many uses. If you can't vote to close or delete then a downvote might delete the question, but even if it doesn't it still serves the point of rating the content.

Comment: Help center not up to date ?

Comment: Help center is not 100% up to date, but this information is actually there.

Comment: The link you provided is still telling something completely different. It's not at all about removing Questions because they have many downvotes. There are many criteria and the only way downvote seems to be taken into account "is question has a negative score". It is clearer here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that This is totally different from "deletion because question got many downvotes".

Answer (score -15):

[EDIT: Updated in the comments]

<Sorry if this has already been said, but> Since the downvote harms both me (-1 reputation penalty) and my target (some other reputation penalty), I would much rather comment the persons answer and explain that he did something wrong (and WHAT exactly). Moreover, you say downvotes shouldn't always be clarified - I strongly disagree with that. There's no point in knowing you asked or answered a question wrong if you don't know what would be the right way to do this. Comments are the constructive way to criticise someone, while downvotes - the destructive. I would have used them more often if they didn't have any penalties except marking the post as less deserving attention, but currently it's a PUNISHMENT, and I don't consider that an appropriate reaction to things

Comment: Try for a few month to leave a comment for each vote you cast, then count afterwards how often your resulting experience was positive and how often it was negative. My motivation to leave comments faded after being called words for the tens time and having to deal with the fallout on my own answers (revenge downvotes, commenting with swear words on my answers). In the same timeframe almost no question have been improved after my comments.

Comment: It looks like you haven't read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436). Anything proposing such a requirement needs to withstand scrutiny against the arguments in the link. This one does not.

Comment: At this point, with 60+ answers, this one repeats something already mentioned (and debunked) multiple times.  It'd benefit everybody if you could go over some of those existing answers to see how people feel about this stance.

Comment: I'd like to mention how my post in just an hour gathered 7 downvotes. With my 70 reputation total, this really discourages me to try answering at all. This question was recoomended to me (for some reason) by stackoverflow itself, and I went through as many answers, as I could afford (around 5, they were very long) and didn't find any saying the same, so I thought that I'd post my opinion in case it helps anyone. In case it didn't, however, I apologized in advance, but I'm still being punished instead of informed. As for the specific comments: ...

Comment: ... 1) I don't have much experience on stackoverflow, but in general politely explaining the problems while still answering the question, if possible, has always worked for me. 2) I don't propose any requirements, only suggest that constructive critics would seem more efficient in most conditions. In general, I don't get why in this case my answer gets downvoted, even despite three clarifying comments. I don't see anything being wrong, other than people disaggreeing with my opinion (which is normal, but doesn't seem like a reason to decrease my reputation). ...

Comment: ... I, however, will not remove my question to avoid downvotes and huge (at my scale) reputation harm, since somewhere here it was asked not to do so. If anyone believes it should be deleted anyway, please inform me in the comments.

Comment: Updates should go in the answer itself, not in the comments. Comments aren't intended to be permanent.

Comment: "This answer is not useful" is the text on the downvote tooltip. How, if there are 60+ answers, can you assume your answer is going to be useful and not deserve to be rated as not useful if you only read 5 answers? It's not punishment, it's telling future readers that hey, on these 60+ answers, this one isn't worth reading, so you can focus on the ones that are.

Comment: Votes on meta are used more relaxed than on the main site. Also note, that voting on meta doesn't influence your reputation.

Answer (score -16):

Change the downvote down arrow *to* something else, like “Does not answer question” or “not relevant” or “not useful/helpful”. I would be more willing to click that than a downvote button.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how that text can fit there. There is already a pop-up (used to be a tool-tip) that has a similar text.

Comment: We can put the arrows on their side. Left - the post is not useful. Right - the post was useful.

Comment: @Dharman I suppose, but up/down is intuitive. Left/right is not.

Comment: That's some of what Close voting offers. We don't need to duplicate.

Comment: This idea sounds a bit similar to the naming effect that Brian mentions in this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398585/1536976). Maybe the label "downvote" makes is more personal than another label would do. Maybe renaming it would already improve the "downvote rate"? Although I'm not sure about that.

Comment: The tooltip on the downvote arrow reads: *"Downvote this answer if you find it unclear or **not useful**."*

Comment: "Does not answer question" is a reason to flag an answer or ask that the author remove it.

Comment: @ein The close reason you are referring to is reserved for answers that **do not attempt** to answer the question (e.g. a comment asking for clarification, a follow-up question, etc.). If a proposed answer attempts to answer the question, but gets it wrong, you are asked to *vote* on it.

Answer (score -16):

**Many new users get very offended by a single downvote on their question, yet they have completely no objection for the upvotes. Why is that?**

It's in the "101 human's behaviour" class. A positive comment reinforces your behaviour, while constructive, negative feedback points you to a more effective way of thinking. Have you created any thread here in meta asking why you are so, damn good in something as a company? Probably no. Because most of the feedback will be "you are doing it great. Keep going". A downvote, following by a comment with explanation is the only way that you properly, educate users.

**Why I don't downvote**

*If I don't have time to leave a proper feedback, I don't downvote*

Most of the times, I feel sorry about the user. The impact it has is enormous and more than what you think. I advised a lot of friends and colleagues to ask questions here. Those who were hammered by downvotes just stopped asking. Some of them even asked me to post the question. They had absolutely no idea what they did wrong.

*Even if I have time to leave I feedback, I still prefer to not downvote*

What if I explain to the user what they did wrong and they improve the quality of the question? What if someone else does it and I leave a downvote that won't be valid a couple of hours later? What if my downvote is part of a great edited question? I don't always have the time to come back and check the questions I downvote and see how they changed. Why should I punish a user permanently if I can just leave a comment explaining what they can do to improve it? Or just flag the question if it is off topic?

**What we can change to make downvote acceptable?**

1. Make it mandatory to leave a comment. Yes. Don't let users cast downvotes without leaving a proper explanation. Downvotes without content are just opinions. We need constructive feedback.
2. Increase the reputation you lose when you cast downvote to -2 or -3. But, if the user edits the question and the votes turns to positive OR if a moderator closes the question, refund the reputation and give +1 as bonus to the users who casted a downvote.
3. Create a new page as a short tutorial, with examples of bad questions and questions that will probably get negative votes. If a user keeps getting downvotes, then forward this tutorial page to his email. Why? Because most of the times, you feel that is a lost hope by just casting a downvote. No-one will become better. The OP will not improved and you just did it for nothing. If I know that my downvote will be a reason to educate a user, then I will happily do it.

Comment: "*A downvote, following by a comment with explanation is the only way that you properly, educate users.*" also, often enough - retribution.

Comment: "*What if I explain to the user what she did wrong and she improves the quality of the question? What if someone else does it and I leave a downvote that won't be valid a couple of hours later? What if my downvote is part of a great edited question?*" I suggest using the follow feature. I use it *extensively* and almost always follow a post after downvoting it. Rather seldom a post I've followed gets updated. Rarer still, that edit addresses an issue. So, *maybe* your downvote mars an excellent post in the future but chances are low from my experience.

Comment: "*Downvotes without content are just opinions*" That is what downvotes are. They are opinions. If you don't like the post then you should be free to express your opinion.

Comment: While I like your explanation at the start I need to point out that your suggestions are the opposite of what the question asked. We do not want to have less downvotes or make it more difficult for people to cast downvotes. We need more opinions. If you like the questions and you want OP to improve it then talk to them in the comment section and explain what they can do to improve it, or edit the post yourself.

Comment: You can cast downvotes regardless of whether the post is of good quality or not. Sometimes I leave a comment and the downvote but once the post is improved I only remove the comment and not the downvote. I still don't like the post, but I did help OP to improve it so that the next one they post will be better received by everyone else.

Comment: @Dharman If self-moderating is based entirely on opinions, then we are doomed to have a reputation hunting game. Users vote strategically and not based on the actual question. Imagine that you add a comment that a few users don't like. Then they downvote every single question and answer you have posted. They are free to do it. It is their opinion. But is it right? We should never judge something with plain opinions. We need arguments.

Comment: Re *"Make it mandatory to leave a comment"*: The canonical is *[Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)* (cross-site)

Comment: From my experience, leaving a down-vote with a comment rarely gets a question updated. Maybe 1 out of 20 questions are improved after that. Most of the time op never responds at all. So because of the 5% chance that something will improve, we should stop marking bad questions? Is that really fair given that most people visit SO coming from a search engine and want to see good questions with good answers and not terrible question without answers?

Comment: @BDL By your logic, none of this is worthwhile and we should just give up. 90% of visitors come by once or twice and never again, 90% of questions are garbage, 90% of answers are garbage. Nobody agrees on what's right, nobody agrees on what's best, and the one certainty is that if SE is still around in ten years, people will STILL be arguing over the right way to handle downvoting and there STILL won't be a solution. Because there isn't one. There can't be one. It's impossible to achieve.

Comment: This is pretty much the reason I downvote rarely as well. I much prefer to vote to close which is an explicit form of feedback, and I do usually leave comments in that case.  I will however downvote answers which I feel are factually incorrect or perhaps definitely bad advice.

Comment: @Dharman, the Code of Conduct says nothing about expressing subjective opinions. The Code of Conduct clearly states among community's four expectactions: "_Be clear and constructive when giving feedback, and be open when receiving it._"

Comment: *"Those who were hammered by downvotes..."* . Surely you could have seen why and helped them understand. Individual posts rarely get a lot of downvotes unless they are unintelligible, could very easily be answered in a web search or are way outside the scope outlined in the help center. People who help here a lot also have a right to expect a reasonable level of quality. It's not all about those asking

Answer (score -17):

> What can we do to encourage downvoting?

**What makes you think we need to?**

[image]

**Meanwhile, in another part of the galaxy...**
[image]

**Fact:**  SO 'grazers' (those who look for answers to their questions, but don't bother/care to take the time for up/down-voting), will always greatly outnumber the 'regulars' (those who actively work to curate what they consider quality content).
And I suspect the ratio of 'missing' up-votes to visible down-votes is significant, even with a conservative estimate.  So, who's version of quality content do you want - the grazers or the regulars?  Ideally, both.  Consequently, a balance must be enforced.  And I think that's what SO is efforting when they increase the proverbial cost for down-votes.

Comment: If your question was viewed +1k times, and none of those views upvoted it, I would point out that votes strongly correlate with views, and if I was looking for answers to the same question I would upvote it. If anything, that kind of reflects on the quality of the question rather than the viewers.

Comment: "I would point out that votes strongly correlate with views..." According to what metric?  I don't think they necessarily do.  And that's why SO skews the cost of up-votes vs. down-votes and rewards posts with high views, regardless.

Comment: rewards with... a badge? i mean, they reward a lot of weird things with badges.

Comment: @Braiam: I . . . can't imagine how the question quality could be much better. Unless you mean it should have been self-answered, which seems a rather high standard.

Comment: @JonEricson I think the point that Braiam's making is that high views, low votes probably indicates a search target trap: people are seeing the post in Google, clicking through, and not finding what they're looking for. (Those who have time and inclination might edit or leave a downvote.) The answer also has not been voted on much at all compared to its view count. So while the page might not be _bad_, it may not be "good" (for some definition) either. And we can't simply equate page views with value -- there might even be _negative_ value in some cases. (cont'd)

Comment: Cf. [How to save the world... one question title at a time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201940)

Comment: @jscs: How do you square that with the 7 upvotes the _answer_ got?

Comment: @JonEricson the same way I explain the score on the question. The answer might be useful, the question not so much.

Comment: @Braiam: Surely the answer _exists_ because of the question? (But we've been through this before. Questions seem to be assumed worthless until they have some mystical quality I can never detect.)

Comment: @JonEricson I mean, the OP hasn't been very forthcomming with us. The -1 vs 1k views is actually +2/-3 vs 1k view. The question got -3 votes immediately after being asked, and got two votes since then (it was in the close queue too). There are comments that put into question the knowledge of what the asker is doing (the title as jscs doesn't help). Also, the answer is a "you are doing it wrong" kind of answer, which also got most of its votes after being asked.

Comment: I just don't see how this answers the question. You're pointing out that one question got one downvote, and using that as evidence that there doesn't need to be any encouragement of downvoting? A sample size of 1 is not a compelling argument. There are plenty of *extremely* low-quality posts that don't get downvoted. That's what we need to fix.

Comment: @JonEricson If you see the answer timeline, 4 of the 7 came on the same day it was posted, which means they are unlikely to be from inbound searchers. And the next upvote was nearly two years later. So my reading is that those 1000 viewers arrived and were unimpressed. Again, I'm not saying that there's anything _wrong_ with the Q or A here; I'm only disputing the idea that 1000 views _equates to_ goodness.

Comment: @CodyGray - I have other examples. One trend I've noticed is that the more advanced-topic questions appear get higher votes. Even if I spent more time on a 'beginner' question, it still seems to suffer at the hands of voters vs viewers.  
Regardless, I imagine that SE has metrics for days. We can all speculate about who views/votes, and when and why. I'm simply suggesting that SO/SE has analyzed the data and determined that down-votes need to cost more, to provide a balanced community. Clearly, I have an unpopular perspective.But I've been around here long enough to have anticipated that. ;-)

Comment: @jscs - IMO, the link you provided is supporting my question title. I work extensively with 'black box' software platforms, which means I Google A LOT. I appreciate it when people use exact/specific syntax, makes my searches more efficient and productive.

Comment: It's certainly not _misleading_, @Tracy, I agree, and naming the API right up front is good. But it's not particularly descriptive, either. I don't know the tech stack, but there's gotta be many ways in which `IEnumerable() .Select` could "not work"...and plenty of people with problems that fit that vague description. If the Google link said, for example "IEnumerable() .Select results do not match count", or "IEnumerable() .Select unexpectedly empty", or anything more specific, I think you'd have far gotten fewer views but a far higher percentage of _happy_ viewers.

Comment: *"I'm simply suggesting that SO/SE has analyzed the data and determined that down-votes need to cost more, to provide a balanced community."* While this sounds reasonable, even compelling, I can assure you that it is wrong. Jeff Atwood, the site's founder, created this policy before there was even any data to analyze, and it's been in place ever since. There was no data behind it whatsoever, and I haven't heard any indication that SE has analyzed the data from years' worth of usage in order to confirm the original supposition.

Comment: I do personally agree that beginner questions get a poorer reception here than they should. Downvotes on questions are free and don't cost anything, so this rationale can't be applied to explain this. Even if it could, that's not really a reason to discourage downvoting overall. We still need more downvoting on low-quality questions and answers. I regularly see spam and homework dumps (where there is no question in sight) get *upvoted*. There's just no excuse for that.

Comment: "I haven't heard any indication that SE has analyzed the data from years' worth of usage..."  That seems odd.  Why even go through the trouble of collecting/sharing it then?

Comment: "We still need more downvoting on low-quality questions and answers."  I disagree, respectfully.  I far prefer other SE communities where there is very little downvoting.  Basically, the scoring gets 'shifted' to the right.  People who write poor quality/unclear/open-ended questions/answers don't get responses and/or upvotes.  Their lack of quality is still 'punished', but without discouraging them from participating altogether.  We are talking about an (ideally) hugely diverse community.  My definition of a good question/answer may not match yours.

Comment: So what if someone else thinks a 'homework question' is useful, and someone else wants to take the time to write a good response for it?  Good for them!  We are all allowed to have our own viewpoints.  Inevitably, SO often reflects a bias towards the more senior members on the site, and their demographic.  Just like you said: "I do personally agree that beginner questions get a poorer reception here than they should."  And why do you think that is?

Comment: Fatigue with all the other low-quality questions has made people quick to judge. More downvoting is the solution to that: it means fewer low-quality questions being put into the faces of active users. I have spoken with several users who are relatively new to this site, and they're constantly bombarded, on the front page, with blatantly off-topic questions. It's very frustrating and confusing for them. If these questions were downvoted, they wouldn't appear on the front page anymore. Shifting everything to the right by just giving more upvotes doesn't solve that problem. QC needs balance.

Answer (score -18):

IMO, voting up/down should be encouraged more than voting to close. A -200 question is not locked out and people who wish to engage with the question/user are not discouraged to do so.

A closed question eliminates the communities' ability to engage with and develop a new user.

Its a fairly standard joke that googling an issue you find 1 result which is a stack overflow question that was marked as a duplicate and linked to something that's 10 years old and does not answer the question.  Closing a question removes future people for developing the answer for odd things.

Comment: Closed questions can be edited and commented on. In the majority of cases, that's because they aren't answerable on Stack Overflow. The solution is to edit the question so it is acceptable. However, that is most likely a job for the question asker, as they usually have the most of the relevant information. For example, if they ask for debugging help but haven't supplied enough information to find the problem, then nobody can definitively answer the question at all.

Comment: Voting to close is for questions which should be closed, up/down-voting is for questions which should exist on the site. These are essentially orthogonal.

Comment: What do you mean by *"people who wish to engage can"*? E.g., engage in what way? Can you elaborate (preferably by [editing your answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/398672/edit))?

Comment: The jokers could have asked a new question *explaining* why the duplicate and the answer don't work in their context. They didn't, instead they went to reddit to post a meme. Fine. Our content curation system works.

Answer (score -19):

To me, downvoting seems brutal and is hard to take as constructive. Rather than downvote, couldn't we have more prominent tags to raise issues with the post - that would overall diminish its score?

Duplicate, unclear, polemic, subjective, [RTFM](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/RTFM#Phrase), language/style, wrong, dangerous side effects, misses edge cases, etc. Those are attributes that would properly convey that they are not directed at the poster, but at the post itself.

I would find it useful to tag posts this way, while I find it hard to downvote any, but the most obviously spiteful questions or answers. Noobs *will* ask stupid or ill-worded questions, and answers *will* be wrong or overly simplistic. Still, most of the time that deserves an explanation. You don't want to just "slap away" a curious 12-year-old, and have a potential [Linus Torvalds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds) switch his interest in programming to something else!

Comment: "You don't want to just "slap away" a curious 12-year-old" - unfortunately, curious 12-year-olds aren't actually allowed to use Stack Exchange, as per the site's T&Cs. You have to be 13 or over (16 or over if you're in the EU), due to data protection issues.

Comment: That is quite an emotional weight you're giving to the act of downvoting. A downvote isn't a slap. Regarding the proposed feature, similar ones have been proposed before: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328037 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357702 to enumerate a few. They don't encourage voting, only makes it harder. The reasons for downvoting suggested here are easily contestable too.

Comment: I'm sorry, but in what universe is "RTFM" is going to be less personal than a "-1"?

Comment: Downvotes are not meant to punish users. They don't necessarily mean that there is a problem with the post. Downvotes are our way of showing which content we think is going to be useful for other readers and which is not. We rate content, not users.

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from posting an explanation in the comments. Downvotes are not a replacement for it. We ask that you use your power of votes to tell us which content you think helps and which is less helpful. If you have a way to improve the less helpful posts then add a comment.

Comment: Comments are often seen as more hostile feature than downvoting. People tend to post rude remarks in comments e.g. RTFM. That does not help OP ask better questions or post better answers in the future. We have close reasons to say that a post is unclear or a duplicate. If it's a duplicate you do not need to downvote, sometimes you might even want to upvote. If there are problems with the wording then edit the post. Everything has its purpose.

Answer (score -20):

I think the downvote algorithm gets something right.

There is evidence that people gain pleasure in creating pain in others. I'm not talking about abnormal people; it's apparent that normal people feel this pleasure too.

https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/their-pain-our-gain/ uses the word, [schadenfreude](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schadenfreude#Noun), which from my limited German, means "the joy you feel causing someone else pain".

So, if Stack Overflow is to be a place where positive feelings succeed, downvoting should have a negative consequence; however, I don't think that downvoting a question is the same as downvoting a reply.

It gets really complicated quickly.

- Downvoting questions can create an elitist culture, where only the "best" questions are accepted (let's not focus on what best means at the moment)
- Downvoting answers can create a negative feedback, where those who assist are pushed into not assisting unless the answer meets some imaginary bar of "good enough"

As the two categories are different, I'd recommend differences in the downvoting cost.

- A question that is downvoted should incur a cost, but not a great cost, because the asker may be naive, learning their way through a new technology.  For this, I agree with the current costs, -2 points to the downvoted is acceptable, as is -2 to the downvoter.
- An answer that is downvoted typically bears one of a few hall marks.  It is wrong, it is a generalization of what is typically right, or it is correct, but a person is attempting to gain position for future upvotes.

For an answer that is downvoted, I would adjust the scales, such that downvoting a blatantly wrong answer doesn't hurt too much, but downvoting impacts the voter more than the person being downvoted (to avoid the gaming of people attempting to gain position).

In my mind, a downvote of an answer costing more points to the downvoter than the answerer is an acceptable solution, as it penalizes the gaming of multiple answer-ers attempting to gain.  I'm not sure what the cutoff should be, but maybe -6 to -2 might be ok.  In any case, we seem to have most of the initial downvotes come from other people answering the questions.

Comment: How would that help to bring in more downvotes? Penalizing voters does not encourage more downvoting, it does the opposite.

Comment: "Schadenfreude" = the joy you feel watching someone else feeling pain. No need to be the cause for it

Comment: "*In any case, we seem to have most of the initial downvotes come from other people answering the questions.*" [citation needed] Also...so what? Presumably if somebody tries to answer a question, they'll have some expertise in the subject. So, chances are that answerers would be able to spot other bad answers. Sure, some may downvote for "personal gain", others might do it to signal that an answer has problems. Which is what downvoting should be about.

Comment: The word *[schadenfreude](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schadenfreude#Noun)* (not capitalised in the loan word version) has made it into English: *"1. Malicious enjoyment derived from observing someone else's misfortune."*

Answer (score -21):

Looking at my own voting, I'm at 1000 vs. 100, which I consider a nice rate.

To me, the problem isn't with the downvoting itself, though with the implications for the OP.
Adding a downvote just feels rude. You have the power to say: This is bad! Without having to explain why you consider this being bad.

I often add a comment or verify if there is already a comment, though, that's more work than upvoting where the message is often implied.

This leaves me casting close votes instead of downvoting.

A second thing preventing me to do the actual downvotes, on questions and answers, are the previous downvotes. There's a difference between telling (especially new users) this isn't helpful and telling them there effort isn't appreciated. This looking from the perspective that it actually can get fixed. Knowing I won't be coming back to check on those improvements and undo that downvote if done.

So, to encourage someone like to add downvotes:

- Give reputation if downvotes are considered valid

  - After a post reaches a threshold, like 5 or 10, give the original down voters a confirmation
  - If the post gets updated, inform the downvoters. Possibly reset the downvotes and consider the downvote a correct incentive to force an update. Possibly to be verified via the queues
  - The post gets deleted (which isn't possible at this point when someone answered on the bad question)
- Improve the way that downvotes (and upvotes) are presented

  - At the moment, the vote count is right there in your face. Having a better way to indicate the message, like -1 -> -5 becomes: Needs improvement; -11 -> ... This is considered unhelpful/unrelated. We might have to, instead of downvote, have to pick a reason. Though, if we have an easy to do so without too much overhead, I see some improvements.

Looking at some other answers, I saw suggestions like badges or removing the downvote penalty, however, for me, that wouldn't be helpful.

Comment: "*If the post gets updated, inform the downvoters. Possibly reset the downvotes*" do you know just how many posts that have very serious issues get updated with *at best* some spelling fixes or other corrections that are ultimately not related to the issue? Removing votes on update seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: @VLAZ I can agree with that, that's the hard balance. That's exactly why I prefer the close votes. It ends up in a queue, and can get reopened when correctly fixed. That same system for downvotes sounds to me like a good idea.

Comment: Are you fine with resetting upvotes too? I mean, the post changed, so whose to say the upvotes are still well deserved as well?

Comment: @StoryTeller: if the update ruins the answer, yes. As mentioned in the previous comment of mine, some queues can help with deciding if it needs to be reset or not

Comment: So, more workload for reviewers? More rubbish to wade through? When this idea comes from someone who has only done 162 reviews in all their time on SO, you get how it sounds, right?

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm just sharing some ideas that pop up in my mind, assuming they might trigger some improvement by someone else. Talking about my limited reviews, that's most likely a good indicator of a flaw in my proposal. (Maybe we need some improvements there as well?)

Answer (score -22):

> What can we do to encourage downvoting?

I don’t think questions should be voted on in general, but I wonder if removing user attributions while the question is still in an infancy stage?

> Many new users get very offended by a single downvote on their question, yet they have completely no objection for the upvotes. Why is that?

To me, this reason is because it’s difficult to make permanent objects of type shame.

> Why so many users demand that the downvotes be accompanied by an explanatory comment yet nobody demands an explanation for the upvotes?

Because sometimes people downvote when another answer is better than theirs.

> Do people really value the fake Internet points so much or is it about acceptance by strangers?

One way or the other *every person has a threshold for passiveness.*

> Why is their perception of our voting systems so skewed?

I suspect and maybe myself have been guilty of misunderstanding the voting system. Part of the reason for this is simply its similarity to emotion-conveying toggles on social media sites. People are emotional by nature and it’s natural for us perceive something and construct an emotion about it.

> It's true that the ratio of upvotes to downvotes is often driven by the tag, but I am pretty sure that we all encounter bad questions and answers in every tag.

Agreed.

> There's always something to upvote as well as downvote. If we see a badly asked question, then we should downvote.

1. Yes. 2. No, edit or flag or mark as duplicate!

> If we see a wrong or outdated answer then we should downvote.

Will do!

> Do we have any ideas about what we could do or change to encourage people to spend a little bit more of their votes on downvoting posts?

I don’t think questions should be voted on in general. Maybe just edit or flag or mark as duplicate questions. For voting on answers I think the current system is quite nice. If I have any reasonable idea to contribute (which might exist already) to this question beyond my personal thoughts it would be removing user attribution on a question or answer. Why do questions and answers even need user attribution?

I’m just going make a general edit section below to post related points:

This question is similar to the following- “How do I verbalize to someone not wearing a mask that they are participating in public society in a suboptimal way?”

Comment: Editing and marking as a duplicate are orthogonal actions. They can and should take place alongside potential downvoting based on the overall quality and usefulness of the question. Editing may not be enough. Better watch out for the scarecrow arguments in the answer, by the way. There are much better arguments for why we don't demand explanations to upvotes than that.

Comment: Re *"Why do questions and answers even need user attribution"*: They don't, but it is part of the ego-centric design of Stack Overflow (not of the designers, but the system).

Answer (score -22):

> What can we do to encourage downvoting?

Hmm...

> *At the same time, I've been fielding complaints from folks regarding downvoted posts for many, many years now. Authors, readers, even voters have claimed that our scoring system is fundamentally broken because of its transparency - that by making the score immediately apparent, it invariably influences how people vote, how they edit, how or whether they answer... In ways that are susceptible to unconstrained feedback loops or even outright manipulation.*
>
> *Our response to those complaints has generally been some variation on, "nuh-uh!" And I'm concerned this has started to wear a bit thin. It's time we listened and, with as little disruption as possible, tried to collect some actual data on all of this.*
>
> [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390343/ethical-considerations-of-the-ongoing-experiment-re-not-displaying-negative-scor/390414#390414)

...another approach would be just to rely on (up)votes, with the system then targeting answers with the least votes for potential deletion.

One simple way to do this would be to assign a [half-life](https://www.remm.nlm.gov/halflife.htm) to votes, similar to those for radioisotopes:

- Very popular answers would experience the most vote-decay, which shouldn't be a problem if they remain popular and continue to attract new votes;
- Because they would have so few votes left, the vote-decay on less-popular answers would be slow, giving their authors more than enough time to improve their content;
- Assuming its vote-count have reached some defined threshold, an unpopular or abandoned answer can be expunged from SO immediately, with the option of being mailed back to its author (depending on SO account preferences e.g. a suitable email address).

Some points of interest:

- The vote-count for each answer would remain visible at all times, which allays the concerns raised about them being potentially misrepresented e.g. in [What were the results of the A/B experiment where negative question scores were clamped to 0?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393907/what-were-the-results-of-the-a-b-experiment-where-negative-question-scores-were)
- More than ever, authors must keep their questions and answers relevant to maintain their popularity - will most authors be happy to make the extra effort?
- Just as importantly, will most SO users accept their votes no longer being permanent, and the ongoing need to cast new votes on existing answers to maintain their popularity? Rewards for voting (e.g. increased reputation) may need to be restructured as well.
- The deletion of a question or answer cannot (so easily!) be attributed to the actions of a particular user. The *gaming* (as opposed to *gamification*) of the system is made more cumbersome by the absence of rapid gratification - if there is no moderator intervention, then the algorithm (this or another) decides what to expunge and when. Of course, unhappy SO users can always put forward their own algorithm...

Will this solve all the woes of downvoting? Based on my experience: no - it's more likely to be just another small step along the way...

For those who are interested, an investigation of various decay models used in storage management research can be found in [On Models for Object Lifetime Distributions](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.30.402&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Darko Stefanovic, Kathryn S. McKinley and J. Elliot B. Moss.

Answer (score -24):

**Make the amount of upvotes/downvotes separate and *compute* it based on previous votes and other things**

Let’s say it starts with *20 upvotes / 20 downvotes*.

When you spend more upvotes than downvotes, next time you'd get fewer upvotes to use and more downvotes instead. The same works vice-versa.

Let's call it the ying-yang correction.

Given how [*useful* features Stack Overflow added lately](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction), this might also give some impact!

Comment: That would reduce the number of downvotes even more. Consider users like me who mostly downvote. When I find a useful post I will upvote, but that is much rarer than stuff that needs my downvotes.

Comment: But this means that if only bad post come in then after a while, we'd have to decide which bad posts to start upvoting.. unless we just go off and upvote random stuff to get our downvotes back.

Comment: Sorry would like to upvote, but had only downvotes left. :)

Comment: See [Should we have a policy about “too much downvoting”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42601/289905).

Answer (score -25):

*What can we do to encourage downvoting?*

**Nothing**. Downvoting shouldn't be encouraged. It should be used as a last resort, when the Q&A author doesn't answer on a comment. I actually believe it would be wise to remove downvoting completely.

**People will *not* learn to write better questions / answers through anonymous downvotes. They learn this by *reading* on Stack Overflow. They learn this through experience.**

So, if your intent is to increase quality, **write a cheat sheet**. Give examples of good questions/answers. Explain which things should be avoided and why. Make it easy to find. This will speed up the learning.

Comment: "*Give examples of good questions/answers.*" we do - it's called the scoring system. How do you make it clear what's good, without also outlining what's bad? Also, you seem to overestimate how much a poster is willing to read before writing something. From my experience, the average is *very little*. Often it's even "none". You might not be aware of exactly how many posts suffer severe quality issues. If you look through the review queues or monitor the most recent posted questions, it becomes a painful daily reality.

Comment: That means you would also want to get rid of upvoting. How would we then decide which posts are good or bad? Your whole reasoning is very flawed. I hope that after some time you will see that we need a voting system to separate good from the bad.

Comment: Re *"it would be wise to remove downvoting completely"*: That will probably happen eventually, unless Stack Overflow starts to be innovative. It has been nearly 12 years with the tired old Q&A model without much innovation. It must be possible to solve the tension with beginners on Stack Overflow by augmenting and/or radically change *part* of the software (small tweaks here and there will not cut it).

Comment: [Example from today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62615668/how-to-generate-an-ai-dataset-with-spacy). That is 3 unnecessary downvotes. It should never have been exposed to voting, but simply not accepted until in an answerable state. For example, why can't there be a private draft phase where questions can be worked on without the fear of downvotes? Perhaps even collaborative work on questions. If micro work can work for answers and moderation tasks, why not for this?

Comment: @PeterMortensen The question asker should get the question into the proper state before posting on Stack Overflow. Once they post on Stack Overflow we can give them further feedback, but the majority of responsibility is on them. They need to do research, spell check, create MCVE and so on. We can't do this for them. If they don't do this then we must close the question. Once they improve it, we can reopen it. The problem is that many people do not improve at all. If they don't improve the question without and with our feedback then what else can we do?

Comment: You are right but even in this thread you can see the blaming down votes against those who think down votes without explanation are bad.

Answer (score -26):

**Constructive Update**

While commenting other posts I have realized that community may achieve both securing ourselves from increasing of hating behavior and transforming downvotes into a constructive mechanism.

Only by achieving both these points can we encourage to downvote a lot of community members.

> The key is to make downvoting having no publicity visible attributes.

The reasons and how it could work.

I noticed from comments that downvoting supporters aim:

1. to improve content quality
2. to prevent other users from lower-quality content
3. ones want to focus efforts in their tag feed on a high quality question

Also it seems, among supporters there is an old consensus that downvotes are not aimed at helping authors to improve content.

Also I noticed that downvoting unsupporters aim:

1. to keep the balance of community activities on a creative side, to avoid the increasing of expressing hide hate behavior via easy downvotes
2. to keep new users welcoming and mitigate the risk of unclear criticism of their mistakes
3. to do not destroy implicit searching effects, when fewer quality answers attract search traffic by the same kind fewer quality queries

Comparing these it is interesting that

1. Unsupporters prefer to not affect authors by downvoting and supporters realise that authors are not the primary target for downvotes
2. Supporters clearly eager to make their best for the community, but feel narrowed in their efforts because of the strict Code of Conduct and anti-hatering consensus.
3. Supporters treat quality as a factor of usefulness, unsupporters point the quality is not only one such factor

> If so, community could rethink and remodel the downvotes entity.

Currently *downvotes* are used as subordinate to entity *content usefulness* to measure it. In this aspect *downvotes* are totally duplicate the entity *upvotes*. It is mathematically clear that one such subordinate entity is enough to build the scale and measure *usefulness* , and construct above it any type of ranking mechanism.

On the other hand current discussion shows the second usage the entity *downvotes*, namely as subordinate to entity *content quality* to measure it.

This dual usage design leads all the problems.

Practically it can be solved via the following steps:

1. Create new action button on Q and A to mark exactly low quality. This should be the same manner aggregative tool as downvoting now. The votes should be aggregated totally separately from upvotes without any comparison in GUI. Moreover, probably, it should be visible only to moderators or users with some level of privileges.
2. There should be no such restrictions for low quality votes as for current downvotes.
3. The downvote arrow should be eliminated forever from the GUI. The ranking mechanism should be adopted to [0-infinity) log-scale or with regularly rescaling.

Having this we can dramatically encourage ourselves to label exactly the low quality content. These efforts then can be used build large-scale datasets to train artificial tools for different tasks starting from matching and linking duplicates, suggesting fixes, interactive guidelines while posting to authors, etc.
And in the same time, there will be no undesirable consequences in increasing hating, subjectiveness and unwelcoming.

---

**Initial thoughts**

The wording of the question is absolutely manipulative, since the question asserts without any evidence that downvoting is a useful and necessary tool for the community and improving the quality of content.

On the example of ordinary social networks, it is clearly visible that Facebook, which offers a negative rating for content, is much more polarized and subject to hate than, for example, Instagram. Not to mention Stack Overflow! Of course, this is a subjective user's observation, however, it would be very right if the author of the question were to give us the results of such an objective study of social networks and their content rating systems before making statements about the extreme usefulness of the downwashing tool.

In my opinion, it is quite the opposite. The downvote tool by its nature contradicts both the key principles and the goals of the community to create an open, friendly resource, especially for new members, rich in community content.

*Firstly*, it is unreasonable that "poor-quality" questions and answers are not useful. So I was repeatedly helped by the answers left to questions with a negative rating. Questions with a negative rating and high marks for answers are regularly met. Not the most popular answers are regularly found useful. The secret is simple - users, including me, formulate "low-quality" search queries that are relevant to "low-quality" questions! If I’m not mistaken, then the Stack Overflow blog even had a post about this effect.

*Further*. Downvoting is an anonymous tool, and for this reason it is especially attractive to haters. Especially, if he/she begins to be encouraged or restrictions would be lifted.

The number of people who want to remove restrictions and the tonality of answers to this question gives me the impression that supporters of lifting restrictions do not like Stack Overflow. They are *not* happy with the content, and it is *not* convenient for them to use Stack Overflow. We need to understand the reasons of such dissatisfaction.

Otherwise, they are ready, under the slogan of improvement, to begin to destroy the "bad" content in their opinion.

However, those who wish to downgrade are completely unacceptable to strive to decide for other members of the community that the content is of poor quality and that the content is not needed by others.

A reasonable question: Why does someone think that they have the right to deprive me of any content that could help me tomorrow? On what basis will anyone censor the content?

Maybe on the contrary, it is precisely the one who constantly experiences difficulties in finding content useful to himself/herself that needs help? In new tools for searching, filtering, matching, recommendations, etc.

*Further.* Downvoting sets up a critical attitude and distracts participants from other forms of improving content: writing new questions, answers, editing, and setting flags. Downvoting is worth nothing in comparison with that. Actually, it is a surrogate, an imaginary feeling of participation in a common cause.

Therefore, the presence of participants exclusively engaged in downvoting is a serious signal to analyze why people spend hours of their time to downvote many thousands of answers. In general, it looks like an attempt to sweep the beach. Perhaps the efforts and energy of these participants should be redirected to some new constructive forms of activity. At least in the form of manual labeling of data with special flags, for subsequent consideration by search algorithms and composing datasets.

Comment: Do you suggest we remove voting altogether? Downvoting does not mean deleting or hiding. It means ranking content. If you find something that helped you, you should upvote. If you find something that did not help you or even caused you more confusion then downvote. This way it will be easier for other users to find answers that are more useful than others. I don't understand why you think that downvoting is worse than not upvoting when it comes to ranking content.

Comment: It looks like you are a brand new user. Maybe you need some time to get to know how voting and content ranking works. Popular stuff rises up to be more visible. Less popular posts go down so that less people waste time reading them.

Comment: We do delete terribly bad content, however, but this is not done using downvotes nor upvotes. They are used purely to rate content. We delete posts using delete votes, but only the ones which are beyond hope. It actually makes finding things easier on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Dharman, I'm very old more than 7 years a passive user. Long time I did not answer and so have not enough reputation to make actions. And as a passive user who only search I can proof that downvoting never meant something and helped. Just because you either come to very high scored Q\A where upvoting plays or your happy to read any available ideas. If you state that downvoting improve ranking search result then it must be proof with research and numbers. More likely that it is a myth.

Comment: And I worth very much the stackoverflow's restrictions to act critically, because I was many years a tester and know how it is hard to switch youself from critics to creativity. The flag systems, delete voting and restrictions for general voting I fill as awesome approach. I would stay everything as is.

Comment: Seem to have a warped perspective that down-voting is only personal and is about hate. Hover over a downvote link and reasons are given in a tooltip for it's purpose and they are neither personal or attack related. The word *"hate"* appears numerous times in your answer

Comment: @charlietfl, сonduct a thought experiment: if you consider your advice necessary for me, a participant who has tried to reasonably express his concerns, is it worth it to assume that users who are prone to be haters will not read and follow the tooltip? For my part, I’ll suggest you join Stack Overflow in Russian in order to feel to what extent Stack Overflow can be distorted.

Comment: Well I have been around SO for many years and am not familiar at all with the hate concept you espouse. Perhaps it's cultural perspective differences but I see people helping people every day here and getting thanked for it

Comment: @charlietfl, exactly! SO is so unique with it's grown friendly and helping culture, that it will be very sad to step on the very well known rake as downvoting content.

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this answer that I don't know where to begin ...

Answer (score -28):

Downvotes are not *necessary* imho, if the content is "bad" or off-topic enough it will be flagged or closed pretty quickly. I have used the site long enough to know even the upvotes hardly matter, especially for difficult questions. Three upvotes to me indicate that at least three other people thought or understood the information to be useful. Whether is that truly the case? The next user has to judge for himself.

In summary: the votes don't make much of a difference to general user experience in the long term (except for some people who are more interested in the moderation process). It is similar to accessing information over the internet, it clearly works without a voting system.

Comment: *"It is similar to accessing information over the internet, it clearly works without a voting system."* - The sheer fact that Stack Overflow needed to be invented is evidence, that the internet (where *"Everyone's a publisher!"*) simply didn't work. The information is published, without even an attempt to rate it. In a time, where a *"left-pad"* package is among the most successful "libraries" developers use, we surely need a place where content is publicly rated. Unbiased. And downvoted with extreme prejudice, where necessary.

Comment: "*it clearly works without a voting system.*" this is wrong. There is no *explicit* voting but SEO serves as the same mechanism. The information you see has already been automatically moderated and presented to you in a particular order. On this site, *we* are doing the same job.

Comment: @vla I hope not. SEO rates based on popularity (among others). Stack Overflow rates based on quality (in theory anyway).

Comment: "*if the content is "bad" or off-topic enough it will be flagged or closed pretty quickly*" you cannot flag or close *answers*. They can be wrong for any amount of reasons and still be on-topic enough to not warrant flagging. So, your proposed solution doesn't help with those.

Comment: @IInspectable it's still a content rating system. So, "accessing over the internet" is not a process where everything is equal, as the answer here suggests.

Comment: @VLAZ it has nothing to do with SEO, but everything with having a brain and using it. Voting on SO is part of the moderation process, but ultimately it is not necessary for content access.

Comment: @prusswan it's necessary if you want to access *good* content. As already mentioned, that was a driving decision behind the conception of Stack Overflow. The success of the platform is an indication that it's the correct approach.

Comment: @VLAZ so what is "good" content now? +30 or +3 or 0 or -3? You see value in these numbers, but I don't, at least not enough for the determination of good content

Comment: *"You see value in these numbers, but I don't"* - Neither do I, as I explained elsewhere. The numbers are biased towards upvotes. Ideally, a good answer should have a positive score, a bad answer a negative score. That's not what we see, though. Downvoting doesn't happen nearly as often as it should, for many reasons. This Q&A attempts to eliminate one of those reasons.

Comment: @IInspectable they never will. This is just another useless attempt to moderate for the sake of moderation, by people who think voting is more important than content

Comment: Voting isn't part of moderation. Voting is part of curation. In my experience, the latter doesn't work reliably. I cannot remember a single day where I didn't come across a highly upvoted answer, that's (ever so subtly) wrong. So I leave comments, explaining what's wrong, and while the comments receive upvotes, the referenced answers simply will not attract the same number of downvotes. Even years later. You [can see this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1387064/1889329) yourself. This is a Q&A that was viewed 137k times.

Comment: @IInspectable, what are the search trafic sources to Stackoverflow? I only use Google search and rating of Q\A never was criteria for me to search and choose. I don't think that google search engine pay attention for votes. Otherwords downvoting does not help to search rigth content at all. But downvoting tends community to be subjective and express implicity hate behavior instead.

Comment: @IInspectable, where this understanding of _bad should have negative score_ come from? Could you prove it? To my mind it's obviuosly that reference point and coordinate system can be absolutely arbitrary chose from maths and any ranking mechanism. Attemps to affect ranking by subjective indirect action as downvoting will not have any positive effect. Because the direct actions to mark relevant content are: upvotes and redirects from search engine. But reference point has a huge matter from the human phycology aspect, the zero ground prevents of expressing hate and broad criticism.

Comment: @ego *"where this understanding of bad should have negative score come from?"* - Read the tooltips ("This answer is useful"/"This answer is not useful"). Do you now understand, why bad answers should have a negative score? Voting should not be subjective, either. But that's likely a much harder problem to solve, namely that practically *all* non-native developers lack a number of prerequisites, that generally (as I perceived it over the course of close to a decade) prevents them from making good (i.e. judicious) decisions.

Answer (score -30):

## Make downvotes less direct

Getting a -1 with no context feels personal. I want to know *why* someone thinks my question or answer is bad so that I can fix it- and then be rewarded for fixing it. The goal of downvotes is to filter out and fix bad questions and answers, so maybe more focus should be put on that instead of a number next to a post that gives a vague idea of quality/usefulness.

You used to be able to start comments with -1, but that was banned some time ago because it was mean or something. I contend that it was a *very* useful thing to be able to do and that the policy was a mistake without a proper replacement.

Instead of making downvotes taking effect immediately and rarely being converted to upvotes after an edit, I think it would be better to add a feedback field to downvotes and delay their effect on reputation for 7 days so that the poster has a reasonable grace period to fix problems. Instead of being a fully public comment (as with the -1 comments), these criticisms would be anonymous (except to moderators) and visible only to users who can edit the post. Moderators would have the power to singlehandedly mark criticisms as bad, removing their effect and penalizing the critic; high-rep users could do the same with 3 votes (similar to close votes). The poster would have the opportunity to edit posts and be given a small reward for addressing criticism, also reversing the effect on post rating unless critics explicitly indicate the post has not been fixed.

Rewards/punishments would be something like the following:

- +2 rep for giving feedback

  - The reward is turned into a -3 penalty for criticisms later flagged as bad
- +5 rep if the post is edited in the next 7 days

  - The user who edits the post receives +1 rep for each addressed criticism: the user who made the criticism is given 7 days to indicate whether or not it was fixed. If the critic does not respond in that time, no reward is given to the editor, but the criticism is still cleared.
- +3 rep if the post is deleted or closed in the next 7 days
- The downvote penalty kicks in if the post is not edited within 7 days

Comment: Starting comments with "-1" was banned because it is altogether *not useful*, and we are trying to actively *discourage* people from leaving comments to accompany their downvotes. There are almost no circumstances where it is beneficial to do so. Votes should always be anonymous, and never connected to specific users or comments. If you want to leave feedback in addition to your vote, you can do that, but they should not be connected. The "replacement" for such comments is the detailed explanation in the tooltip on the downvote arrow, which explains why the answer was downvoted.

Comment: @CodyGray If the goal is to close/delete bad questions/answers, just get rid of downvotes and rely on flags to get the job done. If the goal is to fix bad questions/answers, then constructive criticism is the way to get that done.

Comment: @Beefster Flags serve a different purpose, as well as closing questions. To rate the quality and usefulness of a post, you cast an upvote or a downvote. A question can be bad and still get answers (the lack of attempt is a common reason, for example). If a question is in a poor condition to be answered here, it should be closed. Flags are used for cases where the post is spam, abusive, or otherwise not what it pretends to be (answer), in a way that needs to be removed and not brought back.

Comment: Downvotes are an important mechanism for facilitating closure and deletion of bad questions/answers. Furthermore, downvotes are a signal to other viewers that the post is problematic, even though it is not (or, perhaps, *should not* be) deleted. Constructive criticism is great, but it has nothing to do with downvotes.

Comment: @CodyGray why do I get "Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved." when I downvote if "we are trying to actively discourage people from leaving comments to accompany their downvotes"

Comment: @Beefster That is a good question. I suppose new users still confuse votes with comments. If there is something that can be easily improved then let the author know. You can also downvote and follow the post so that when it gets improved you can take the downvote away. Voting does not need any more explanation than is provided in the tooltip. If people wanted to point out a mistake or a problem they can always do so in the comments and the two things are not connected.

Answer (score -30):

Why not have two sites?

1. *Stack Overflow*
2. *Stack Overflow Overflow*

On *Stack Overflow*, instead of downvotes, any question or answer can receive **transfer votes** (visible to the author and higher rep users, invisible to lower rep users).

A question or answer which receives 5 transfer votes will be moved across to *Stack Overflow Overflow*.

*Stack Overflow* will be a serene garden.

*Stack Overflow Overflow* will be a weedy jungle.

A sort of [Reddit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit) for those who like to go a-weeding (or who wish to machete their way through a random jungle of code questions and answers).

Questions and answers on *Stack Overflow Overflow* can receive upvotes, downvotes and transfer votes. But the transfer votes (even when there are 5 or more) don't initiate a transfer back to *Stack Overflow* so long as the net vote total remains below zero.

**N,B.** For the avoidance of doubt: it wouldn't be possible for ***anyone*** to *post* questions or answers to the second-class site. Posts could only ever be transferred there (and, if they were ever cleaned up enough and achieved a positive vote total, transferred back again). You wouldn't even need a separate domain. A purpose-built subdomain would do it: *overflow.stackoverflow.com*.

Comment: I liked this. I've often thouight we need HomeworkOverflow for similar reasons; a place where questions are not answered directly, but teaching is given

Comment: I like what this answer is attempting, but I don't think having another place to go will end up helping. It's not like users don't have plenty of other options of sites where they can ask questions -- Quora, Reddit, Yahoo! Answers, Cnet Forums just to name a few. I believe the reason why people come to Stack Overflow is because they know in those other weedy jungles where the rules aren't as strict, they just don't get the same quality answers (and often, don't get an answer at all).

Comment: On the other hand, it is probably a lot more welcoming to the user to receive a notice saying "Hey, your question is welcome over here on StackOverflowOverflow" instead of just "Your question isn't useful or it was poorly researched or it's just not clear" like the downvote tooltip conveys. Having two sites might not be a solution, but thinking about it could help us come up with better ways to ["make it more obvious to new users that downvotes on the main site are not insults and in fact can help them help themselves."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366889/7795130), so you got my upvote.

Comment: That site already exists. It's called Yahoo Answers. Or perhaps Reddit. Or Quora. There are plenty of unmoderated or less-moderated places where you can go on the Internet to ask a question. Stack Overflow is not interested in being such a platform, and it doesn't need to be. Our niche is quite different: we focus on *quality*. Why compete against Reddit for a "random jungle of code questions and answers"?

Comment: The trouble wit the two-site idea is neither askers nor answerers will see much value in posting on the "second-class" site.

Comment: @snakecharmerb indeed. Why would I ever want to go to the garbage dump site when it's literally where we dump all the garbage posts? It seems like just another way to effectively delete a post. Just banish it *elsewhere*, so you don't have to look at it. Only with this proposal, in some cases it would be easier to banish posts.

Comment: This will never be accepted on meta. Instead, it is much more likely that 1) Stack Overflow Inc. will never innovate (the acquisition by Microsoft will not change that), 2) downvotes and close votes will be removed, 3) it will be increasingly difficult (but not impossible) to find anything of value of Stack Overflow due to the noise, and 4) Stack Overflow will become the new [hyphen site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts-Exchange) (in a different kind of way).

Comment: @CodyGray - Perhaps I could have explained my concept better above. StackOverflowOverflow (or whatever it would be called) _wouldn't_ be a different site. Just a different domain for "the rest" of Stack Overflow. This would leave StackOverflow as questions of guaranteed quality and answers of guaranteed quality. Which, unless I've misunderstood, _is_ what Stack Overflow wants to be.

Comment: @snakecharmerb - It wouldn't be possible for anyone to _post_ questions or answers to the second-class site. Posts could only ever be transferred there (and, if they were ever cleaned up enough and achieved a positive vote total, transferred back again). You wouldn't even need a separate domain. A purpose-built subdomain would do it: _overflow.stackoverflow.com_.

Comment: @Rounin How is this meaningfully different from closing bad questions and then re-opening them if they get cleaned up/brought on-topic?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery - You raise an excellent point. Being "moved" _**is**_ a meaningfully different UX from being "closed". The semantics of "close" are quite negative. Something being closed indicates that it's "beyond redemption" or "unsalvageable". Whereas being relegated to a second-division subdomain strongly suggests that there's opportunity for redemption. Can you name something else on the web that you can "close" - your website, your email account, your social media accounts, your Netflix subscription etc. - but you can later bring back? "Close" definitely has an air of finality about it.

Comment: A high quality Q&A site is what *the entire network* wants to be, not just Stack Overflow. There's no place for a Garbage.SE.

Comment: @CodyGray - I wouldn't automatically write off any question or answer which is less than high quality as "garbage". That's quite the binary outlook. I think there is value in having a range on the spectrum labelled "not good enough to be amongst the high quality questions and answers but not garbage enough to be worth deleting." I'd contend there absolutely is a place for NeedsImprovement.SE and that isn't the same place as HighQuality.SE. Trying to force high quality questions/answers and those that need improvement to co-exist in the same place ends up leading to more problems.

Comment: If it's not garbage, then we welcome it on Stack Overflow. We just have quality standards here, and they're the same quality standards as you find across the entire Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @CodyGray - Again, I think you're framing this as a binary: that either something is garbage or it is quality. We both understand that there are different levels of garbage and different levels of quality. If something would benefit from being worked on but good enough that it doesn't merit deletion, that doesn't mean that (in its present state, at least) it doesn't still add a little more noise and confusion than necessary to an otherwise high quality page. [1/2]

Comment: What I am suggesting above is that it can be removed from the otherwise high quality page and returned to that page when it meets the same standard as the rest of the page. [2/2]

Comment: Re: the name - perhaps "StackOverflow Drafts" would be more appropriate?

Comment: @atravers - Yes, I agree. Excellent suggestion. Stack Overflow Drafts - for questions and answers that absolutely show potential but haven't yet arrived at the gold standard.

Answer (score -31):

Consider adding the ability to contact the downvoter(s) with comments along the lines of

> @downvoters, could you please clarify your reasoning?

or

> With the recent edit, does the @downvote still apply?

making this comment appear in downvoters’ inboxes but leaving them anonymous unless they choose to respond.

Comment: Oh no, not _even more_ "why the downvote" comments! Those are already posted by the hundreds. Not to mention how annoying it would be for the downvoter to receive a notification every time that happens. If they wanted to leave feedback, they would've done it from the beginning. They don't need to be reminded or forced to comment because of the poster's plea.

Comment: Last note, this question is about how to encourage downvotes, not how to discourage them.

Comment: @E_net4likesdownvotes apparently I’ve already succeeded :-)

Comment: again, the reason is already given inside the tooltip of the downvote (like for upvote). Simply assume that everyone is giving a downvote for that same reason and nothing more.

Comment: Not like you can claim that you got all reasons for the downvotes, but nevertheless, this could be yet another sign that we don't need that system. ;) Although feedback isn't mandatory, the percentage of downvotes without comments is not that large (usually less than 30% according to rene's [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/813466/up-accept-and-down-votes-over-time)).

Comment: Happens with enough frequency: 1. I see a post with a problem 2. I *don't* downvote but instead start writing a comment to mention the problem. 3. by the time I finish and post the comment, somebody downvoted. 4. I get an angry message back "but why did you downvote?" or even occasionally a revenge downvote (an educated guess - happens very soon after I post a comment on the newly downvoted answer). I've taken to sometimes avoiding commenting for this reason alone. If I see a post gets a downvote before I've finished writing a comment I sometimes just discard it.

Comment: It doesn't matter *who* downvoted. Often unfair votes are immediately compensated, e.g. if I see downvoted correct answer I am simply upvoting it. If you get multiple downvotes, you are likely to be wrong and the system should tell you why, as well as researches (read help section, search meta, ask meta, etc.) not downvoters who are right..

Comment: @VLAZ: Perhaps a system would be nice where you could give anonymous feedback ... Revenge downvoting would then be no problem.

Comment: To me it does not make sense that downvoting *costs* something - points. If downvoting is the result of a serious thinking process with the result of a constructive critics it should be honored. One way could be that, if a downvoter also adds a comment, he should get as many points as for an upvote.

Comment: If everyone I ever downvoted could ping me whenever they felt like it, I feel like that would deter me from downvoting. People would likely use that kind of a feature to harass people for downvoting. Whether less downvoting a desirable effect or not is another topic, but the question was how to *encourage* downvotes.

Answer (score -31):

### Assumption

> There is no bad question. (Ever heard of that? Isn't it a good value
> to have?)

### Consequences

- Do not allow any downvotes on questions.
- Instead make some non-hurtful button(/buttons?) that has the meaning of "not useful"/"lacks research effort"/...
- This should not affect any reputation of the user. It should not have any direct negative effect on the user to ask a question even if it is ill-posed, not useful and so on (indirect effects like the system classifying the question as cold as ice, is ok, as it hurts the user only slightly).

### Example

My answer is not well written, I haven't researched enough and I didn't explain well and I know I could do it better and be much more convincing if I may say so.
But I lack the effort and just want to answer. Please let me do it and tell me, hey thank you for the answer by a score of minimum 0, then click on the "lacks effort"/"badly written" button and I see a 26 on that button, which means I need to improve the answer very much.

### Dream outcome

I feel so welcome and in a warm hug by the community who just wants my best and wants me to improve my answers and questions. They don't put a mark on my forehead that says "-349" in *red*. No, they have other means. They are more "polite" and care a lot for my feelings. Which can be hurt by the slightest minus. I put myself out there and am very vulnerable.

### TL;DR

- Feelings of users are important.
- Downvoting can feel for some/many users like the soft version of calling them an "idiot".
- "There is no bad question."
- Use a button for improvement of question, but do not call it "downvote" and do not punish the user for a bad question.

Comment: "*Instead make some non-hurtful button(/buttons?) that has the meaning of "not useful"/"lacks research effort"/...*" the downvote button is not meant to be hurtful. Yet it apparently is. Why would these new buttons also not be hurtful if they convey the same meaning? Yes, instead of, say, a -5 you'd have 5 "this is bad" marks. What's the difference?

Comment: *There is no bad question*: Only true if you want to teach a single person. If you want to build a library where people can find almost everything without having to ask new questions, there are bad questions. Poorly phrased, No research, Does not included the slightest bit of information. SO is somewhere in between these extremes.  But there are definitely questions that are not acceptable.

Comment: And honestly, I don't want to welcome every single question where op didn't even bother to run a spellchecker or show the slightest bit of effort. There are way too many questions each day already and way too few people answering/curating, so why care so much about the low-effort users?

Comment: Regarding the part where you say that users feelings are important, that has been disagreed with several times: there are plenty more visitors than active users, the system optimizes for those by upholding quality standards. Relevant meta question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311837

Comment: When I'm looking for answers on SO, I really don't care at all if any feeling of any wannabe answerer might have been hurt. I want good, useful answers, and the bad ones gone or largely downvoted, so that I know that I shouldn't use them. Pretending to "be nice" to a few people who "just want to help" just hurts everyone that tries to make use of the site.

Comment: *Feelings of users are important.* Ehhhhhh.  In some scenarios, yes.  In a highly detail oriented field (like programming or engineering), details *matter*.  Buildings don't stay up because someone feels hurt their best didn't meet standards.  Same with here; we're building a repository that's supposed to withstand the test of time.  Can't do that if we just allow everything because of feelings.

Comment: @VLAZ I think that "downvote" is sadly and subtly interpreted as a personal downvote. When it is not a downvote, but an encouragement to improve, then I could similarly feel as if there are 5 people who wanted to tell me im a not that smart or something("hurtful"). Being "downvoted" and given a negative number instead of getting a positive number of let's say complaints is not a big difference, I would say. But instead of complaint, write "encouragement to improve". I think it's a difference and sends a better message. I still have to work out arguments for my point though...

Comment: @BDL "so why care so much about the low-effort users?" potential effort improvement? I personally dont feel hurt if i have -100 on this answer, because my mindset is, hey, great, people are talking to me and I can improve based on their criticism or in turn change opinions. Also, I can separate myself from my question. I think that we could cheer on people that ask, and improve their effort. It's a big potential, they could make leaps and become better users. But yes, with a 1-for-all solution there is more to consider, e.g. your valid points. Im working on my arguments.

Comment: @fbueckert If you say the priority is on good questions and answers and not on feelings, I agree. You also say in some scenarios feelings matter. I want to work in that direction. A direction of not discouraging a part of online users, which are sensitive and have a lot to learn. I'm not sure how big this part is. Does everyone want only to improve from the start or are some insecure and sensitive at first? Some that put their thoughts out there and get discouraged by downvotes. Some people just need to get encouraged to try again and then could get very productive. I want to encourage them.

Comment: I mentioned other scenarios to make a distinction.  To clarify: *none* of those scenarios apply here.  Our focus is on the content, and the content alone.  We try to ensure that new users understand what we're all about, and try to familiarize them with us beforehand, but there's only so much we can do.  At the end of the day, content trumps people here.

Comment: @BDL, "didn't even bother to run a spellchecker" - it's absolutely definetely that community get more high quality content if integrate any javascript spellchecker into post\comment edit boxes, instead of encouraging users to downvotes for spelling errors

Comment: @EgorBEremeev: Don't get me wrong, I would never downvote a posts just because of a spelling error. But if I read a title like "Plesae help me I have code are not campilig", then that doesn't show a lot of effort on ops side. Yesterdays favorite: "C++ programm changing bahavior with debugger"

Comment: Re 'put a mark on my forehead that says "-349" in *red*': Yes, this is a kind of public shaming. The least they could do would be to hide (but still accessible) the user name for negatively scored posts. But it is more likely that downvotes and close votes will be removed altogether.