# Why there is penalty for down vote?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I have downvoted the answer which is totally irrelevant to the question. Also commented with proper feedback for the posting person. But my reputation goes by -1.

Comment: yes, ...so simple,  stop downvoting

Comment: There have also been suggestions to get rid of this penalty, to [encourage downvoting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398537).

Comment: (please don't stop downvoting)

Comment: Think of it this way: when you earn reputation you earn currency you can spend on your moderation activities. Each downvote costs 1 point so to keep moderating the site you should provide good answers yourself yo earn the points needed for moderation.

Comment: @Dharman, some kind of motivation in simple words :)

Comment: If the downvoted answer gets deleted, then your reputation loss (-1) will be reversed.

Comment: Yes @DalijaPrasnikar , that I observed

Comment: In other words, you have 903 reputation points. Don't let them go to waste. Start downvoting more!

Comment: The point of this, along with locking votes in after 5 minutes, is to discourage tactical voting.

Comment: This is just one example of how you don't really own reputation points, you lease them. They're property of SO and they can be taken for any number of reasons, some of which you have no control over and in rare cases it won't even show up in your reputation change history. Better to learn to not be bothered by it sooner rather than later. Rep that goes up, can just as easily go down again. As long as it goes up more than it goes down, you're golden.

Comment: And after all, it's just fake internet points. If you lose _1_ point, what's the matter? A good edit, and you're back to normal!

Comment: @10Rep it should not be named as Reputation. Instead, just point. For some new people, it is also a motivation to contribute to SO.

Comment: It could be called Cookies.  Users would still complain about losing them.  What they are called isn’t important.  However, just calling them points, wouldn’t be a good change

Comment: Cookies isn't actually such a bad example. You don't hoard cookies, you use them for what they are intended - you eat them or you share them with others. Otherwise they go stale, dry and then bad. Whatever you do, eventually you will lose them and will need to replace them with others.