# Can't we filter review items to just show the posts which are in the tags which are followed by us?

Tags: support, review-queues, filtering

I was recently reviewing the close vote queue and was noticed posts with tags like [julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julia), [demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/demo) etc... which are completely out of my knowledge which makes me unconfident of reviewing them. I can skip them but this isn’t a good choice at all!. Can't we just filter out posts with our preferred tags?

Comment: Yes, there's a filter, is it not working?

Comment: Uh. Sorry @KevinB but im unaware of its existence. Where can I find it?

Comment: It's on the left side of the page, second section, looks like a button

Comment: @KevinB Oh cooool. Cant we add more than 3 tags? Why that limit for 3?

Comment: You can always change it to a different three when your first 3 have no more to review

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [Display review queues based on watched tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380450/8967612) and other similar posts linked there.

Comment: Let me have a look @41686d6564standsw.Palestine

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine I found one post in it but sadly there are no answers/solutions to it. Its [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309583/filter-review-queue-by-default) one.

Comment: For what it's worth, in the staging ground you *can* filter by both your watched tags (though it doesn't support wildcards (yet)) and your "tag badges", so if those filters are received well when it goes live, *maybe* the feature will appear in reviews in the future.

Answer (score 6):

Yes we can (sort of).

Most queues have a filter option that allows you to filter by up to three tags, which will then only show you posts that have at least one of those tags.

The filter input UI element looks like a button. It says "Filter" on it, and is usually located near the top left of the review queue UI.

For the real deal of what you're asking for, there's a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to have such functionality: [Allow review items to be filtered by favorite tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262383/11107541). You can go add your vote there. When I see a feature-request I want to see happen, I typically vote, follow it, and add it to my "wishlist" saves list.